# Como Adicionar um listener para o evento keypress em todos os inputs em javascript puro?

Tags: javascript

Preciso ter um `listener` para o evento `keypress` de todos os inputs da minha aplicação, queria saber a forma mais correta e performática de fazer isso, seria um comportamento semelhante ao `$('input').on('keypress')` do jQuery mas queria fazer em javascript puro.

Tentei algumas alternativas como as desse link: [Adicionar evento a múltiplos elementos sem ser dentro de um loop for](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50138/adicionar-evento-a-m%C3%BAltiplos-elementos-sem-ser-dentro-de-um-loop-for)
mas não está rolando.

Comment: JQuery seria um JavaScript "impuro"? srsrs

Comment: @DanielOmine rsrs! Utilizar javascript puro é mais rápido do que utilizar frameworks, mas é na minha opinião arriscado devido ao cross browser.

Comment: Exato. É que no final das contas vc vai acabar chegando no mesmo que no JQuery. Você pode ir direto no código do JQuery e extrair só as partes que interessa. rsrsr.

Comment: @DanielOmine, kkkkkk...Heresia usar jQuery, é que estou estudando javascript e o foco aqui é desempenho, mas realmente teria que ter tratamentos adicionais para não ter problemas de crossbrowser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue a solução com comentários.

Adicione o código no fim da sua página HTML. É uma boa prática adicionar o código ou o link para o `.js` no fim da página quando esse não precisa ser executado antes do conteúdo ser renderizado.

Dê uma lida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109/onde-devo-colocar-um-c%C3%B3digo-javascript-em-um-documento-html), vai ajuda-lo a entender o que escrevi acima.

```
//É importante que o seu código seja executada somente após a renderização de todos os inputs.
//Caso contrário, o script irá fazer referência a um elemento que
//não foi renderizado, por tanto não existe no momento.

//A técnica abaixo chama-se "self executing", ou seja
//automaticamente será executado o código.
(function() {
    //Array com todos os elementos input.
    //Cada indice do array "inputs" representa contém um objecto input
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    //É atribuído o evento "keypress" a cada objecto input
    //Definimos também qual função será executa, no exemplo dei o nome de "minhaFuncao"
    for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index)
        inputs[index].addEventListener("keypress", minhaFuncao);
})();

function minhaFuncao(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id); 
}
```

Comment: @FelipeMoraes, tem certeza que o objeto DOM estará disponivel? [**JSFIddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lu0og25/)

Comment: @TobyMosque sim, quando o código ou o link para o js é inserido no fim, sendo que é uma boa prática quando o código não é necessário até que a página seja renderizada. Vou acrescentar a informação.

Comment: @FelipeMoraes, obrigado cara, funcionou dessa forma, não comentei porque achei q seria simples, mas preciso enviar o objeto input que foi pressionado ou sua id, mas quando passou algum parâmetro o listener só funciona ao abrir a página, depois o listener não funciona mais, sabe como posso passar parâmetro nesse caso?

Comment: @FelipeMoraes, acho que consegui, ao invés de passar parâmetro, deixei a IIFE do jeito que está e na "minhaFuncao" usei e.target, parece que fucionou, isso está correto?

Comment: @JoãoPaulo atualizei a resposta com a sua dúvida. É passado para a função "minhaFuncao" o parâmetro "event", que por acaso dei o mesmo nome.

Comment: @FelipeMoraes, blz cara deu certinho, um abraço.
PS.: Sou novo aqui, tem algo na plataforma como: atribuir melhor resposta na minha opinião, aumentar pontos do usuário ou algo assim?
Ou finalizar como dúvida resolvida..

Comment: @FelipeMoraes, a tecnica `self executing` não garante que o script será executado após a renderização dos objetos DOM, até pq esta tecnica tenta resolver outro problema, criar um closure para limitar o escopo do script.
Quanto a colocar o script no final do body ser uma boa pratica, isto é contestavel, você pode e deve usar o `defer` e o `async` para definir quando e como os scripts serão carregados. [Deep dive into the murky waters of script loading](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/)

Comment: @JoãoPaulo sim, existe botões no lado esquerdo de cada resposta, em que você pode escolher a que resolve o seu problema (é bom para que outros com o mesmo problema vejam a solução escolhida), pode dar negativo ou posito para uma resposta... dê uma lida aqui na central de ajuda para entender como a comunidade funciona: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @TobyMosque eu sei do que se trata, sei que existe o defer/async, porém não é esse o sentido da pergunta nem a solução, não dá para discutir isso aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
/**
 *
 * @param el Object element a ser adicionado o evento
 * @param func Function função a ser adicionada
 */
function addKeypress(el, func) {

  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener('keypress', func, false); 
  } else if (el.attachEvent)  {//Internet Explorer antigos
    el.attachEvent('onkeypress', func);
  }

}

function yourFunc() {
 alert('Teste');
}

(function(d) {

  var inputs = d.getElementsByTagName('input');
  
  for (var input in inputs) {
   addKeypress(inputs[input], yourFunc);
  }

})(document);
```

```css
input {
  diplay: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<label for="txt_input1">Input 1:<input type="text" id="txt_input1" nome="txt_input1"></label>
<label for="txt_input2">Input 2:<input type="text" id="txt_input2" nome="txt_input2"></label>
<label for="txt_input3">Input 3:<input type="text" id="txt_input3" nome="txt_input3"></label>
<label for="txt_input4">Input 4:<input type="text" id="txt_input4" nome="txt_input4"></label>
```

Comment: legal cara, vi q tem um fallback para IE <= 8 neh, valeu