# É possivel adicionar evento de click em elementos criados dinamicamente ? <Leia descriçao>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá boa noite a todos!

Criei elementos em meu HTML (span) e agora preciso adicionar um evento de click para exibir um som sempre que clicar em alguma tag span que foi criada pelo document.createElement porém quando eu tento o som é adicionado apenas quando eu crio a tag span direto pelo HTML.

Como pode ver no print abaixo com exceção do primeiro, todos os outros quadrados são criados pelo JavaScript com createElement, eu gostaria de clicar em cada quadrado e reproduzir um som que será reproduzido aleatoriamente em cada quadrado.

O problema é que quando eu coloco o comando:

```
let sound = document.querySelectorAll('span');
```

Esta pegando apenas o primeiro span que foi criado diretamente pelo meu HTML e não um arrayLike para que eu possa adicionar evento de click com um forEach. Alguem poderia me ajudar? Estou criando isso apenas para fins de estudo, desde já agradeço a todos vocêss!

Print: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se esta resposta te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50265/74

Comment: Particularmente a parte sobre delegação de eventos

Comment: _"Exibir um som"_ é uma bela de uma sinestesia.

Comment: @Piovezan, no caso não disse direito mas esse "Exibir um som" seria tomar uma parte da musica que eu colocar no meu HTML e ativar com o var.play() na função.

Comment: @bfavaretto, vou dar uma lida mais tarde, obrigado pela indicação!