# O que é e qual a função do . (ponto) em POO?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, operadores

Muito tempo atrás um professor definiu e explicou a função do `.` em `POO` (Aula de Java).

Com o tempo acabei esquecendo, mas achei bastante interessante, muitas vezes pensamos é apenas um "ponto", porém, não é bem assim.

Por isso a pergunta: `O que é e qual a função . (ponto) em POO?`

Comment: Sintaxe para acessar propriedades ou métodos de um objeto/classe?

Comment: Sim, mas acho que tinha algo com relação a operador ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Isso pode variar de uma linguagem para outra. Por exemplo, no PHP usasse o operador seta `->`, no javascript pode-se usar opcionalmente o `['nome_do_atributo']`. Essa resposta vai ser variável. Mas no contexto pedido pela pergunta, trata-se de um operador que vai te permitir acessar os membros de uma instância de uma classe (o objeto)

Comment: Acho que seu professor deve ter falado sobre ponteiros (apontadores), e não ponto. O Ponteiro tem uma importância bem grande dentro de classes, métodos etc, serve para  chamar atributos, métodos pertencentes a classe ou atributo, ou o escopo atual. E no caso do Java, se não me engano, o ponto é usado como ponteiro.

Comment: Na verdade em java, os ponteiros são chamados de referência. Só que no java não existe aritmética de ponteiros.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

É um operador binário (possui dois operandos, um do lado esquerdo e outro do lado direito). Normalmente chamado *dot operator*.

O mais comum é que do lado esquerdo fica o objeto ao qual está se referenciando. Do lado direito está a mensagem que está passando para o objeto. O mais comum é ser a invocação de um método, mas também pode ser o acesso direto à uma variável do objeto. Então ele é o operador de acesso a membros de um objeto. Existe caso que o lado esquerdo não ser o objeto mas algum membro que dá acesso ao um objeto.

Há casos em que o acesso não é feito no objeto e sim diretamente na classe.

Também pode usar como separador de nomes dos pacotes, mas isso não está tão relacionado ao foco da pergunta.

[Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

Você quer dizer operador ponto (dot operator)?

De acordo o Java Tutorial disponível nesse [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html). O ponto serve para:

> Code that is outside the object's class must use an object reference or expression, followed by the dot (.) operator, followed by a simple field name...

Em tradução livre:

> Código externo ao objeto precisa usar uma referência de objeto ou expressão, seguido pelo operador ponto...

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Isso está mais relacionado a como se dá acesso externo de dentro de uma classe.

Answer (score 3):

Esse operador também é referido como *dot operator*.

Como a resposta do @Maniero♦ já fala, ele é um operador *binário* (possui 2 operandos na forma `a.b`) que acessa os *membros* de um objeto ou classe da seguinte forma:

Eu tenho uma classe `Lampada`:

```java
public class Lampada {
    public boolean acessa = false;

    public void acender() { acessa = true; }
    public void apagar() { acessa = false; }
}
```

Perceba que este código não segue nenhum tipo de "boas práticas" da programação, é só um exemplo.

Os *membros* da `Lampada` são o [campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269089/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-atributo-e-campo-nas-classes) privado `acessa` e os [métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11848/quais-s%c3%a3o-as-defini%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-m%c3%a9todo-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-e-procedimento) `ligar()` e `desligar()`.

Perceba que tudo isso está dentro de um [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13034/o-que-s%c3%a3o-escopo-l%c3%a9xico-e-escopo-din%c3%a2mico-e-quais-s%c3%a3o-suas-principais-diferen%c3%a7as), isso significa que **não podemos acessar algo dentro desse escopo fora dele**, é aí que o *dot operator* vem para salvar a pátria. Tendo uma instância dessa classe podemos acessar seus membros:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var lampada = new Lampada(); // Instância da Lampada

    boolean acessa = lampada.acessa; // Acessando o campo 'acessa'
    lampada.ligar(); // Ao acessar métodos eles são executados, isto é:

    System.out.println(lampada.acessa); // true
    System.out.println(acessa); // false
}
```

Perceba também que usando o ponto podemos também *separar os escopos*, isto é, `c` é diferente de `a.c` que é diferente de `a.b.c`. Neste último caso estamos acessando um escopo dentro de um escopo dentro de um escopo:

```java
class Exemplo {
    class A { public B b = new B(); }

    class B { public C c = new C(); }

    class C {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var a = new A();
        a.b; // Acessa 'b' dentro da classe A
        a.b.c; // Acessa 'c' dentro da classe B que está dentro da classe A
    }
}
```

Note que é exatamente isso que acontece quando chamamos `System.out.println()`, porém ao invés do `a.b.c` ser uma variável, é um método da variável `out`, que e uma instância de `java.io.PrintStream`. Veja como esse operador realmente é importante e muito usado!

---

O ponto também é usado para separar os "domínios" de um pacote:

```java
package da.up.na.resposta;
```