# Quais são os escopos das variáveis no ADVPL e quando utilizar cada um?

Tags: variáveis, escopo-de-variáveis, advpl

Estou pegando um código de um colega para dar manutenção. Eis que me encontro com esse código aqui:

```
Static Function Conv2Json(cCpo)
    Local cRet := ""
    Local cSeparador := ""

    aCpo := StrtoKArr(cCpo, ';')

    cSeparador := " + ' - ' +"

    For i := 1 to len(aCpo)
        cRet += _cTabela + "->" + aCpo[i] + cSeparador
    Next i

    cRet := SUBS(cRet, 1, len(cRet) - len(cSeparador))
return cRet
```

Porém não vejo `_cTabela` sendo usado como parâmetro nem tampouco sendo declarada como variável da função.

Eu vi, entretanto, que ela é declarada na função chamadora:

```
User Function makeUniJson(cTabela, cOp, cTabgeo) 
    Local cJson := ""

    Local cCodTab       := ""
    Local cTabProtheus  := ""
    Local cTabGeosales  := ""
    Local cStatus       := ""

    Local xResult       := ""

    Private _cTabela    := cTabela

    Default cTabGeo     := ""

    ...
```

Pelo visto, tem algo a ver com o escopo da variável, mas não entendi direito como essa questão do escopo funciona.

Qual a diferença entre variáveis declaradas com `Local` ou `Private`? O que seria o `Default`? Existe algo como `Global` ou `Public`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ADVPL em essência é o [Clipper](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43902/101) (piorado). A linguagem possui uma coisa chamada [escopo dinâmico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13034/101), umas das piores invenções da computação. Mas não é um grande problema, porque esse mecanismo é totalmente opcional, você pode usar variáveis locais como qualquer linguagem e ter o escopo léxico normalmente, sem prejuízos. Todo bom programador sabe que não deve usar escopo dinâmico, a não ser em linguagens feitas só para criar *scripts*, mesmo nessas linguagens não é incentivado pelos próprios autores.

O escopo da variável é determinado pelo momento da execução que ela foi criada e sobrevive e **é visível** até que o escopo esteja ativo ainda, mesmo que o escopo léxico seja outro. Ou seja, a variável é criada em uma função e todas as funções que ela chamar e as que forem chamadas na pilha toda, ela existe e é visível normalmente, ela só deixa de existir quando finalizar a função que a criou. Ela é criada por padrão se não colocar algum atributo modificador de escopo ou se for explícito e declarar a variável como `private`.

É uma espécie de variável pública global, onde esta tem o tempo de vida por toda a aplicação a partir do momento que é criada e sempre é visível, mesmo fora (depois de finalizar) de onde ela foi criada, só que a variável privada tem o escopo um pouco reduzido, já que ela só existe pra cima da pilha e não pra baixo.

Você pode pensar, `public` é pior que `private`, já que tem um escopo muito mais amplo, certo? Na teoria sim, na prática não. Na prática todo programador sabe que `public` é perigoso demais e evita o seu uso (nenhum código Clipper/Harbour precisa de `public` ou `private` para ter todo seu potencial, é recurso completamente desnecessário, em tese ADVPL também poderia, mas na prática não), enquanto que a variável `private` (escopo dinâmico) o programador se sente seguro e usa como se a variável fosse tão privada assim, e não é bem assim como já mostrado acima.

Mas advinha? Protheus é todo desenvolvido com `private` em mente. Você tem que adivinhar quais são as variáveis que estão no escopo naquele momento. E podem ser centenas. E tem que tomar cuidado para não criar uma nova no escopo dessa função porque pode conflitar com a "privada" já existente. É uma loucura, é insano, até para uma aplicação pequena, imagina para uma com milhões de linhas com pilhas de chamadas de dezenas de funções.

Então em seus códigos só use `local` (ou `static` em alguns raros casos), não use `public` ou `private` em hipótese alguma. Mas consuma as variáveis existentes declaradas assim pelo sistema. Elas acabam fazendo parte do contrato, da API. Considere elas sempre como se elas tivesse sido recebidas como parâmetro.

Aí você pensa: deve ter documentação mostrando todas as variáveis em cada função. Mas não tem, primeiro porque a documentação é fraca, segundo porque quase não faz sentido. Dependendo da ordem de chamada serão outras variáveis. A sua função de usuário não tem documentação, e é na sua função que elas estarão disponíveis. Depende de quem chamar pode mudar as variáveis disponíveis. É na tentativa e erro, e olhar na depuração quais a variáveis que estão lá agora (o que pode ser diferente dependendo da versão (é ruim assim mesmo, tenho experiência recente, inclusive tive chamado aberto para resolver certas situações que tornavam impossível resolver certa questão que eu estava trabalhando).

Lamento você ter que passar por isso. Também passei. Tive que pedir a criação de pontos de entrada novos para resolver sem depender dessas variáveis. Quando eles criam coisas novas eles fazem certo e passam argumentos para a minha função de usuário, hoje eles sabem que não é para usar isso. Mas adivinha de novo? Nem todos os programadores lá sabem o que estão fazendo ou estão comprometidos em fazer certo e muita coisa ainda é criada desta forma. Quando passa no único departamento que é ISO 9000 lá (sim, só um departamento minúsculo tem a certificação) fazem certo. E obviamente que tudo o que é legado não tem como resolver porque a maioria das variáveis viraram parte do "contrato".

Olhe na depuração as variáveis disponíveis, faça isso em vários lugares e veja se é algo pontual como diz a outra resposta. Algumas pessoas têm acesso aos fontes atuais do Protheus, se você tiver veja se é pontual. Eu vi, e não é ainda, hoje. A lista só não aumenta mais porque agora entendem que não devem criar novas assim, o que confirma tudo o que eu disse acima.

No seu exemplo `makeUniJson()` "exporta" a variável `_cTabela` para todas as funções que ela chama ou as outras que vão sendo chamadas por elas, deve ser o caso de `Conv2Json()`. Não tem o que fazer para impedir isso, a não ser no seu código que não crie novas variáveis assim. Prefira só exportar o que precisa por parâmetros, como em qualquer linguagem sã.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/xBase/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eventual leitor desta resposta, sugiro essa leitura complementar para se aprofundar no conceito e absurdo que é escopo dinâmico: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13471/64969

Comment: Recomendo também a leitura da documentação da TDN, que fala sobre os escopos das variáveis no AdvPL -- http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6063097

Answer (score -1):

Como foi explicado em outra resposta, variáveis `private` possuem escopo dinâmico.
Este tipo de escopo é mais comum em linguagens tipo "shell", como `bash` (Linux) e `cmd` (DOS/Windows).

Em linguagens de uso geral não é comum a existência de escopo dinâmico, que no entanto existe em pelo menos 2 linguagens atuais: em perl (5/6), onde é declarado explicitamente, e em Lua, onde variáveis globais possuem implicitamente escopo dinâmico.

No eco-sistema ADVPL/Protheus não é comum o uso genérico de variáveis `private`, entretanto no ERP Protheus existe um caso de uso específico onde essas variáveis são utilizadas: na customização de rotinas pelo cliente.

Cada "módulo" (Materiais, Estoque, etc) do Protheus publica uma lista de "pontos de entrada" (funções) que as rotinas de negócios disponibilizam, para que possam ser customizadas pelos clientes.

Essas customizações geralmente são efetuadas por analistas de consultorias que possuem conhecimento do módulo em questão. Normalmente (sempre?) os parâmetros são passados para os pontos de entrada em uma variável `private` do tipo array e nome PARAMIXB.