# O que são AMD e CommonJS?

Tags: javascript, arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software

Recentemente tenho ouvido falar bastante sobre Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) e CommonJS. Parecem dois termos que estão na moda.

Li algumas coisas sobre, mas ainda estou confuso.

AMD e CommonJS são bibliotecas ou especificações?

Quem pode nos explicar de forma simples e prática o que são esses dois termos?

Comment: Acho que existem já algumas respostas sobre isto aqui. Seria interessante incluir Modulos Harmony talvez.

Comment: Pergunta relacionada (ou pelo menos minha resposta lá é relacionada!): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17343/an%c3%a1lise-e-projeto-em-javascript

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## AMD

É uma API javascript que define Módulos de forma que suas dependências possam ser carregadas de forma assíncrona. É muito útil em melhorar a performance de sites evitando o carregamento síncrono de scripts antes do conteúdo do restante do site.

Além de carregar vários arquivos JavaScript em runtime, também pode ser utilizado no desenvolvimento para manter os arquivos javascript encapsulados para vários javascripts diferentes funcionando como um import.

O RequireJS é uma implementação de AMD.

Utilizando RequireJs(AMD) com KnockOut por exemplo:

```
require(['knockout-x.y.z', 'appViewModel'], function(ko, appViewModel) {
    ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
});
```

indica que deve carregar or arquivos 'knockout-x.y.z' e 'appViewModel' antes de executar o código dentro da funcao

enquanto o arquivo appViewModel deveria ter

```
// Main viewmodel class
define(['knockout-x.y.z'], function(ko) {
    return function appViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable('Bert');
        this.firstNameCaps = ko.computed(function() {
            return this.firstName().toUpperCase();
        }, this);
    };
});
```

pois só funcionaria depois que a biblioteca knockout fosse carregada.

## CommonJs

CommonJs é uma API com o objetivo de agrupar as necessidades de diversas aplicações javascript em uma única API, que funcione em diversos ambientes e interpretadores. Criando o conceito de se módulos que façam essas funções. E estes módulos podem ser carregados assincronamente com ferramentas AMD.

Dentre as funcionalidades oferecidas temos:

- Definições Assíncronas
- Promessas
- Testes unitários

Este [link](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) trás um exemplo de como utilizar o CommonJs em conjunto com AMD utilizando curl.js e requirejs

Comment: A sua foi bem direta e clara, +1

Answer (score 6):

Existe uma pergunta semelhante no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521471/relation-between-commonjs-amd-and-requirejs), coloquei alguns trechos da reposta traduzida, acho bem difícil mas se por um acaso o link ficar offline pelo menos temos como nos orientar por essa resposta, espero que ajude.

RequireJS implementa a API AMD [(fonte)](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html)

CommonJS é uma forma de definir os módulos com a ajuda de um exportações objeto, que define o conteúdo do módulo.

```
    // someModule.js
exports.doSomething = function() { return "foo"; };

//otherModule.js
var someModule = require('someModule'); // in the vein of node    
exports.doSomethingElse = function() { return someModule.doSomething() + "bar"; }
```

CommonJS especifica que você precisa ter uma função para buscar as dependências, as exportações de variáveis ​​para exportar conteúdo do módulo e alguns identificador do módulo que é usada para exigir que o dependências. CommonJS tem várias implementações, por exemplo Node.js

RequireJS implementa AMD, que é projetado para se adequar ao navegador, Aparentemente AMD começou como uma offspin de formato CommonJs Transportes e evoluiu em sua própria API de definição de módulo. Daí as semelhanças entre os dois. A novidade no AMD é a função de definir-que permite que o módulo para declarar suas dependências antes de ser carregada. Por exemplo, a definição poderia ser:

```
define('module/id/string', ['module', 'dependency', 'array'], 
function(module, factory function) {
  return ModuleContents;  
});
```

Então CommonJS e AMD são Javascript módulos de APIs que têm implementações diferentes, mas ambos vêm das mesmas origens. AMD é mais adequado para o browser, porque suporta o carregamento assíncrono de dependências de módulo. RequireJS é uma implementação da AMD, enquanto ao mesmo tempo tentando manter o espírito de CommonJS (principalmente nos identificadores de módulo). Para confundir ainda mais, RequireJS, sendo uma implementação AMD, oferece um invólucro CommonJS tão módulos COmmonJs quase pode ser diretamente importado para uso com RequireJS.

[FONTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521471/relation-between-commonjs-amd-and-requirejs)

Comment: Então se eu entendi corretamente, RequireJS é uma biblioteca javascript que implementa a especificação AMD. Me deparei com AMD e CommonJS justamente por causa do RequireJS.

Comment: Ficou engraçado o primeiro bloco de código traduzido...

Comment: @bfavaretto obrigado novamente, não tinha percebido que estava traduzido o código. já arrumei.

Comment: @GuilhermeJSantos pelo que entendi, sim!