# A Ausência de ponto e vírgula no CSS e Javascript pode influenciar no funcionamento do código?

Tags: javascript, css

Sempre deixo meu código css e javascript minificado mas nunca tinha reparado no output gerado. Pois bem, notei que a última regra de um seletor (no css) e a última função (no javascript) sempre perde o ponto e vírgula. Por exemplo, uma regra simples no css:

```
div {
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Ficaria:

```
div{border:2px solid red;color:#fff} /*perdendo o último ponto e vírgula */
```

Um outro exemplo, no javascript:

```
$(function(){
   var foo = true;

   if(foo) {
     foo = false;
     bar();  
   }
});
```

Irá gerar:

```
$(function(){var foo=true;if(foo){foo=false;bar()}}) /* sem os últimos ponto e vírgula */
```

Em caso em que só existe uma função dentro de um bloco, ele também perde a pontuação.

```
if(foo){
  bar();
}
```

Vira:

```
if(foo){bar()}
```

**A minha dúvida sobre o assunto é:** A ausência desses vários ponto e vírgula podem influenciar de alguma forma no funcionamento do código? Fiz testes em códigos simples mas estou pensando se posso ter problemas em trabalhos mais complexos.

Comment: Sei que no `css`, para a última regra, a existência do `;` é indiferente.

Comment: Acredito que vai depender muito da tecnologia, alguns browsers com codigo *legacy* ("velho") podem não reconhecer, mas para a maioria dos usuários que devem usar IE, Safari ou Chrome/Firefox não faça diferença.

Comment: O `;` é mero separador no CSS, nao tem razão de existir no final. Na verdade são 2 perguntas em uma, pq nao tem nada a ver a sintaxe de JS com a de CSS.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3341/utilizar-ou-n%C3%A3o-ponto-e-v%C3%ADrgula-no-fim-das-linhas-no-javascript este topico responde as suas duvidas, é uma resposta bem completa

Comment: A pergunta é excelente. A resposta do bfavaretto também. Se quiser se aprofundar mais sobre como funciona o parsing do Javascript e como escrever código bom tanto para quem for manter quanto para o interpretador, recomendo ler o livro *Maintenable Javascript*, de Nicholas C. Zakas. Sobre o assunto específico da pergunta, pesquise por ***Automatic Semicolon Insertion*** - o mecanismo pelo qual o Javascript analisa e considera onde acaba uma expressão ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### CSS

No caso do CSS, não vejo problemas em remover o `;` da última propriedade de uma regra. Como depois dela vem a  chave de fechamento, não tem como haver problemas. O minificador provavelmente faz isso para reduzir o tamanho do arquivo, salvando um caractere por regra.

#### JavaScript

No JS, [as regras omissão do `;`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9) são mais complexas. Remover o ponto-e-vírgula logo antes do fechamento do bloco não me parece problemático, mas outros casos podem ser. Seu exemplo do `$(function...)`, por exemplo. Vamos simplificar e ver onde pode dar problema. Basicamente o que você tem é uma chamada de função:

```
funcao()
```

Isso pode dar problema se outro arquivo for concatenado depois disso. O minificador não sabe o que faz a função faz. E se ela retornar uma função? Por exemplo:

```
function funcao() {
    return function(a) { console.log(a); }
}
```

Imagine algo concatenado depois disso, como um típico código que usa o [*module pattern*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17343/an%C3%A1lise-e-projeto-em-javascript/17355#17355):

```
(function() {
    return { foo: true };
}());
```

O código minificado e concatenado ficaria assim (supondo que `funcao` já estivesse disponível e no escopo):

```
funcao()(function() { return { foo: true };}())
```

O resultado é que a função retornada por `funcao` será invocada, recebendo como parâmetro o objeto `{ foo: true }`. O objeto será logado para o console (pois é isso que nossa função de exemplo faz).

Portanto: uma retirada de `;` em JavaScript, se não for feita com muito cuidado, pode sim causar efeitos colaterais.

Answer (score 0):

1. Na hora de aplicar as técnicas Minify , sem o ;, seu código provavelmente irá parar de funcionar;
2. No meu ver fica algo mais bacana de se entender;

Comment: Isto seria uma opinião ou uma resposta?

Comment: Apenas uma opinião. Devo ter alocado em local errado.