# Uso de ';' antes de iniciar uma função

Tags: javascript, design-pattern

Tem se tornado frequente eu encontrar códigos no github que se iniciam assim:

```
;(function(window){
    'use strict';
})();
```

Só nunca entendi o seguinte. Qual a finalidade de utilizar o ';' antes de iniciar a declaração da função?

Comment: Tem as fontes dessas funções que originaram a pergunta?

Comment: https://github.com/fians/Waves/blob/master/src/js/waves.js

Esta é um exemplo...

Comment: Perguntas relacionadas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38379/a-aus%C3%AAncia-de-ponto-e-v%C3%ADrgula-no-css-e-javascript-pode-influenciar-no-funcioname?lq=1, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3341/utilizar-ou-n%C3%A3o-ponto-e-v%C3%ADrgula-no-fim-das-linhas-no-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O *semicolon* é utilizado para certificar-se que a instrução anterior foi terminada.

Por exemplo:

```js
(function() {

})()  // <--- Não tem ponto e vírgula

//  Adicionado ponto e vírgula para evitar um resultado inesperado do código anterior   
;(function ($) {

})();
```

O nome dessa técnica é [**IIFE**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (*Immediately-Invoked Function Expression*).

Comment: Fazendo uma busca em inglês acabei encontrando isso aqui também:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145514/whats-the-purpose-of-starting-semi-colon-at-beginning-of-javascript

Obrigado pela resposta! :D

Answer (score 8):

Funções de auto-invocação são construídas entre parenteses, colocar um ponto e vírgula antes do inicio da função pode evitar que a função torne-se parte de qualquer código antecessor, note que:

O código

```
var a = 10 

(function(){...})()
```

É o mesmo que

```
var a = 10 (function(){...})()
```

Agora colocando o ponto e virgula, você evita este tipo de eventual problema em seu código

```
var a = 10 

;(function(){...})()
```

Comment: Excelente complemento. =)

Comment: @Qmechanic73 notei que vc já havia respondido, mais como já estava escrevendo aproveitei para postar :P