# Propriedade Private / Protected JS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, orientação-a-objetos, propriedade

É possivel fazer um objeto no js/jQuery onde seja visivel apenas usando o metódo, por exemplo get / set?
Um exemplo de um objeto:

se eu der um `console.log(pessoa.documeto)`, ele vai exibir os valores, mas o que eu queria é ver se existe como deixa-lo 'private' ou 'protected' igual ao PHP e outros.

```
var pessoa = {
        nome    : '' , //Publico
        idade   : '' ,  //Publico
        documentos : [
                //Protegido / Privado
                {
                    CPF : {
                num         : '' , 
                dataemissao : '' ,
                ufemissao   : '' ,
                obrigatorio : true ,
                status      : ''
            } ,
            RG : {
                num : '' ,
                dataemissao : '' ,
                ufemissao   : '' ,
                obrigatorio : '' ,
                status      : false
            }
                }
        ] ,
        parentes : [
                {
            pai : {
                nome    : ''    ,
                idade   : ''    ,
                cpf     : ''    ,
            } ,
            mae : {
                nome    : ''    ,
                idade   : ''    ,
                cpf     : ''    ,
            },
            irmaos : [
                {
                    nome : ''   ,
                    idade : ''  ,
                    cpf : ''
                }
            ]
               }
        ] ,
        //Metodos
        get : function(propriedade){
            /*
            * Pega a propridade e tal,
            * mas nao vou descrever isso aqui agora =D
            */
        } ,
        set : function(proriedade , valor){
            /*
            * Seta a propriedade e bla, bla, bla...
            */
        }
     };
```

Comment: Com objeto literal não dá, mas é possível conseguir algo semelhante com o [module pattern](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17355/).

Comment: Hmm, então vou ter que dar uma olhadinha em algum framework para JS/jQuery ou criar uma função que seria a class (PHP) e outras funções dentro que seria algo como os métodos. isso ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O caminho mais simples é usar uma função para gerar o objeto. Todos os valores que devem ser privados seriam variáveis visíveis somente no escopo dessa função. O getter e o setter seriam outras funções no mesmo escopo, e com acesso a essas variáveis via [closure](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31414/o-que-s%C3%A3o-closures-e-qual-sua-utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o/31417#31417) (basicamente seria a mesma técnica usada no *module pattern*, que expliquei [em uma outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17355/)).

Um exemplo simples:

```
function criaObj() {
    var privado = "bla";

    function getPrivado() {
        return privado;
    }

    function setPrivado(val) {
        privado = val;
    }

    return {
        get: getPrivado,
        set: setPrivado
    };
}

// Uso
var obj = criaObj();
console.log(obj.getPrivado()) // "bla"
obj.setPrivado("foo");
console.log(obj.getPrivado()) // "foo"
```

Outra opção é usar uma função construtora e [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) (ou [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)) para criar getters e setters "de verdade".

```
function Construtor() {
    var privado = "bla";

    // Cria propriedade bla (getter/setter) no objeto sendo instanciado
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'bla', {
        get: function() { return privado; },
        set: function(val) { privado = val; }
    });
}

var obj = new Construtor();
console.log(obj.bla); // "bla"
obj.bla = "foo";
console.log(obj.bla); // "foo"
```

Comment: Compreendi e agradeço pela atenção! Só não dei um positivo por que faltou 1 ponto para liberar =/

Comment: Tranquilo. Ainda vou complementar a resposta com uma outra opção um pouco mais complexa.

Comment: @DouglasDreer ponto concedido, a pergunta ficou legal

Comment: @DouglasDreer Não sei se chegou a ver a atualização da resposta com outra opção.

Comment: Vou testar esta atualização e logo te dou um parecer. Pois a anterior não consegui fazer funcionar direito.

Comment: Funcionou com você me explicou e tudo mais, mas como faria se houvesse vários parâmetros ?
`function pessoa(){ var nome = '<insira seu nome>'; var idade = '<insira a idade>';
var array = ['branco' ,'loiro' , 'olhos claro'];
var object = {item : valor };
(...)
});
`