# Código dentro de parenteses

Tags: javascript, funções

Qual a diferença de escrever um código em Javascript nas seguintes formas:

Forma Original:

```
'use strict';

var openCtrl = document.getElementById('btn-search'),
    closeCtrl = document.getElementById('btn-search-close'),
    searchContainer = document.querySelector('.search'),
    inputSearch = searchContainer.querySelector('.search__input');

function init() {
    initEvents();   
}

function initEvents() {
    openCtrl.addEventListener('click', openSearch);
    closeCtrl.addEventListener('click', closeSearch);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev) {
        // escape key.
        if( ev.keyCode == 27 ) {
            closeSearch();
        }
    });
}

function openSearch() {
    searchContainer.classList.add('search--open');
    inputSearch.focus();
}

function closeSearch() {
    searchContainer.classList.remove('search--open');
    inputSearch.blur();
    inputSearch.value = '';
}

init();
```

Agora qual a diferença fazer desta forma:

```
;(function(window) {

    'use strict';

    var openCtrl = document.getElementById('btn-search'),
        closeCtrl = document.getElementById('btn-search-close'),
        searchContainer = document.querySelector('.search'),
        inputSearch = searchContainer.querySelector('.search__input');

    function init() {
        initEvents();   
    }

    function initEvents() {
        openCtrl.addEventListener('click', openSearch);
        closeCtrl.addEventListener('click', closeSearch);
        document.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev) {
            // escape key.
            if( ev.keyCode == 27 ) {
                closeSearch();
            }
        });
    }

    function openSearch() {
        searchContainer.classList.add('search--open');
        inputSearch.focus();
    }

    function closeSearch() {
        searchContainer.classList.remove('search--open');
        inputSearch.blur();
        inputSearch.value = '';
    }

    init();

})(window);
```

Comment: + respostas: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23785/3635, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9938/3635 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/3635

Comment: Também relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17343/an%C3%A1lise-e-projeto-em-javascript/17355#17355

Comment: Fechei, mas não sei se foi uma boa ideia. Tem vários conteúdos relacionados, mas nenhum é duplicata exata. O mais próximo que achei foi esse terceiro link que botei no aviso de duplicata

Comment: @bfavaretto ao meu ver isso http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23785/3635 responde perfeitamente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geralmente em JavaScript isso é feito para conter o escopo. Por exemplo, eu escrevo um plugin que tem muitas funções com diversos nomes, mas eu quero expor apenas algumas para uso, então eu contenho o código dentro de parênteses para ser colocado como um *namespace*.

```
function soma () {...}

function subt () {...}

function mult () {...}

function divi () {...}

var calculadora = {
    somar: soma,
    subtrair: subt,
    multiplicar: mult,
    dividir: divi
}

// Funciona
calculadora.multiplicar(2, 3); // 6

// Também funciona
mult(2, 3); // 6
```

Dessa forma o código que você importa tem funções no escopo global que você pode tentar reescrever sem perceber, já que você não sabe o nome das funções que foram usados porque você não escreveu o código. Com isso também evitamos dar nomes complicados e cheios de jeitinhos para não conflitar com outros nomes de função.

```
(function (window) {
    function soma () {...}

    function subt () {...}

    function mult () {...}

    function divi () {...}

    window.calculadora = {
        somar: soma,
        subtrair: subt,
        multiplicar: mult,
        dividir: divi
    }
})(window);

// Funciona
calculadora.multiplicar(2, 3); // 6

// Não funciona
mult(2, 3); // Uncaught ReferenceError: mult is not defined
```

Desta maneira podemos definir escopos e isolar funções *internas* de exposição interna e não precisamos nos preocupar com conflitos externos, isso também vale para variáveis dentro do escopo.

Answer (score 1):

Na segunda forma você está criando uma Closure: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

A diferença é que, em uma closure você cria um novo escopo e as varíaveis e funções criadas dentro dela pertencem somente à ela.

Comment: No seu script, a unica diferença ao executar é que nenhum dos métodos criados estariam disponíveis fora da Closure e a execução seria a mesma.