# Dúvida com revealing pattern

Tags: javascript

É possível fazer isto com revealing pattern?

o console sempre retorna undefined

```
function FlashService() {

    return{
        get: get
    };

    var _abc = 'teste';

    function get() {
        console.log(_abc);
        return abc;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você precisa atribuir o valor à variável antes de retornar. Devido ao *hoisting* de variáveis e funções (que explico com mais detalhes [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34728)), a declaração da variável é erguida para o topo do escopo, mas a atribuição não. Em resumo, seu código não funciona porque é entendido assim:

```
function FlashService() {
    function get() {
        console.log(_abc);
        return abc;
    }
    var _abc;

    return {
        get: get
    };

    _abc = 'teste';
}
```

Ou sejá, o retorno ocorre antes que o valor seja atribuído, e portanto a *closure* captura a variável com seu valor inicial, `undefined`. A parte do `_abc = 'teste'` nem chega a ser executada.

Funcionará se você alterar para:

```
function FlashService() {
    var _abc = 'teste';

    return {
        get: get
    };

    function get() {
        console.log(_abc);
        return abc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado camarada...