# Nome para funções anônimas

Tags: javascript, funções

Em alguns códigos de exemplo de frameworks, libs, etc. verifiquei que as funções anônimas eram passadas com um nome para as mesmas.

```
minhaFuncao(function minhaFuncaoAnonima() {
    // ...
});
```

Qual o objetivo de nomear funções anônimas? É algum padrão que deve ser seguido?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Existem dois objetivos:

1. **Recursão:** é uma maneira de possibilitar que [expressões de função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13365/74) sejam recursivas. O nome definido para essas funções só está disponível dentro delas próprias, e pode ser usado para chamadas recursivas. Expressões de função anônimas não permitem recursão.
2. **Depuração:** Nos *debuggers* de JS mais usados, essas funções são identificadas pelo nome na pilha de chamadas, em vez de constar como *anonymous function*. Isso ajuda a enxergar melhor que trecho de código está sendo executado.

O artigo citado pelo TobyMosque, [*Named function expressions demystified*](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/) é a grande referência sobre o assunto. Porém, já está um tanto defasado, e acredito que os problemas de compatibilidade que ele aponta não se apliquem mais aos browsers modernos (no caso do IE, versões 10+, talvez 9). Vale a pena ler o artigo linkado para mais detalhes, ele é realmente excelente (assim como outros do mesmo autor, como o [*Understanding delete*](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)).

Comment: o "2" faz todo sentido +1.

Answer (score 13):

Isso chama-se *[Named Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function)*. Se a função fôr recursiva, isto é chamar-se a sí própria, isto é muito util e respeita as regras de escopo normais.

Por exemplo:

```
var number = 12;
var numberFactorial = (function factorial(number){
    return (number == 0) ? 1 : number * factorial(number - 1); // aqui a função chama-se a sí própria
})(number);
console.log(numberFactorial); // 479001600
```

Assim a função pode chamar-se a sí própria para encontrar o resultado. E repara que a função factorial não vai ficar no escopo global: http://jsfiddle.net/xgoo0w02/

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/z9knLsmm/