# Delegate (similar ao C#) em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, delegate

Um recurso que utilizo muito no C# é o [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/900fyy8e.aspx) que é um tipo de referência utilizado para referenciar métodos anônimos ou nomeados. Especialmente as classes já implementadas no *framework* como o [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) e o [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx), conforme exemplo abaixo.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main
    {
        ExibirMensagem((s) => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        });
    }

    public static void ExibirMensagem(Action<T> actMensagem)
    {
        actMensagem("Exibiu a mensagem");
    }
}
```

Eu precisaria de algo similar a isto, porém no JavaScript. Eu sou novo no JavaScript e não sei como fazer isto, pode até ser algo muito simples. No Java 6 que não suporta este tipo de comportamento, eu me lembro que para contornar isso e fazer algo parecido eu usava uma interface que poderia ser implementada anonimamente, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
public interface IAcao {
    void Executar(String str);
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        ExecutarAcao(new IAcao() {
            @Override
            public void Executar(String str) {
                Log.v("Exec", str);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void ExecutarAcao(IAcao delAcao) {
        delAcao.Executar("Executou Ação");
    }
}
```

É possível esta abordagem no JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript possui um recurso semelhante ao *delegate*. É a função anônima, que no fundo é o mesmo conceito do delegado. Ela pode tomar a forma de [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101). Geralmente é usada como [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101), assim como os delegados. O delegado é um pouco mais poderoso, mas em coisas poucos usadas e que fazem mais sentido em linguagem de tipagem estática.

Assim como os delegados a função anônima é um corpo de código que é alocado em algum lugar e um ponteiro é atribuído a uma variável, pode transferir essa referência para outras variáveis, inclusive parâmetros. Então é só [declarar a função dentro da variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101).

Seu uso é bem simples. Os detalhes de uso podem ser obtidos nos *links* colocados acima.