# O que são delegates?

Tags: ios, swift, terminologia, delegate

Em programação iOS é comum utilizar estruturas que atuam como *delegates*.

Uma delas, por exemplo, é o `UITextFieldDelegate`. Essa classe, de acordo à [documentação](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate), informa ao implementador eventos importantes do `UITextField`, como se usuário iniciou a digitação ou a finalizou.

Entendo o uso do `UITextFieldDelegate`, mas não o que são esses *delegates* e por que são necessários.

- Existe uma definição mais concreta?
- É um design pattern? Uma arquitetura?
- É exclusivo da programação iOS ou é implementado em outras tecnologias?
- É uma implementação de uma espécie de programação orientada a eventos?

Comment: Você pode pensar num delegate como um ponteiro `*` para uma função `fun()`, ele guarda uma referência para que ela possa ser invocada futuramente.

Comment: Isso vem de uma dúvida de Swift, Objective-C?

Comment: Vem de Swift.......

Comment: Pode por a *tag*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boa parte disso está mais ou menos respondido em [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101).

Grosso modo é um ponteiro para uma função, é uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101), assim você pode colocar a função em uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) e tornar o código flexível ao que executará, pode parametrizar o que será executado fazendo um [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101). Mas ele pode ter algo mais, pode ter o mecanismo necessário para [enclausurar variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101), ou servir de *multicast*. Tem várias maneiras de implementar.

Entenda [O que é Design Pattern?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101). Tudo o que usa é um padrão de projeto. Alguns são receitas de bolo outros são mecanismos prontos, até variável é padrão de projeto. Ele é um *design pattern*.

[É usado onde for preciso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45020/101), embora nem todas as linguagens possuem um mecanismo pronto, e algumas usam outro nome. [Em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116095/101). E [em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141712/101). Agora [tem em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207509/101), mas quando não tinha era possível fazer também, só que tinha que escrever um código enorme.

É uma técnica básica para criar [eventos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207571/101) e onde se usa eventos como base da programação pode ser [orientado a evento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80611/101), mas [um delegado não é um evento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56957/101). Só note que este [paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) é secundário e sozinho ele não serve pra muita coisa, nada real.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Swift/Conceptual.md).

Comment: ótimas referências. muito obrigado ;-)