# Escopo, funções aninhadas, chamada de funções

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13364/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-var-name-function-e-function-name#34728) e me deparei com uma dúvida em um teste que estou realizando, segue :

```html
<script>
function x(a1="a1"){          // "x" tem acesso a "a"
 var a2="a2";
 console.log("Consele fx =" + a1);
   console.log("Consele fx =" + a2);
    function y(b1="b1"){      // "y" tem acesso a "a" e "b"
     var b2="b2";
        console.log("Consele fy =" + a1);
        console.log("Consele fy =" + a2);
        console.log("Consele fy =" + b1);
        console.log("Consele fy =" + b2);
        function z(c1="c1"){  // "z" tem acesso a "a", "b", e "c"
         var c2="c2";
            console.log("Consele fz =" + a1);
            console.log("Consele fz =" + a2);
            console.log("Consele fz =" + b1);
            console.log("Consele fz =" + b2);
            console.log("Consele fz =" + c1);
            console.log("Consele fz =" + c2);
        }
   }
}
x(10);
 //Consele fx =10
 //Consele fx =a2
y();//erro
z();//erro
</script>
```

Então minhas dúvidas :

**a)** Ao chamar a função `x()` tudo o que está dentro não deveria ser
   executado ?

**b)** Como faço para que `y()` e `z()` seja executados ?

**c)** Como alterar os parâmetros das funções na chamada ?

**d)** O erro que dá é que as funções não foram definidas, então como
   definir corretamente essas *funções* e *parâmetros* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **a)** Ao chamar a função x() tudo o que está dentro não deveria ser executado ?

não, quando chamas a função `x` dentro dela é defenida/declarada a função `y`. `z` nunca chega a ser defenida/declaradaporque `y` não é invocada/chamada. Terias de ter `y()` ou `z()` dentro de `x`, onde o escopo as torna acessíveis.

> **b)** Como faço para que y() e z() seja executados ?

O que faz uma função ser invocada é `()`. Tens de ter no código `y()` dentro de `x` ou `z` pois só está disponivel nesse escopo (ou dentro de sí própria). Para correr `z` só dentro de `y` ou dentro de sí própria, essa função `z` não está disponivel ao escopo global e nem a `x`.

> **c)** 
>   Como alterar os parâmetros das funções na chamada ?

é só passares valores nos argumentos. Por exemplo: `y(1)`, ou `y([123, 456])`. Se usares `y(1)` então o parametro `b1` terá o valor `1`. Esse parâmetro `b1` pode ter uma valor automáticamente caso `b1`seja *undefined* uma vez que tens na declaração: `function y(b1 = "b1"){`.

> **d)** O erro que dá é que as funções não foram definidas, então como definir corretamente essas funções e parâmetros ?

elas estão corretamente defenidas/declaradas, o problema é de escopo como referi em `b)`, elas não existem ao olhos do escopo global, elas só estão disponiveis no escopo onde foram declaradas e escopos internos a esse.

---

```js
function x(a1 = "a1") {
    var a2 = 'a2';

    function y(b1 = "b1") {
        var b2 = "b2";
        console.log("Consele fy =" + a1);
        console.log("Consele fy =" + a2);
        console.log("Consele fy =" + b1);
        console.log("Consele fy =" + b2);

        function z(c1 = "c1") {
            var c2 = "c2";
            console.log("Consele fz =" + a1);
            console.log("Consele fz =" + a2);
            console.log("Consele fz =" + b1);
            console.log("Consele fz =" + b2);
            console.log("Consele fz =" + c1);
            console.log("Consele fz =" + c2);
        }
        z(); // vai assumir "c1" pois o argumento é "undefined"
    }
    y('algo');
}
x(10);
```

Comment: Agora estou começando a juntar os pauzinhos... Vlw man bem explicado... Vou fazer mais agluns testes para me aprofundar...