# Parâmetros de funções não definidos previamente

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Tenho visto algumas funções javascript com parâmetros que não são previamente definidos, mas que mesmo assim funcionam. A duvida surgiu com a função abaixo. A função `myFunction()` chama o método `pessoas.sort()`, que por sua vez recebe uma função auto invocada como argumento. Essa possui o parâmetro `a` e o `b`. Por que ela funciona mesmo esses não tendo sido previamente definidos? O engine JS os interpreta sozinho? Como isso pode ser feito em outras ocasiões e com outros parâmetros?

```js
var pessoas = [
{country:"Brazil", name:"Lucas"},
{country:"EUA", name:"Jhon"},
{country:"Japan", name:"Sushi"}]

function myFunction() {
    pessoas.sort(function(a, b){return a.name - b.name});
    show();
}

function show() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  pessoas[0].country + " " + pessoas[0].name + "<br>" +
  pessoas[1].county + " " + pessoas[1].name + "<br>" +
  pessoas[2].country + " " + pessoas[2].name;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Mostrar</button>
```

Comment: Apesar de ser bom questionamento, acho que tem uma visão errada de função auto invocada, nenhuma dessas do seu exemplo são, veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13365/14262

Comment: Uhm, tem razão @MarceloBonifazio. Eu quis dizer que a função que serve como argumento do método pessoas.sort() é uma função auto invocada. Obrigado pela correção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ter parametros opcionais é comum em vários métodos nativos, o que é "estranho aqui" é a própria callback de organização ser opcional. Isto [está documentado](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), e caso não seja passada essa callback diz a MDN:

> Se omitido, o array é ordenado de acordo com a potuação de código Unicode de cada um dos caracteres, de acordo com a conversão de cada elemento para string.

Comment: Obrigado! Porem, falta-me uma duvida. Existem valores de parâmetros reservados, e decodificados automaticamente pelo engine do JS? Já vi códigos usando valores id, value etc. Como funciona e quais são?

Comment: @LucasTrino o que queres dizer com _"parâmetros reservados"_? podes dar um exemplo?

Comment: Parâmetros definidos pela própria linguagem. Parâmetros cujo valor é interpretado automaticamente, sem necessidade de declaração, pelo próprio engine JS.

Comment: Segue um exemplo melhor. Analise essa função. Ela possue o parâmetro `atrib`. Ele não foi declarado antes: `function muda(atrib){ document.getElementById('style-8').src = atrib; }`  Porem, quando o uso com um evento `onChange` dessa forma: `onChange="muda(value);"` ele retorna o valor do atributo `value` para o atributo `src` do elemento com `id` igual a "style-8. Minha duvida é essa. Esse parâmetro `atrib` é definido na própria linguagem? Existem outros, e quais são eles?

Comment: @LucasTrino não tenho a certeza se percebi. Mas em JS todos os nomes das variáveis parametro de funções podem ser o que quiseremos. No teu exemplo `atrib` podia ser `birta` ou outra coisa qualquer. Algumas funções têm parametros predefenidos, como a callback de `addEventListener` que vai receber o objeto do evento como primeiro argumento. Dito isso há algumas "variáveis" pré-defenidas: `this` e `arguments`. Essas sim são inseridas "mágicamente" pelo JavaScript e associadas ao escopo da função. Era isso que procuravas?

Comment: Sim, exato. Muito obrigado. Sempre que precisar pegar o valor de um atributo de um elemento qualquer, posso simplesmente colocar o nome do atributo no argumento da função como no exemplo acima?

Comment: @LucasTrino podes dar um exemplo?