# O que há de errado com o código? exercício com vetor e comparação de valores

Tags: javascript

No código abaixo quero escolher alguns números e por eles em um vetor, o usuário ira tentar advinha-lós e seus lance ou chutes irão ser guardados em outro vetor e no fim irei informar ao usuário quantos números ele acertou, criei esse código porém não roda de forma alguma, e o console do navegador não reporta nada. Qual o problema do código?

```
>  <input type="text" id="numero" />
>     <input type="submit" value="lance" id="verificar"/>
>     <script>
>     var loteria = [1,6,3]
>     var sorteados = []
>     var lance = document.getElementById("numero")
>       var botao = document.getElementById("verificar")
>           botao.onclick = clicado
>           var clicado = function() {
>               var aux=0       
>                   sorteados.push(lance)
>                   for (var i = 0;i<loteria.legth;i++){
>                       if(lance.value == loteria[i]){
>                           aux++
>                           return
>                       }   
>                   }
>               if (sorteados.legth == 3){
>               alert ("voce acertou"+aux)
>               }
>           }
>     </script>
```

Comment: Ver https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13364/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-as-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-var-name-function-e-function-name