# Diferença entre exportar uma função e uma IIFE no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funções, módulo-ecmascript

Existe alguma diferença entre:

```
module.exports = (function() {
  // Code.
})();
```

E:

```
module.exports = function() {
  // Code.
};
```

Levando em conta o contexto de exportação e importação de módulos?

Comment: Os `()` após a função significa que ela será executada imediatamente após a sua declaração.

Comment: Isso cria alguma diferença no contexto de exportação e importação de módulos?

Comment: Nesse contexto eu não sei explicar. :(

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13364/70

Comment: Não. Eu já sei isso. Só quero saber se há alguma diferença entre as duas no contexto de módulos (exportação e importação), como disse no comentário acima... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não muda nada no "contexto de exportação e importação de módulos". O que realmente irá mudar, entre os dois exemplos, é o **valor** que será exportado.

No primeiro exemplo:

```js
module.exports = (function() {
  // Code.
})();
```

Veja que temos uma [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript), o que significa que ela será executada logo após a sua declaração. Desse modo, o valor exportado pelo `module.exports` será o valor que for retornado por ela. Desse modo:

```js
module.exports = (function() {
  return 'Luiz Felipe';
})();
```

O módulo em questão exportaria o valor `'Luiz Felipe'`, e não uma função.

No entanto, na maioria das vezes, isso é completamente desnecessário, já que o escopo dos módulos é privado para outros arquivos, então não há realmente nenhuma necessidade em exportar um valor envolto por uma IIFE no Node.js.

---

No outro caso:

```js
module.exports = function() {
  // Code.
};
```

O módulo iria exportar a função propriamente dita, e não o valor retornado por ela. Para obter o seu retorno, você precisaria de executá-la após importá-la, utilizando o `require`.