# Qual é a finalidade de definir o nome de uma função que é atribuída a uma variável?

Tags: javascript

Estava dando uma olhada em alguns posts aqui no site e me deparei com está pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13364/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-var-name-function-e-function-name). Pois bem, na resposta aceita foi explicado a declaração de **expressões de funções**, *anônimas, nomeadas e autoinvocada*. Causando minha dúvida na função nomeada. Para que serve o nome da função se o valor do `return` está no nome da variável e não no nome da função. Qual o propósito de se nomear uma função que está dentro de uma variável?

```
//expressão anônima de função
var a = function() {
  return 3;
}

//expressão nominada de função
var a = function bar() {            // dúvida para que serve bar
  return 3;
}

//expressão "autoinvocada" de função
(function digaOi() {
   alert("Oi!");
})();
```

Comment: Ao meu ver é uma "Possível" duplicata pois acredito que a resposta linkada já explique a diferença na parte *Exemplo de visibilidade de escopo* e no meu entendimento ao invés de abrir uma pergunta você poderia comentar na resposta, mas é só minha opinião, para ela ser considerada duplicata precisa do voto de outros usuários.

Comment: Sim eu vi *Exemplo de visibilidade de escopo*, acontece que ainda não entendi. Lá está no exmplo ** var funcaoDois = function banana() { banana() }** certo? Apenas chamou banana, como faço para trabalhar com a função **banana**. Posso fazer assim:  **var funcaoDois = function banana() { banana() { console.log("Alguma coisa")}.  }**. Isto foi que gerou minha dúvida.

Comment: Da uma lida nas outras respostas do mesmo link elas se complementam.

Comment: Curiosamente foi feita a mesma pergunta ontem, por outro usuário. Marquei como duplicata da mesma pergunta que apontei no caso de ontem, avise aqui se o conteúdo que tem lá (+ as respostas daqui) não resolverem sua dúvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria por uma questão de escopo, onde a função `bar()` só é acessível dentro de `a`.

A função `a` recebe um outro nome `bar` que só é visível dentro de `a`:

```
var a = function bar() {
  // bar é visível aqui
  return 3;
}
// bar NÃO é visível aqui
a();   //  retorna 3
bar(); // erro: bar is not defined
```

Não vejo muita utilidade em criar um segundo nome para a mesma função e este último com escopo limitado.

Veja neste exemplo que tanto faz chamar `a` quanto `bar` o efeito é o mesmo:

```js
var x = 0;
var a = function bar(){
   console.log(x);
   // setTimeout(a, 2000);
   // ou
   setTimeout(bar, 2000);
   x++;
}

a();
```

Comment: Então, continuo sem entender muito bem. As chaves aí no caso delimitam qual função, **a** ou **bar**?  Como eu utilizo **bar** no seu segundo exemplo? Posso fazer **var a = function bar() { bar(){ console.log("Testando")}**?

Comment: Estou editando a resposta para ficar mais claro.

Answer (score 2):

Como foi comentado na pergunta que citou - e na resposta do @dvd, há a diferença entre os escopos. Quando você faz:

```
var a = function bar() {
    // ...
}
```

Dentro da função existirá a referência à própria função `bar`, algo que na função anônima não existirá.

```
var a = function () {

}
```

Como poderia ser possível referencia algo sem nome? Mas e por quê não pelo próprio objeto `a`? Bom, a função é a própria definição de `a`, o que implica que dentro da mesma o objeto `a` não esteja definido.

E por quê definir o nome é útil? Bom, a solução mais simples que poderia utilizar esta técnica é definir uma função recursiva como *callback* de um evento:

```js
function myEvent(callback, n) {
  return callback(n);
}

const result = myEvent(function fatorial(n) {
  return (n == 0) ? 1 : n * fatorial(n-1)
}, 5);

console.log(result)
```

> **Nota:** repare que ao fazer
>
> ```js
>  
>  var a = function bar() {}
>  
> console.log(a.name)
> ```
>
> O valor de `a.name` será `bar`, não `a`.

Comment: Entendido Anderson.