# O que seria este .f em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, funções

Dando uma olhada em um tutorial sobre JavaScript me deparei com o seguinte trecho de código:

```js
let user = {
  name: "John"
};

function sayHi() {
  console.log(`Hello ${this.name}`);
}

user.f = sayHi;  // dúvida
user.f();  // retorna Hello John
```

Percebi que se retirar o **f** da associação da função ao **`user`** me é retornado `Hello` e o **this.name** é retornado como um *id* ou *hash* ou alguma coisa do tipo aleatoriamente:

```js
let user = {
  name: "John"
};

function sayHi() {
  console.log(`Hello ${this.name}`);
}

user = sayHi;
user();  // retorna Hello ...
```

Então as minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

- o que seria este **`f`**
- como ele associa o objeto a função
- o que seria os valores aleatórios quando não utilizo o **`f`**

Comment: `.f` poderia ser qualquer coisa (ter qualquer valor), é basicamente o mesmo que fazer isto: `let user = {
  name: "John", f: sayHi
};`, mas no caso `.f =` você está setando a propriedade posteriormente. Note que o uso da função `sayHi` é *"referenciado"*, e ele pode ser declarado depois, leia em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/3635 sobre funções.

Comment: ps: Vale lembrar que se passar um objeto por um parâmetro poderá alterar o valor das propriedades em referencia, atualizando o objeto setado no parâmetro, mas isto é outra história.

Comment: Blza @GuilhermeNascimento entendido. Valeu man!

Comment: Parece ser um atributo criado que representaria um novo método: funcao (f)  tipo: `obj.func  = function() { ...}`.  Só uma obs: se você tiver várias instâncias do mesmo objeto, melhor colocar no prototype. Senão cada objeto terá sua própria cópia do método, geralmente é um desperdício de recurso.

Comment: @IvanFerrer certo, no tutorial é abordado sobre isto também.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1°: o que seria este f?**

Nesse exemplo:

```
let user = {
  name: "John"
};

function sayHi() {
  console.log(`Hello ${this.name}`);
}

user.f = sayHi;  // dúvida
user.f();  // retorna Hello John
```

Ao fazer `user.f = sayHi`, você diz pro Javascript: atualiza pra mim a propriedade `f` que está dentro do objeto `user`, caso não haja essa propriedade, crie essa propriedade `f` e atribua à ela o valor `sayHi`, que nesse caso seria uma `função`. Por isso ao user `user.f()`, ele retorna `"Hello"`.

**2°: como ele associa o objeto a função?**

Está na resposta acima, ele cria essa nova propriedade `f` e associa a essa propriedade, a função `sayHi`, no primeiro exemplo. No segundo exemplo, ele sobrescreve a variável `user` com o valor da função `sayHi`.

**3°: o que seria os valores aleatórios quando não utilizo o f?**

Nesse caso você associou ao user, a uma "refêrencia da memória" do `sayHi`, os caracteres aleatórios seriam por causa do `this.name`, que nesse caso não não tem mais referencia, seria um "lixo"*****, porque não existe mais a propriedade `name` no `user`.

***UPDATE**: O [@bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto) explicou o que seria o "hash" ou "lixo":

> O que vocês estão chamando de lixo ou hash é na verdade o name de um
>   elemento HTML (iframe) usado no preview de código aqui . Se isso for
>   executado numa janela normal vai vir undefined. Porque quando você
>   executa uma função fora do contexto de objeto, this dentro dela aponta
>   para a janela.

Comment: Boa resposta man, vou aceitar a do Maniero por uma questão cronológica, ele respondeu um pouco antes, mas, as duas explicam muito bem. Valeu!

Comment: Na verdade a minha foi antes hahah mas de boas, o importante é que te ajudou!

Comment: Kkkk verdade man, agora que vi ;)

Comment: Então @Maniero em cima ele disse que o hash seia uma referência da memória, acho que o último parágrafo que talvez possa ser retirada a palavra hash

Comment: Isto `ele cria uma nova propriedade e associa a essa propriedade` deveria ser `ele cria uma nova propriedade e associa a essa função`? Isto está confuso `nesse caso você teria a função sayHi()`, ele teria a função ou teria o valor retornando por um possivel `return`? Afinal ele está já "executando"

Comment: Hmm certo, vou esperar pra ver se ele edita.

Comment: Editada as correções para evitar partes confusas.

Comment: O que vocês estão chamando de lixo ou hash é na verdade o *name* de um elemento HTML (iframe) usado no preview de código aqui . Se isso for executado numa janela normal vai vir undefined. Porque quando você executa uma função fora do contexto de objeto, `this` dentro dela aponta para a janela.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não quer inserir uma resposta com a sua visão?

Comment: Eu tinha percebido essa diferença mesmo, mas não tinha me ligado nisso, vou editar a resposta com sua contribuição @bfavaretto

Answer (score 5):

> o que seria este f

Um membro de um objeto criado neste momento, como qualquer outro sem nada especial. Ou se preferir é um elemento de um *array* associativo que se passa como objeto, que é o que são objetos em JS. Ele é só uma variável normal dentro de um objeto/*array*, não existe uma característica que o difira de outras coisas, não tem nada mágico nele, é igual ao `name` só que em `name` você guardou uma `string` e em `f` guardou uma função (sim, você pode guardar funções em variáveis). veja mais em [Qual a diferença entre as funções var name = function() e function name()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101).

> como ele associa o objeto a função

A atribuição que está fazendo nesse membro do objeto está fazendo essa associação, está pegando o nome da função (sem parenteses que chamaria a função) e este nome é uma referência para a função efetiva, e está guardando na variável `f` que pertence a `user`.

> o que seria os valores aleatórios quando não utilizo o f

Aí no segundo exemplo aconteceu outra coisa, você redefiniu o objeto `user` completamente e não tem mais o que tinha, ou seja, nem tem o campo `name`, agora `user` só tem a referência para a função `sayHi` e mais nada. Quando chama ele com `user()` está mandando imprimir um elemento que não existe, ou seja `this.name` não existe mais, então pega um valor lixo na memória (no sentido de algo que está lá mas não deveria, na minha opinião). Eu acho que não deveria acontecer esse comportamento, mas é JS, sabe como é.

Isto ocorre porque ali tem uma [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101), mas no caso não tem um valor associado com aquela variável, mas JS tenta sempre dar algum resultado, então ele considera que deve ter algo ali, de fato segundo o comentário do bfavaretto ele acha esse nome no elemento `iframe` que fica exposto (na minha opinião já exposta, indevidamente, mas é assim que o JS é).

Comment: Valeu Maniero, mais uma vez!

Comment: Não é lixo, JS nunca expõe memória (seria grave se fizesse isso). Ver https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/421218/o-que-seria-este-f-em-javascript#comment818688_421221

Comment: @bfavaretto dei uma editada, não quis dizer no mesmo sentido do do lixo de C, apenas algo que não deveria estar disponível, editei, veja se ficou mais claro.

Comment: Entendi, realmente eu achei que estava falando do lixo "clássico" :) Ficou melhor com o edit. Aproveitando o relaxamento de conceitos, tem um certo comportamento indefinido nessas referências a this fora de contextos em que ele faça sentido. No strict mode isso não ocorre, this vira null em vez de apontar pro objeto global.

Comment: Bom saber, ainda não gosto do null, mas já é melhor