# Não consigo incrementar uma variável global em parametro de função

Tags: javascript, funções, parâmetros, variáveis-globais

O que me foi pedido:

- Declare a global variable called counter and assign it 0.
- Declare a function called incrementCounterBy, which receives a parameter called amount. It should increment counter by the amount.
- Declare a function called resetCounter that should set the counter value back to 0.
- Test your counter and have some fun.

E o meu código está assim:

```
var counter = 0;

var incrementCounterBy = function (amount) {    
counter++;
};


var resetCounter = function () {
    setCounter= 0;
};
```

Quando tento correr o código recebo o erro:

> Code is incorrect
>   Make sure you are incrementing the counter by amount

Comment: O que é pedido não é: `counter++;` MAS SIM `counter += amount;`.

Comment: ahh como n vi isso mais cedo? que frustrante n saber interpretar bem o que é pedido!  De qualquer forma, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De fato está errado, porque `counter++` aumenta o valor do `counter` em 1. Mas você não deve aumentar em 1, e sim usar a quantidade que foi informada na função.

E na função `resetCounter` você está atribuindo o valor na variável `setCounter`, e não na `counter`:

```js
var counter = 0;

function incrementCounterBy(amount) {
    counter += amount;
}

function resetCounter() {
    counter = 0;
}

incrementCounterBy(2);
console.log(counter); // 2
incrementCounterBy(5);
console.log(counter); // 7

resetCounter();
console.log(counter); // 0
incrementCounterBy(3);
console.log(counter); // 3
```

Repare também que declarei as funções como `function nome() {...}` em vez de `var nome = function() {...}` (para saber mais sobre a diferença, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/112052)).

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO PELO ESCLARECIMENTO e obrigado pela partilha do link também!!!
por alguma razão as funções só aceitam se levar o var nome = function() {...}
mudei isso e deu certinho,