# Verificar qual array só tem números pares

Tags: javascript, array

Escreva uma função chamada `getValidPassword` que recebe um array bidimensional como parâmetro.

Cada entrada do array representa um *passcode*. Você precisa encontrar o *passcode* que não tem números ímpares e retorná-lo. Exemplo:

```
var loggedPasscodes =[
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [4, 3, 4, 3]
];

getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) // returns the array: [2, 6, 0, 8]
```

---

A minha resolução é esta:

```js
var getValidPassword = function (loggedPasscodes) {
    var passcode;

    for (var i = 0; loggedPasscodes.length > i; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; loggedPasscodes[i].length > j; j++) {

            if(loggedPasscodes[i][j] % 2 == 0) { // even
             passcode = loggedPasscodes[i];
             break;
            }  
        }
    }

return passcode;

};

var loggedPasscodes =[
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [4, 3, 4, 3]
];

console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes));
```

Dá-me o resultado `[4, 3, 4, 3]`, infelizmente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você está saindo do segundo *loop* assim que encontra um número par. Ou seja, se tiver um número par e tiver algum ímpar depois, o número ímpar sequer tem a chance de ser verificado. E se tiver algum ímpar antes, ele está sendo ignorado. Ou seja, você não está detectando se tem números ímpares.

E de qualquer forma, você está percorrendo sempre todos os *passcodes* e retornando o último, independente de só ter números pares ou não (*fazer um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/112052) e [debugar o código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7785/112052) ajudaria a perceber esses problemas*).

---

Para saber se todos os números são pares, você deve verificar se algum é ímpar, e aí sim você pode interromper o *loop*. E você também precisa guardar a informação de que esse número ímpar foi encontrado, caso contrário não terá como saber se o *passcode* satisfaz a condição de só ter números pares.

Outro detalhe é que não precisa fazer `var nomeFuncao = function() {etc}`. Não há vantagem nenhuma em fazer isso ([e nesse caso não faz diferença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/112052)). Não invente e declare a função normalmente usando `function nomeFuncao() {etc}`:

```js
function getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) {
    for (let i = 0; loggedPasscodes.length > i; i++) {
        let passcode = loggedPasscodes[i];
        let temImpar = false;
        for (let j = 0; passcode.length > j; j++) {
            if (passcode[j] % 2 !== 0)  { // ímpar
                temImpar = true;
                // se encontrou um ímpar, sai do loop (não precisa verificar os demais números)
                break;
            }
        }
        if (! temImpar) {
            return passcode; // não tem ímpar, pode retornar direto
        }
    }
};

let loggedPasscodes =[
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [4, 3, 4, 3]
];

console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes)); // [2, 6, 0, 8]
```

O detalhe é que este código vai encontrar o primeiro *passcode* que só tiver números pares (caso tenha mais de um). Se não tiver nenhum, o retorno é `undefined` (e como o enunciado não diz o que fazer neste caso, podemos deixar assim mesmo).

Se quiser **todos** os *passcodes* que satisfazem a condição (e não somente o primeiro), aí você tem que guardá-los em um array e só no final retornar este array:

```js
function getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) {
    let codes = [];
    for (let i = 0; loggedPasscodes.length > i; i++) {
        let passcode = loggedPasscodes[i];
        let temImpar = false;
        for (let j = 0; passcode.length > j; j++) {
            if (passcode[j] % 2 !== 0)  { // ímpar
                temImpar = true;
                // se encontrou um ímpar, sai do loop (não precisa verificar os demais números)
                break;
            }
        }
        if (! temImpar) {
            codes.push(passcode); // não tem ímpar, adiciona nos resultados
        }
    }
    return codes;
};

let loggedPasscodes =[
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [10, 2, 4, 42],
    [4, 3, 4, 3]
];

console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes)); // [ [2, 6, 0, 8], [10, 2, 4, 42]]
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar os métodos [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) e [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
function getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) {
    return loggedPasscodes.find(passcode => passcode.every(n => n % 2 === 0));
};

let loggedPasscodes =[
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [4, 3, 4, 3]
];

console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes)); // [2, 6, 0, 8]
```

`find` retorna o primeiro elemento do array `loggedPasscodes` que satisfaz a condição informada (ou `undefined` se nenhum for encontrado). No caso, a condição é que todos os números de `passcode` sejam pares (é o que `every` verifica, retornando `true` caso todos satisfaçam a condição - se tiver um número ímpar, o retorno é `false`, indicando que o *passcode* não satisfaz a condição).

Se quiser **todos** os *passcodes* que satisfazem a condição (e não somente o primeiro), basta trocar `find` por [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), que retornará um array contendo todos os *passcodes* que satisfazem a condição (ou um array vazio, se nenhum for encontrado):

```js
function getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) {
    return loggedPasscodes.filter(passcode => passcode.every(n => n % 2 === 0));
};

let loggedPasscodes =[
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [10, 2, 4, 42],
    [4, 3, 4, 3]
];

console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes)); // [ [2, 6, 0, 8], [10, 2, 4, 42]]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var getValidPassword = function (loggedPasscodes) {
    var passcode, hasOdd;

    for (var i = 0; loggedPasscodes.length > i; i++)    {
        hasOdd = false;

        for (var j = 0; loggedPasscodes[i].length > j; j++) {

            if(loggedPasscodes[i][j] % 2 !== 0)  { // odd
                hasOdd = true;
                break;
            }  
        }

        if (!hasOdd) {
            passcode = loggedPasscodes[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    return passcode;
};

var loggedPasscodes =[
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [4, 3, 4, 3]
];

console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes));
```