# clearInterval não para a função setInterval

Tags: javascript

Estou estudando as função de temporização no Javascript e não estou conseguindo fazer o setInterval() parar por meio do clearInterval()

```
var timer = function(){
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log(count);
        count++
        }, 200)}



var stop = function(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(timer)
        console.log('executei');        
            }, 2000)
    }
timer()
stop()
```

No console da pra ver que a função stop aparentemente tá executando, mas o timer continua a rodar.

```
index.js:5 1
        index.js:5 2
        index.js:5 3
        index.js:5 4
        index.js:5 5
        index.js:5 6
        index.js:5 7
        index.js:5 8
        index.js:5 9
        index.js:14 executei
        index.js:5 10
        index.js:5 11
        index.js:5 12
        index.js:5 13
        index.js:5 14
        index.js:5 15
        index.js:5 16
        index.js:5 17
```

Comment: var timer tem que receber setInterval, mas está recebendo function.

Answer (score 3):

A função `clearInterval` deve receber o retorno da função `setInterval`, porém como você encapsulou a `setInterval`, acabou passando a função `timer` como parâmetro, logo seu `setInterval` vai continuar a ser executado.

---

Você pode criar uma variável para guardar o retorno do `setInterval`, com isso será possível passar a mesma como parâmetro para a `clearInterval`:

```js
let intervalo = null;

var timer = function(){
    let count = 0;
    intervalo = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(count);
        count++
        }, 200)}

var stop = function(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(intervalo)
        console.log('executei');        
            }, 2000)
    }

timer();
stop();
```

---

Também é possível alterar a função `timer` para retornar o intervalo e a função `stop` para receber o intervalo por parâmetro:

```js
var timer = function(){
    let count = 0;

    const intervalo = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(count);
        count++
        }, 200);

    return intervalo;
}

var stop = function(intervalo){
    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(intervalo);
        console.log('executei');        
            }, 2000);
}

let intervalo = timer();
stop(intervalo);
```

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Answer (score 3):

O valor de `timer` não é um "ID" do return do `setInterval`, é um uma função anonima que você setou:

```
var timer = function(){
```

Não tem como `clearInterval` adivinhar o que tem dentro da função, você tem que pegar o retorno de setInterval e expor em uma variável, algo como:

```js
var interval, count = 0;

var timer = function(){
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(count);
        count++
     }, 200)
};

var stop = function(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(interval)
        console.log('executei');        
    }, 2000)
};

timer()
stop()
```

Na verdade nem precisa ficar declarando uma série de funções, seria melhor jogar em funções diretas:

```js
var interval, count = 0;

function timer(){
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(count);
        count++
     }, 200)
}

function stop() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(interval)
        console.log('executei');        
    }, 2000)
}

timer()
stop()
```

Veja aqui a diferença de [`var funcao = function` e `function funcao()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/3635)