# Como usar recursividade para iterar em array

Tags: javascript, recursão

Estou querendo implementar uma função recursiva que percorra um array e retorne os elementos *(uma alternativa ao loop for para fins didáticos, apenas)*.

Fiz desta forma, mas ele me retorna `undefined` ao fim, já que na última chamada da função ele não cai no `if`. Mas a função recursiva não teria justamente essa finalidade, ter uma condição de saída?

Como poderia melhorar a implementação?

```js
const meuArrayRecursivo = (arr) => {
if (arr.length > 0) {
    let el = arr[0];
    arr.shift();
    return `${el} ${meuArrayRecursivo(arr)}`;
}

//undefined;
};

console.log(meuArrayRecursivo([1, 2]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De fato, em uma função recursiva, é crucial ter uma condição de parada.

Mas o problema é que quando o array tem tamanho zero, ele não entra no `if`, e a função não encontra nenhum `return`. [E nestes casos, a função acaba retornando `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Description).

Então você precisa retornar algo quando o array for vazio. No caso, como você está montando uma string com os elementos, basta retornar uma string vazia:

```js
function meuArrayRecursivo(arr) {
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    let el = arr[0];
    arr.shift();
    return `${el} ${meuArrayRecursivo(arr)}`;
  }
  return ''; // <--- aqui
};

console.log(meuArrayRecursivo([1, 2])); // 1 2
```

Também mudei o código acima para usar uma `function` normal. O uso de *arrow function* aqui não traz vantagem nenhuma - muita gente acha que é a única forma/a "melhor"/mais "moderna", etc, mas na verdade existem algumas diferenças (no exemplo específico não tem, mas há casos em que tem, [veja a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) para mais detalhes - [este link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13365/112052) também é interessante).

---

Detalhe que o [método `shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift), além de remover o primeiro elemento do array, também [retorna este elemento](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift#Return_value), então você poderia fazer assim:

```js
function meuArrayRecursivo(arr) {
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    return `${arr.shift()} ${meuArrayRecursivo(arr)}`;
  }
  return '';
};

console.log(meuArrayRecursivo([1, 2]));
```

Ou assim:

```js
function meuArrayRecursivo(arr) {
    return arr.length ? `${arr.shift()} ${meuArrayRecursivo(arr)}` : '';
};

console.log(meuArrayRecursivo([1, 2]));
```

Comment: Perfeito! 

Ainda tenho muito o que melhorar... mas me ajudou muito! =)