# Comportamento confuso na alteração de valor das variáveis em funções js

Tags: javascript, funções, variáveis

Qual o motivo de `time1` imprimir 3 e `time2` imprimir 2?

```
let gols = 1

const time1 = function () {
    console.log(gols)
    gols = 2
}

gols = 3

const time2 = function () {
    console.log(gols)
}

time1() // 3
time2() // 2
```

Comment: Leia [`O que é um Teste de Mesa? Como aplicá-lo?`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%C3%A9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%C3%A1-lo/220505#:~:text=O%20Teste%20de%20Mesa%20%C3%A9%20um%20processo%20manual%20que%20%C3%A9,l%C3%B3gica%20de%20um%20determinado%20algoritmo.&text=No%20livro%20Treinamento%20em%20L%C3%B3gica,ou%20seja%2C%20efetuar%20um%20teste.)

Comment: O motivo é a ordem que executou os "sets" `gols = algo`

Answer (score 4):

Isso nada tem a ver com *closure*, inclusive essa forma que se espalhou por aí de declarar a função é horrível porque passa a ideia errada do que é aquilo, quando tem uma função simples, use uma função simples, só adicione complexidade quando for necessário. Se fosse uma *closure* o comportamento seria diferente em certos cenários. Sem função anônima fica igual:

```js
let gols = 1

function time1() {
    console.log(gols)
    gols = 2
}

gols = 3

function time2() {
    console.log(gols)
}

time1() // 3
time2() // 2
```

O problema é achar que o código está executando em ordem que você lê.

A execução disso na verdade é assim:

```js
const time1 = function () {
    console.log(gols)
    gols = 2
}

const time2 = function () {
    console.log(gols)
}

let gols = 1
gols = 3
time1() // 3
time2() // 2
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Global.js).

Tudo que está no mesmo contexto é executado junto. Note que as funções acima estão apenas declaradas, elas não são executadas até sua chamada. O contexto global, ou seja, fora de alguma função é uma coisa só e as declarações não são executadas.

A variável `gols` é global. Nada no `let` indica que não seja. Talvez esteja confundindo isso. Ela foi declarada em um contexto global, então ele tem [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) e é visível globalmente. Em qualquer lugar que mude o valor dela afetará tudo.

Então o que acontece aí é que:

- declara uma função
- declara a outra
- declara uma variável `gols` com um valor
- logo em seguida o valor é mudado
- e chama uma das funções. Como internamente essa função faz referência à variável global o valor dela, nesse momento, é usado. E em seguida o valor é alterado. A variável é global, então o valor global é alterado. O próximo acesso à variável em qualquer lugar da aplicação verá esse novo valor.
- depois acessa o valor **global** de novo em outra função.

Esse é só um dos motivos para não usar variável global. Ela não funciona como as pessoas esperam. Há perda do controle de onde ela é alterada. Se em código simples causa confusão imagine em um complexo.

Answer (score 2):

Como disse nos comentários faça um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220474/o-que-%C3%A9-um-teste-de-mesa-como-aplic%C3%A1-lo/220505#:%7E:text=O%20Teste%20de%20Mesa%20%C3%A9%20um%20processo%20manual%20que%20%C3%A9,l%C3%B3gica%20de%20um%20determinado%20algoritmo.&text=No%20livro%20Treinamento%20em%20L%C3%B3gica,ou%20seja%2C%20efetuar%20um%20teste.) para compreender o que programa está fazendo passo a passo.

Nesse teste são quatro colunas Código, gols, saída e comentário, onde:

- **Código:** mostra a linha que está sendo executada.
- **gols:** mostra o valor da variável gols após a execução do **Código**.
- **saída:** mostra a saída no console decorrente ao uso de `console.log()`.
- **Comentário:** um comentário auxiliar do que o código está fazendo.

Cada linha representa um passo do funcionamento do algorítimo:

```
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
| Código                             |   gols   | saída |            Comentário           |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
| let gols = 1                       |     1    |       | declara gols com valor 1.       |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
| const time1 = function () {        |     1    |       | declara a função time1()...     |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
|     console.log(gols)              |     1    |       |    declara o corpo da função.   |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
|     gols = 2                       |     1    |       |    declara o corpo da função.   |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
| }                                  |     1    |       | ...encerra declaração           |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
| gols = 3                           |     3    |       | atribua 3 para gols.            |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
| const time2 = function () {        |     3    |       | declara a função time2()...     |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
|     console.log(gols)              |     3    |       |    declara o corpo da função.   |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
| }                                  |     3    |       | ...encerra declaração           |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
| time1()                            |     3    |       | executa time1()                   |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
|     console.log(gols)              |     3    |   3   |    imprime o valor de gols      |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
|     gols = 2                       |     2    |       |    atribua 2 para gols.         |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
| time2()                            |     2    |       | executa time1()                   |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
|     console.log(gols)              |     2    |   2   |    imprime o valor de gols      |
+------------------------------------+----------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma diferença entre a definição da função e a execução da mesma.

Quando você faz `time1 = function () etc`, está definindo a função. Ou seja, só está dizendo o que ela faz, mas neste momento ela ainda não executa o que está lá dentro ("*função, você deve fazer isso, mas não agora, só quando eu mandar*").

Quando você faz `time1()`, aí sim está executando a função ("*função, sabe aquilo que eu disse que é pra você fazer? Faça agora*").

Então seu código cria a variável `gols` com o valor 1. Depois define a função `time1`, depois muda o valor da variável para 3, depois define a função `time2`.

E só depois você executa `time1`, que imprime o valor de `gols` (que nesse momento é 3), e logo depois muda o valor para 2.

Por fim, você executa `time2`, que imprime o valor de `gols`, que agora vale 2.

---

Só pra constar, você poderia ter declarado como funções normais (`function time1() { etc }`), pois não há ganho nenhum em usar uma *function expression* - nesse caso não faz diferença no resultado, mas tem casos em que faz, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/112052).

E você não está exatamente usando *closures*, [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/112052) e [aqui](https://javascript.info/closure) para entender melhor.