# Como realmente aprender a usar promessas em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Faz um tempo estou tentando aprender a usar promessas e programação assíncrona em JavaScript, mas até agora não tive muito sucesso nisso. Já entendi que existem funções que retornam as tais promessas e que então é possível encaixar um callback no método `then` do objeto retornado. Também sei construir funções que retornam promessas usando a biblioteca `Q.js`.

Meu problema é que não sei como usar as promessas na prática. Sempre que tento vira uma confusão e acabo tendo um monte de `then`'s aninhados e na maioria das vezes nada funciona. Sem falar que é extremamente comum que eu caia em situações do seguinte tipo: preciso de certos dados que são carregados do servidor, essa chamada retorna uma promessa, mas eu preciso dos dados em uma função que é executada logo em seguida.

Na verdade não estou conseguindo pensar do jeito certo com programação assincrona e promessas. É muito natural pensar daquela forma "primeiro acontece isso e em seguida tem que acontecer aquilo", mas parece muito estranho pensar "alguma hora vai acontecer isso e nem sabemos quando vai acabar e precisa acontecer uma outra coisa que depende da primeira". Alguém poderia dar algumas dicas/referências pra pegar o jeito mesmo disso?

Comment: Escrevi um artigo sobre isto https://epxx.co/artigos/nodejs3.html quem sabe ajude.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Na realidade, se seu programa estiver bem estruturado a forma de raciocínio ("primeiro acontece isso e em seguida tem que acontecer aquilo") não é assim tão diferente. Imagine uma função do tipo:

```
function f() {
    var x = prompt("Digite x");
    var y = x * x;
    alert(y);
    console.log("pronto");
}
```

Há 4 instruções sendo executadas, e cada uma delas tem que acontecer depois da anterior. Suponha que você coloque cada uma delas em uma função (nesse caso é *overkill*, mas em geral se uma função é muito grande faz sentido quebrá-la em funções menores, certo?):

```
function f() {
    var x, y;

    function a() { x = prompt("Digite x"); }
    function b() { y = X * x; }
    function c() { alert(y); }
    function d() { console.log("pronto"); }

    a();
    b();
    c();
    d();
}
```

Nesse caso eu me aproveitei do fato que funções definidas dentro de outras [têm acesso às suas variáveis locais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/215). Mas eu poderia também usar o valor de retorno de uma como parâmetro pra outra:

```
function f() {
    function a() { return prompt("Digite x"); }
    function b(x) { return X * x; }
    function c(y) { alert(y); }
    function d() { console.log("pronto"); }

    d(c(b(a())));
}
```

Nesse caso fica feio (pois a chamada é na ordem inversa), mas a sequência em que as operações são executadas é a mesma. Note que o código das funções continua bem organizado e lógico.

Agora, como seria se em vez de ler a entrada do usuário fizéssemos uma requisição via Ajax para obtê-la? E se no final, em vez de mostrar pro usuário fizéssemos uma segunda requisição para enviar ao servidor? Com promessas, tirando a questão do formato de dados o programa continua o mesmo!

```
function f() {
    function a() { return get('/le_valor/'); }
    function b(x) { return x * x; }
    function c(y) { return post('/resultado/', {valor:y}); }
    function d() { console.log("pronto"); }

    return a().then(b).then(c).then(d);
}
```

O fato de que *o computador* vai demorar um pouco entre a execução de cada uma dessas funções não importa - o fato é que elas serão executadas na mesma sequência lógica que você concebeu.

Na prática, é claro que você não vai colocar cada instrução numa função separada, ainda que em princípio isso seja possível (em Q pelo menos - já que ele mistura bem tanto funções síncronas quanto assíncronas). Em vez disso, tudo o que precisa fazer é enxergar em que pontos uma operação assíncrona vai acontecer, e garantir que sua função interna termine justamente nessa operação:

```
function f() {
    function a() { return get('/le_valor/'); }
    function b(x) { 
        var y = x * x;
        return post('/resultado/', {valor:y}); 
    }
    function d() { console.log("pronto"); }

    return a().then(b).then(d);
}
```

Notas:

- Se uma função precisa do resultado de duas ou mais funções, basta misturar o exemplo que usa *closures* com o exemplo que retorna os valores. Exemplo:

  ```
  function f() {
      var x, y;

      function a() { return get('/le_valor/'); }
      function b(data) { 
          x = data;
          y = x * x;
          return post('/resultado/', {valor:y}); 
      }
      function d() { console.log("O quadrado de " + x + " é " + y); }

      return a().then(b).then(d);
  }
  ```

  Você *poderia* em vez disso usar um `then` aninhado, mas na minha opinião fica mais difícil de entender o código (como você já percebeu):

  ```
  function f() {
      function a() { return get('/le_valor/'); }
      function b(x) { 
          y = x * x;
          return post('/resultado/', {valor:y}).then(function() {
              console.log("O quadrado de " + x + " é " + y);
          }); 
      }

      return a().then(b);
  }
  ```
- Se uma outra função qualquer precisa executar depois de `f`, não tem problema: como ela *também* retorna uma promessa, pode-se usá-la normalmente (desde é claro que no mesmo estilo):

  ```
  function g() {
      function a() { /* faz algo */ }
      function b() { /* faz algo - em seguida, tem que chamar f */ }
      function c() { /* faz algo - tem que ser executada depois de f */ }
      a().then(b).then(f).then(c);
  }
  ```

  ou:

  ```
  function g() {
      function a() { /* faz algo */ }
      function b() { 
          /* faz algo */ 
          return f();
      }
      function c() { /* faz algo - tem que ser executada depois de f */ }
      a().then(b).then(c);
  }
  ```

  Esse segundo estilo é o ideal se `b` precisa passar parâmetros para `f`. `b` precisa ser síncrona, entretanto. Caso contrário, pode-se usar a estratégia dos *closures* como na nota anterior.
- Em linguagens que suportam o conceito de [***continuations***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation), esse tipo de estruturação do programa não seria necessário - poderia-se ter uma função normal, em que uma chamada assíncrona no meio dela parasse tudo o que o computador estava fazendo, salvasse a pilha de execução e todos os seus dados, e quando a chamada completasse continuasse a execução como se a interrupção nunca tivesse acontecido. Seria o equivalente a uma chamada blocante (*blocking call*), mas que poderia ser executada em um único *thread*.

  Há quem tenha interesse de programar dessa forma em JavaScript, mesmo sem o suporte da linguagem ([exemplo](http://matt.might.net/articles/by-example-continuation-passing-style/)). Mas no fim das contas, acaba ficando uma estruturação feia, não muito diferente das chamadas com *callback*. O uso de promessas é, na minha opinião, um meio mais elegante de se resolver o problema da assincronicidade.
- [Esse artigo](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/) (em inglês) dá mais exemplos do uso prático do Q. Queria cobrir mais dele aqui, mas a resposta já está por demais extensa... Vou parando por aqui, espero que tenha esclarecido um pouco o raciocínio por trás do uso de promessas, e mostrado que não é tão difícil quanto parece à primeira vista.

Comment: Wow! Até eu que não me dou muito bem com JS entendi :o

Comment: Muito bom o passo-a-passo, muito didático.

Comment: 5 dias procurando uma explicação deste tipo. O SO deveria ter um botão pra fazer "Donations" pra quem provê respostas como essas. Parabéns e obrigado!

Answer (score 12):

Voce pode pensar a promessa como uma implementação do `Design Pattern Remote Proxy`.

Uma promessa é um método de resolução de um valor (ou não) de forma assíncrona de forma natural. Promessas são objetos que representam o valor de retorno que uma função pode, eventualmente, fornecer.

Promessas podem também ser objetos representando uma exceção lançada.

Promessas são extremamente úteis para lidar com objetos remotos onde podemos considerá-los como copias locais (num proxy) para o nossos objetos remotos (`Remote Proxy Pattern`).

Tradicionalmente, O JavaScript usa `Closure`, ou `Callbacks` para responder com dados significativos que não estão disponíveis de forma síncrona, como por exemplo solicitações AJAX - `XHR` após uma página ter sido carregada.

Usado Promessa em vez de depender de um `Callback`  podemos interagir com os dados como se ele já tivesse voltado do servidor, ou seja é exatamente o caso onde temos um  `Proxy` para o objeto.

Callbacks tem sido usado a muito tempo, mas os desenvolvedores sofrem quando usam este mecanismo. Callbacks NÃO fornecem consistência e a sua chamada não é garantida. Além disso eles "roubam" o fluxo de execução do código quando dependendo de outras Callbacks. Eles geralmente deixam o DEBUG incrivelmente difícil.

Em vez de disparar uma função e "rezar" para obter uma execução de callback durante a execução de métodos assíncronos, **as `promessas` oferecem uma abstração diferente e muito mais simples**: Eles retornam um objeto promessa.

Vejamos um exemplo: Um usuário deseja enviar mensagem para um amigo. Podemos escrever as Promessas assim:

```
User.get(fromId)
  .then(function (user) {
    return  user.friends.find(toId);
  }, function (err) {
    // Não encontramos o usuário
  })
  .then(function (friend) {
    return  user.sendMessage(friend, message);
  }, function (err) {
    // Não consegui enviar a mensagem
  })
  .then(function (success) {
    // Mensagem enviada
   }, function (err) {
     // Ocorreu um erro inesperado
   });
```

Este código é muito mais legível que um correspondente usando callbacks e podemos garantir que o retorno resolverá para um único valor, em vez de ter que lidar com  interfaces de callback.

O tratamento de erro também é muito mais natural com Promessas, pois manipulamos o `sucesso` e o `erro` de uma maneira análoga.

É isso, espero ter esclarecido.

Comment: Achei muito boa a comparação e a citação das vantagens sobre as *callback's*.