# Ordem de execução não é seguida

Tags: javascript, dexie

Estou usando esta biblioteca para executar funções IndexedDB mais facilmente:

## [Dexie](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js)

Porém o código não segue de forma nenhuma a ordem de execução e isso faz com que meu *script* não funcione.

## Exemplo

Este código é só um exemplo para mostrar que ele não segue a ordem de execução, onde podem observar a consola do navegador enquanto fazem *refresh* à página:

Ver no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ph5ebrw4/).

```
var db = new Dexie('teste');
var atual_sequence = 0;

db.version(1).stores({sequences: '++id,of'});
    
db.open().catch(function(error){
});

db.sequences.where("of").equalsIgnoreCase('0').count(function (count) {
  atual_sequence = count;
  console.warn(atual_sequence);
    
});
db.sequences.add({of: '0'});

console.log('ds: '+atual_sequence);
```

Ele executa o `console.log('ds: '+atual_sequence);` antes de obter o numero de sequência, há alguma maneira de corrigir isto?

Answer (score 3):

Tal como explicado [nessa outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56867/215), o problema é que essa biblioteca está fazendo operações assíncronas, de modo que elas ainda não terminaram de executar no momento que o código posterior é chamado. Uma solução simples e direta seria mover todo o código posterior à chamada assíncrona para o *callback* da mesma:

```
db.sequences.where("of").equalsIgnoreCase('0').count(function (count) {
    atual_sequence = count;
    console.warn(atual_sequence);

    // Movida pra dentro do callback
    db.sequences.add({of: '0'});

    console.log('ds: '+atual_sequence);
});
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/ph5ebrw4/2/). Outra alternativa - se essa solução for deixar seu código muito bagunçado - é usar o `then`, pois a função `count` retorna uma [promessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16921/215) (*Promise*):

```
db.sequences.where("of").equalsIgnoreCase('0').count(function (count) {
    atual_sequence = count;
    console.warn(atual_sequence);
}).then(function() {

    db.sequences.add({of: '0'});

    console.log('ds: '+atual_sequence);
});
```

[Exemplo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ph5ebrw4/3/).