# Executar código apenas depois do setTimeout executar

Tags: javascript

Quero que o código corra normalmente, mas quando o `timeout` chegar o código vai esperar ele realizar pra prosseguir, tipo:

Código normal:

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000); // OPA UM TIMEOUT
alert('continuando'); // só depois do timeout ele da o alert
```

Comment: Isto pode lhe ajudar a entender: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635

Comment: Sugiro [edit] sua pergunta colocando mais **contexto**. Esse é um [problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499/215): você está perguntando sobre sua *tentativa de solução*, e não sobre *o problema real* que você está enfrentando. Se [a raiz do seu problema é outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56863/executar-c%c3%b3digo-apenas-depois-do-settimeout-executar/56867#comment117055_56864), mencione isso na pergunta, assim poderá receber respostas melhores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você possui uma função extensa - seja no *top-level* ou em outra função - e quer que um trecho dela só execute após uma segunda condição seja satisfeita (certo tempo tenha se passado, uma chamada ajax tenha completado, etc), é necessário dividi-la em duas ou mais funções menores. Como o contexto JavaScript num *browser* é essencialmente *single-threaded*, não dá pra "pausar" a execução por um certo tempo, caso contrário a página inteira ficaria "travada".

Ou seja, se você tem um código assim:

```
blá
blá
blá
função assíncrona
blá
blá
blá
```

Você deve transformá-la em algo assim:

```
blá
blá
blá
função assíncrona com callback "meuCallbak"
function meuCallback() {
    blá
    blá
    blá
}
```

Para um exemplo com `setTimeout`, veja [a resposta do silvioprog](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56864/215). Para um exemplo com, digamos, ajax via jQuery:

```
blá
blá
blá
$.ajax(...).done(function() { 
    // Só vai executar depois que a chamada ajax tiver retornado com sucesso
    blá
    blá
    blá
});
```

Etc. Se você quer que certos elementos na interface fiquem inacessíveis enquanto essa ação assíncrona não concluir, você deve desabilitá-los antes de disparar essa ação (o primeiro grupo de "blás") e habilitá-los novamente após o fim dessa ação (o segundo grupo de "blás").

A propósito, se como foi dito em comentário uma resposta "demora em media 3s para chegar", isso não significa que um `setTimeout` de 3s seria correto - pois e quando demorar mais, como é que fica? O ideal seria usar as funções de *callback* da sua API (se é assíncrono, com certeza tem isso em algum lugar, é só achar) e passar para ela esse código que tem que ser executado depois.

Answer (score 5):

Até onde eu sei isso não é possível, pois o `setTimeout()` funciona como uma espécie de *thread*, ou seja, ele é assíncrono. O que você pode fazer é adicionar uma nova função e chamá-la dentro do timeout, algo mais ou menos assim:

```
function outraFuncao() {
  alert("Continuando"); // executou depois do timeout
}

setTimeout(function() {
  alert("Hello");
  outraFuncao();
}, 3000);
```

Essa abordagem em usar uma segunda função é válida e uma das maneiras mais simples de resolver, note que ela é indicada pela [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Outra maneira seria usar uma função de *callback*, mas não vi necessidade em indicar uma abordagem um pouco mais complexa para resolver algo tão simples. =)

Comment: o codigo que mostrei na questao é apenas exemplo, no meu codigo original ele já esta dentro de uma funçao que nao poderia chamar outra por causa do contexto de tudo, esse callback como funcionaria? Obrigada!

Comment: Então, se você já possui a função, poderia chamá-la tranquilamente. Algum motivo especial para não fazê-lo dessa forma? Sobre o callback o setTimeout() já usa um, quando você declara "setTimeout(function() {", essa funcion anônima é um callback. Qualquer coisa posta parte do teu código original para a gente tentar ajudar.

Comment: +1 Só um comentário sobre esse "funciona como uma espécie de *thread*": embora de fato esse código seja assíncrono, ele vai executar no *thread* principal. Isso significa que - assim como todo código na página - enquanto ele estiver executando nada mais vai executar (isso fica evidente caso você demore pra fechar o `alert`, note que nada mais acontece nesse meio tempo, ainda que você possua mais de um `setTimeout` e o intervalo deles já tenha expirado).

Comment: Bem lembrado @mgibsonbr. =)

Comment: Bom veja meu problema: Tenho uma funçao X que é capacitada para ler e tratar um fluxo de dados. Nessa funçao eu executo uma funçao de uma Biblioteca chamada Dexie (postei pergunta dela até) Porém a resposta desta biblioteca demora em media 3s para chegar e sem essa resposta o codigo abaixo dela provavelmente vai funcionar de forma irregular, entende? e é mt codigo que precisa estar reunido.

Comment: @mgibsonbr nao tem como 'arrumar'? pra ele pausar o codigo? :/

Comment: @Elaine, sobre callbacks, há um artigo muito bom que li a um tempo atrás, você pode acessá-lo [aqui](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/). Mas tente resolver chamando a função, parece ser a maneira mais tranquila para fazer.

Comment: Entendi sim. Eu peguei um problema parecido, onde eu tinha um ajax que demorava um certo tempo para processar o pedido do cliente. Resolvi bloqueando os controles da tela e adicionando uma barra de progresso para o cliente, para ele não ficar com a sensação de tela travada. E a barra de progresso pode ser até um GIF, com um círculo girando e um texto "Processando ...". Será que essa não seria uma outra alternativa?

Comment: nao por que o codigo seria executado.. teria que seguir a ordem mesmo..

Comment: Tem outra forma de resolver. Faz o seguinte, declara uma variável "flag = false", daí você usa um while que fica aguardando esse flag ser true, que quem o colocará para true será o setTimeout(). Conseguisse captar a ideia? Algo +- [assim](http://www.sean.co.uk/a/webdesign/javascriptdelay.shtm).

Comment: @silvioprog Se isso for feito, o `setTimeout` não vai ser chamado nunca... :P

Comment: Então @mgibsonbr, só que ela chama o `setTimeout()` antes desse _sleep_ que ela está tentando fazer, então é bem capaz de dar certo. Eu precisava fazer um teste aqui, mas tem grandes chances de funcionar, conforme explicaram [nesse link](http://www.sean.co.uk/a/webdesign/javascriptdelay.shtm) ...

Comment: @silvioprog [Te garanto que não funciona!](http://jsfiddle.net/3z2L74x1/) Esse link é uma *péssima* prática, não use. No caso ele funciona, mas só porque dentro do loop se muda a condição para sair do loop (se não mudasse, entraria num loop infinito; veja meu exemplo acima - vai parecer que o *browser* travou, aguarde uns 20s).

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu vi lá, rapaz, se a Elaine usar essa abordagem ela estará entrando no território da gambiarra rs... Mas fica a dica para outro programador não cair em armadilha assim. Acredito que vale a pena ela tirar um tempo e tentar refatorar o código, para enfim chamar daquela maneira que explicamos a ela. Faz um esforço aí Elaine. =)