# Como funciona o $.when() e o .then() alinhados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Em meus estudos de **javascript com framework Jquery**, venho me deparando diversas vezes com `$.when()` e `.then()` alinhados. Gostaria de saber como os mesmos funcionam juntos. um exemplo que me deparei foi o código abaixo.

```
$.when(loadView, setData).then(
  function(loadViewResult, setDataResult) {
    // lógica
  }, 
  function(erro) {
    console.log(erro);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esse código é baseado em [promessas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16929/74) (*promises*, implementadas no jQuery como [`$.Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)). Uma promessa é um objeto que representa o resultado de uma [operação assíncrona](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) (o caso mais comum é uma requisição Ajax), mesmo que ela ainda não tenha sido completada.

No seu código, você tem duas promessas, uma chamada `loadView`, e outra `setData`. O `$.when` recebe as duas como parâmetros, e retorna uma outra promessa que só será considerada resolvida quando **ambas** estiverem resolvidas. E as funções passadas ao `then` serão executadas quando essa terceira estiver resolvida – ou seja, quando as promessas passadas ao `when` estiverem todas resolvidas. A primeira função passada ao `then` executa em caso de sucesso das duas operações assíncronas, e recebe os resultados delas como parâmetros. A segunda executa em caso de erro, ou seja, se alguma das duas promessas for rejeitada.

Comment: Ei, calma, não precisa aceitar minha resposta tão rápido :) Veja se aparece algo melhor, eu ando sem tempo pra produzir explicações mais detalhadas...

Comment: Nota do moderador: eu excluí os comentários que havia ali em cima porque ficaram obsoletos depois da sua edição. Mas não achei que nenhum era hostil (acho que sei de qual você está falando). Pense assim, não eram comentários apontando o dedo pra você, um era um esclarecimento, e o outro uma piada (que era geral, não estava tirando onda de você).