# Pra que serve o Deferred Object no jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Estou estudando um pouco de jQuery e achei [isso](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) interessante.

O problema é que não entendi muito bem.

Pra que serve o Deferred Object no jQuery?

Como isso pode se tornar útil quanto a utilização do jQuery?

Comment: Existe cá uma resposta que fala sobre este método, e alguns exemplos, vou procurar e se achar coloco o _link_.

Comment: Adiantando, os _deferred object_ consistem numa série de _callbacks_ executados em série, e funcionam como fileiras, um não é executado enquanto outro não tiver terminado.

Comment: Uma resposta explicativa - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82363/como-funciona-o-when-e-o-then-alinhados

Comment: E podes também usar isto para ver outros exemplos - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%24.when%22

Comment: Existe também esta pergunta, que acredito ser a mesma dúvida - http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16921/como-realmente-aprender-a-usar-promessas-em-javascript/16929#16929

Answer (score 1):

**Para que serve?**

Ele server para tratamento de processamento assíncrono. Por exemplo:

```js
   var timer;
(function process() {
$('#output').html('Estou carregando angula coisa…');
var deferred = $.Deferred();

/* Aqui vc define um tempo de notificacao no caso 1 segundo */
timer = setInterval(function() {
    deferred.notify();
}, 1000);

/* Esse timeout simula o tempo de resposta */
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    deferred.resolve();
}, 10000);

return deferred.promise();
})().then(function() { 
/* Esse cara é chamado quando termina o processamento assíncrono */
$('#output').html('Terminei de carregar. Agora vou fazer algo!!!'); 
}, null, function() { 
/* Esse cara é notificado a cada segundo enquanto o processamento não for finalizado */
$('#output').html($('#output').html() + '.'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output" />
```

Neste exemplo temos uma rotina que e executada por determinado tempo. Essa rotina pode ser comparada com o carregamento de uma pagina via js. Imagina que você precise baixar um arquivo em forma de json de uma pagina qualquer. Ao terminar você precisará executar algo. Existe a possibilidade de você efetuar o tratamento síncrono, mais ai pode ocorrer a mensagem abaixo que pode mudar de navegador para navegador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Quando utilizar?**

Você deve utilizar sempre que alguma rotina do sistema for tratada de forma assíncrona e você precisa do retorno da página para efetuar um tratamento especifico. Por exemplo, no load de uma imagem via js ou até mesmo no load de outro js que necessite ser de forma assíncrona.

Comment: Excelente, maravilhoso :)