# O que são promises (promessas) em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promises

Estava pesquisando sobre [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/129) em JavaScript quando achei esta questão:

> [Como realmente aprender a usar *promises* (promessas) em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16921/como-realmente-aprender-a-usar-promessas-em-javascript)

Mas afinal :

- O que são promessas?
- Para que servem?

Comment: Não sei se a tag deve ser _promessas_ ou _promises_ :)

Comment: Por ser terminologia comum desse contexto, eu prefiro _promises_ na tag do que promessas.

Comment: Sugestão: deixa a tag como *promessas* (já que aqui é o SO**Pt**) e faz *promises* ser seu sinônimo.

Comment: Imagine que promises são callbacks com esteróides. Depois leia os textos.

Comment: No dia que for JavaEscrita, podemos falar de Promessas: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Promises do javascript é uma implementação da idea de Futures da programação funcional.

Tem se tornando a forma padrão de se trabalhar com código assíncrono em javascript.

Um objeto promise guarda a promessa de que a função que gerou ele irá em algum momento no futuro terminar e te retornar um resposta. Ela pode ser uma resposta positiva ou negativa. O promise pode ser passado para outras funções ou retornado.

Existe hoje várias implementações de promise para javascript. Todas acabam seguindo essa [especificação](https://promisesaplus.com/).

As vantagens de utilizar promises e não callbacks é que você evita callback hells e cascatas de callback que deixam o código difícil de ler e entender.

**EDIT:** Coloquei um exemplos mais pertinentes que mostram o potencial de promises quando tem vários níveis de callback.

Ex com callback.

```
function isUserTooYoung(id, callback) {
    openDatabase(function(db) {
        getCollection(db, 'users', function(col) {
            find(col, {'id': id},function(result) {
                result.filter(function(user) {
                    callback(user.age < cutoffAge)
                })
            })
        })
    })
}
```

O nível de aninhamento pode se tornar muito maior que isso...e vai ficando cada vez mais complicado de entender.

com promises seria assim:

```
function isUserTooYoung(id) {
    return openDatabase(db)
        .then(getCollection)
        .then(find.bind(null, {'id': id}))
        .then(function(user) {
            return user.age < cutoffAge;
        });
}
```

Cada função faz apenas o que ela deve fazer e não precisa se preocupar em chamar callback ou saber o que a função que chamou ele está esperando.

Comment: @Guilherme Lautert , Como posso melhorar minha resposta para que ela seja aceita? Quais detalhes você acha que ficaram de fora?

Answer (score 24):

Promises (ou Promessas) são uma abstração utilizada para representar fluxos de ações em código assíncrono, sendo que em JavaScript uma `Promise` é um objeto que representa o resultado de uma operação assíncrona, podendo este resultado ser bem sucedido (gerado pela chamada da função `resolve` e que desencadeia a chamada do método `then`) ou mal sucedido (gerado pela chamada da função `reject` e que desencadeia a chamada do método `catch`). Um exemplo simples para ilustrar o conceito:

```js
// Aqui criamos uma Promesa que será "resolvida" após o disparo do timer
// (1 segundo)
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body').append('Timer executado<br>');
    resolve();
  }, 1000);
});

// a função anônima passada como parâmetro para ".then" representa a ação que
// será realizada quando nossa promessa for resolvida/cumprida
p.then(function() {
  $('body').append('Promise resolvida<br>');
});

$('body').append('Texto qualquer<br><br>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/es6-promise/3.1.2/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Nesse exemplo `setTimeout` é uma operação assíncrona que é transformada em uma `Promise` e atribuída a variável `p`. Assim nós temos a variável `p` que representa a promessa de alguma operação que eventualmente vai ocorrer, e neste caso ela ocorre após o tempo estipulado no timer, 1 segundo / 1000 milisegundos, momento em que é feito append da string `"'Timer executado<br>'"` e a Promise é finalizada|completa|resolvida através da chamada da função `resolve`, disparando assim o método `then` que executa a função de append da string `"Promise resolvida"`.

Quanto a utilidade de Promises, esta se encontra na sua capacidade de representação de fluxo assíncrono de uma maneira compreensível para o desenvolvedor. Como exemplo veja como é o modo "tradicional/antigo" para representar tal fluxo em javascript:

```
algumaFnAsync(function() {
    outraAsyncFn(function() {
        maisUmaAsyncFn(function() {
           // código que faz algo após todas
           // as operações assíncronas terem completado
        });
    });
});
```

Você tem funções assíncronas que recebem uma função anônima como parâmetro, sendo que esta função será executada quando a tal função assíncrona terminar sua execução. Não é difícil enxergar o problema aí, em séries de códigos assíncronos que precisam ser executados um após o outro você acaba com vários níveis de aninhamento, o chamado [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) (não encontrei uma boa ref em PT). Promises resolvem esse problema, veja como o exemplo anterior poderia ser reescrito com o uso delas:

```
algumaFnAsync().then(function() {
    return outraAsyncFn();
}).then(function() {
    return maisUmaAsyncFn();
}).then(function() {
    // código que faz algo após todas  as operações assíncronas terem completado
});
```

O código é mais claro na sua intenção e a representação é bem mais próxima de um fluxo síncrono onde você tem "faça isso, depois isso, depois aquilo". Embora sejam uma abstração não trivial promises são uma boa solução para o problema que é a representação de fluxo assíncrono em código.

Answer (score 8):

Uma promessa é uma “caixa” (formalmente, no JavaScript, um *objeto*) que encapsula um valor que será obtido a partir de uma operação assíncrona. Geralmente esse valor advém de operações de I/O, que costumam ser assíncronas.

A promessa, como o próprio nome diz, “promete” *eventualmente* fornecer um valor, num momento *desconhecido* em relação à criação da promessa. Como o recebimento desse valor ocorre em um momento **futuro** em relação à criação da promessa, é necessário utilizar de algum meio para executar algum código quando a promessa tiver sido “finalizada” para que se possa acessar o valor obtido pela operação assíncrona.

O meio mais comum de receber essa “notificação de finalização da promessa” é utilizar o método `then`, que executa um *callback* mediante a **resolução** da promessa. Também existe o método `catch`, executa um *callback* mediante eventuais **rejeições** da promessa.

Desse modo, promessas são um tipo de estruturas que permitem “encapsular” operações assíncronas no JavaScript. São bem mais declarativas que *callbacks*, que era o meio anterior utilizado para gerenciamento desse tipo de operação no JS. Há quem diga que promessas são um primitivo para a manipulação de operações assíncronas.

Um exemplo:

```js
// Nesse exemplo, a função `readFileString` retorna uma promessa que contém uma string.
// Na notação do TypeScript, o tipo desta promessa seria `Promise<string>`.
// Isto é, quando for resolvida, a promessa fornecerá uma string.
readFileString('./foo.txt')
  .then((fileContents) => {
    // `fileContents` é a string resolvida pela promessa.
    console.log('Conteúdo do arquivo:', fileContents);
  })
  .catch((ioError) => {
    // Eventualmente, a promessa também pode ser rejeitada:
    console.error(ioError);
  });
```

As promessas foram introduzidas nativamente no JavaScript na edição ECMAScript 2015 (ES6). Há *[polyfill](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise)* disponível, embora a maioria dos *browsers mainstream* suportem essa construção nativamente.

---

### Os estados de uma promessa

Uma promessa pode ser vista como uma máquina de estados. Nesse sentido, é relativamente simples, possuindo apenas três estados:

[image: Diagrama de estados de uma promessa]

Quando a promessa é criada, assume-se imediatamente o estado **`pending`**. Eventualmente, a promessa pode ser “finalizada”, passando para um de dois estados:

- **`fulfilled`**, quando a promessa é **resolvida** (na maioria das vezes com algum valor). Isso geralmente corresponde a uma operação realizada sem erros.
- **`rejected`**, quando a promessa é **rejeitada** (na maioria das vezes com algum erro). Isso geralmente corresponde a uma operação que encontrou algum erro.

Diz-se, também, que a promessa está **`settled`** quando está no estado `fulfilled` ou `rejected`. A partir de agora, trataremos promessas “finalizadas” como promessas *settled*.

Uma promessa só pode tornar-se *settled* (resolver-se ou rejeitar-se) uma **única vez**, haja vista que os estados `fulfilled` e `reject` são *finais*. Isto é, não é possível retroceder desses estados para o `pending`. A direção das setas no diagrama acima também salienta a impossibilidade do retrocesso ao `pending`.

---

### Utilizando promessas

Existem três principais meios para se utilizar uma promessa:

1. Encadeamento.
2. Utilizar a sintaxe de `async` e `await`.
3. Aninhamento (não recomendado; polui visualmente o código e dificulta a compreensão).

#### Encadeando promessas

Como vimos acima, qualquer promessa possui métodos como `then` ou `catch`, que são utilizados, respectivamente, para tratar a resolução e rejeição da promessa.

O interessante é que, de dentro do *callback* passado a esses métodos, pode-se **retornar** um valor, o qual será utilizado pelo método (`then` ou `catch`) para criar uma *nova* promessa, que por ele será retornada. Isso torna possível o encadeamento de vários `then`s e vários `catch`es.

Isso se deve à natureza relativamente “[pura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)” das promessas, que, embora [não sejam totalmente monádicas](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/94), permitem composição e encadeamento, fatores que advém da programação funcional, uma das inspirações para a promessa no JS.

Sem mais delongas, um exemplo:

```js
const username = 'lffg';

// `fetch` retorna uma promessa, do tipo `Promise<Response>`:
fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`)
  .then((response) => {
    // Note que, de dentro deste `then`, estamos retornando o resultado do método
    // `Response.prototype.json`, que converte a `Response` (resultado da promessa
    // anterior) em JSON.
    // O método `json` também retorna uma promessa.
    return response.json();
  })
  // <------------------------------- Note o encadeamento.
  .then((json) => {
    return json.public_repos; // Deste `then`, retornamos número de repositórios do usuário.
  })
  // <------------------------------- Note o encadeamento.
  .then((repoCount) => {
    console.log(`O usuário pesquisado possui ${repoCount} repositórios.`);
  })
  // Por fim, encadeamos um `catch` para tratar eventuais rejeições.
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Houve algum erro: ' + error.message);
  });
```

Esse encadeamento é *sempre* possível, haja vista que:

- Se o *callback* passado ao `then` ou `catch` retornar uma promessa, o `then` (ou `catch`) fará o “aplainamento” (do inglês, *flat*) da promessa, de modo a retornar uma promessa de “profundidade” 1.
- Se o *callback* passado ao `then` ou `catch` retornar uma promessa, o `then` (ou `catch`) fará com que esse valor seja envolvido em uma promessa.

Mais detalhes em [`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) e em [`Promise.prototype.catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch).

#### Utilizando `async` e `await` para *aguardar* promessas

O `async` é uma anotação que pode ser utilizadas para marcar funções como [assíncronas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Dentro de funções assíncronas, é possível utilizar o operador [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Essa construção sintática foi introduzida no ECMAScript 2017 (ES8). Portanto, em alguns ambientes, pode não ser possível utilizá-la sem um processo de transpilação.

O `async`/`await` tem se tornado extremamente comum já que, para muitas pessoas, tende a tornar a programação assíncrona utilizando promessas de um pouco mais fácil compreensão.

Isso porque o `async`/`await` dão a aparência de *sincronismo*, uma vez que, dentro da função assíncrona, o `await` **bloqueia** a execução até que a promessa seja *settled*.

- No caso da promessa ser resolvida, o `await` desbloqueará a execução e avaliará para o valor resolvido pela promessa.
- No caso da promessa ser rejeitada, o `await` desbloqueará a execução e lançará o erro da rejeição.

Como o `await` lança erros em caso de rejeição, é possível utilizar blocos `try`/`catch`, o que torna a sintaxe ainda mais próxima da ideia de sincronismo que alguns programadores têm.

Convertendo o exemplo anterior ao `async`/`await`, temos algo como:

```js
const username = 'lffg';

// Note que o `await` só pode ser utilizado DENTRO de funções assíncronas:
(async () => {
  try {
    // O `fetch` retorna uma promessa. Utiliza-se o `await` para aguardar a finalização.
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`);
    // O método `Response.prototype.json` retorna uma promessa. Portanto, é necessário
    // utilizar o `await`.
    const json = await response.json();

    // Note que como `json` não é uma promessa, não é preciso utilizar o `await`.
    const repoCount = json.public_repos;
    console.log(`O usuário pesquisado possui ${repoCount} repositórios.`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Houve algum erro: ' + error.message);
  }
})();
```

Mais detalhes [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/211505/69296).

---

### Criando uma nova promessa

Uma promessa é criada a partir do construtor `Promise`, presente no escopo global do JavaScript. A esse construtor deve ser fornecida uma função que chama-se **executor da promessa**, que será invocada *imediatamente* após a instanciação da promessa.

A função executora recebe duas funções como parâmetros, comumente chamadas de `resolve` e `reject`. Quando chamadas:

- A função `resolve`, quando chamada, **resolve** a promessa (passando-a para o estado `fulfilled`) com o valor fornecido.
- Já `reject`, quando chamada, **rejeita** a promessa (passando-a para o estado `rejected`) com o valor fornecido. Esse valor é geralmente uma instância de `Error`.

Um exemplo:

```js
// Promessa que será resolvida após 1 segundo de sua criação.
const promiseThatWillFulfill = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('Valor de sucesso, vindo de dentro da promessa.');
  }, 1000);
});

// Promessa que será rejeitada após 2 segundos de sua criação.
const promiseThatWillReject = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject(new Error('Whoops! Algo deu errado, vindo de dentro da promessa.'));
  }, 2000);
});

//
// Utilização de `promiseThatWillFulfill`:
// =======================================

promiseThatWillFulfill
  // O `then` é um método presente em qualquer promessa:
  .then((resolvedValue) => {
    console.log('Promise `promiseThatWillFulfill` resolvida com: ' + resolvedValue);
  })
  // Como o `then` retorna uma outra promessa, pode-se encadear um `catch`,
  // que também é um método de promessa, para realizar a tratativa da rejeição.
  //
  // Nesse caso, no entanto, o `catch` não será executado, já que sabemos que a
  // promessa `promiseThatWillFulfill` não irá ser rejeitada.
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Algo deu errado em `promiseThatWillFulfill`: ' + error.message);
  });

//
// Utilização de `promiseThatWillReject`:
// ======================================

promiseThatWillReject
  // Neste caso, o `then` não será chamado:
  .then((resolvedValue) => {
    console.log('Promise `promiseThatWillReject` resolvida com: ' + resolvedValue);
  })
  // Será rejeitada:
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Algo deu errado em `promiseThatWillReject`: ' + error.message);
  });
```

Na maioria das vezes, no entanto, o programador não utilizará diretamente o construtor `Promise` para criar uma nova promessa. Isso geralmente é feito por criadores de bibliotecas, que desejam implementar a interface das promessas para métodos, funções etc.

Eventualmente, no entanto, o uso desses construtores pode ser utilizado para “adaptar” funções ou métodos antigos que não foram feitos com a interface de promessas, mas sim com [*callbacks*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/69296), que era o meio *antigo* de se lidar com operações assíncronas em JavaScript (em uma época *triste* na qual promessas ainda não existiam nativamente). [Veja aqui como adaptar bibliotecas antigas à interface de promessas.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486272/69296)

## Continuação...

- Esta resposta dá uma ideia geral de promessas. Abaixo estão listadas outras perguntas comuns que já respondi:
- [Como atribuir o valor de uma `Promise` a uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/379215/69296)
- [Como adaptar *callbacks* à interface de `Promise`s?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/486272/69296)