# Promise não retornando valor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promises, axios

Minha requisição esta me retornando isso:

```
data: Promise
```

Abrindo o Developer Tools do Chrome eu vejo isso:

```
data: Promise
__proto__:Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]:"24/01/2016"
```

Usando o axios, como é possível imprimir este valor ?

```
  Lista (url) {
    axios.get(url)
    .then(res => res.data)
    .then(res => this.publicacaoList = res.map( (contato) => ({
      data: axios.get(contato.id_url).then(res => res.data.data_registro).catch(e => console.log(e)),
      email: contato.email,
      tel: contato.tel
    }) )   )
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }
```

Onde contato.id_url é uma url onde eu faço a requisição para buscar a data.
Os campos da tabela de email e tel retornam normalmente, o campo data retorna um objeto vazio {}

Comment: Se dermos uma sugestão com `async/await` tens como compilar?

Comment: Infelizmente não vou conseguir testar, já sai do estagio e a api que eu estava consumindo eu não tenho acesso em casa.
Mas vou continuar estudando javascript e segunda provavelmente vou conseguir resolver isso. Segunda eu volto com a resposta. Muito obrigado por sempre tentar me ajudar @sergio

Comment: Isso dá para resolver com Promises encadeadas, mas com `async/await` é ainda mais fácil. Estás a usar `webpack`?

Comment: Sim, webpack. Estou gostando muito do vue, comprei um ebook hoje (The Majesty of Vue.js 2) e vou tentar ler e praticar esse final de semana, para na proxima semana ser capaz de fazer um CRUD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando fazes `data: axios.get(contato.id_url)` isso var retornar uma promise para `data`, e o que queres é o valor desse ajax. Então tens de resolver esse(s) ajax primeiro e depois setar `data`.

Sugestão:

```js
Lista(url) {
  axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
      const futureData = res.data.map(contato => axios.get(contato.id_url));
      return Promise.all(futureData).then(contactos =>
        this.publicacaoList = contactos.map((data, i) => ({
            data: data,
            email: res.data[i].email,
            tel: res.data[i].tel
          });
        });
    });
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
  })
}
```

Comment: Funcionouuuu, com a correção 

    data: data.data.data_registro

Mas ainda não entendi muito bem promises, vou estudar mais sobre.

Comment: @mtAlves https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119907/129