# Async/Await retornando Promise{<pending>}

Tags: javascript, async

```
const url = 'http://files.cod3r.com.br/curso-js/funcionarios.json'
const axios = require('axios')    

const busca = () =>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            try{
                const funcionarios = axios.get(url).then(resp => resp.data)
                resolve(funcionarios)
            }
            catch(e){
                reject(e)
            }
        })
    }

    async function getFuncionarios(){
        const funcionarios = await  busca()
        return funcionarios
    }

    const fcs = getFuncionarios()
    //fc deveria vir carregado com todos os funcionarios da url, mas só vem o Promise{<pending>}.Simplesmente não tem como ?
```

Comment: Assim como você usou `await` em `await  busca()` você também deveria usar em `const fcs = await getFuncionarios()`, mas o lugar aonde chama também tem que ser async. Você pode usar then também, mas para isso é importante você entender como funciona callbacks https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45706/3635 e entender com funciona os promises: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119907/3635

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, vamos tentar entender certos conceitos.

#### Como criar e usar `Promise`s?

Em JavaScript, quando vai-se criar uma [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) utilizando o construtor padrão, você passa uma função que tem dois parâmetros:

- `resolve`, que é a função a ser chamada quando a `Promise` foi concluída com sucesso, isto é, foi *"resolvida"*;
- `reject`, que é a função a ser chamada quando a `Promise` encontrou um problema e deseja lançar um erro, isto é, foi *"rejeitada"*.

Assim, usando a "API original" das `Promise`s, você lidaria com elas assim:

```js
const myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // Tenta gerar um número aleatório de 1 a 20
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);
  
  // Após 2 segundos...
  setTimeout(function() {
  
    // Se o número gerado for ímpar,
    // "resolve" (conclui) a Promise
    // passando o número gerado
    if (randomNumber % 2 == 1) {
      resolve(randomNumber);
    }
    
    // Se não for ímpar, rejeita a Promise
    // (gera um erro)
    else {
      reject(new Error('even number'));
    }
    
  }, 2000);
});


// Como não sabemos se a Promise vai
// ser concluída normalmente (resolvida),
// ou se ela vai gerar um erro (vai ser
// rejeitada), iremos esperar pelas duas
// coisas!

myPromise
  // Se ela concluir normalmente, mostramos
  // no console o número que ela nos forneceu 
  .then((number) => console.log(number))
  
  // Se ela gerar um erro, nós jogamos
  // esse erro no console também
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Uma coisa a se observar é que, ao invés da chamada encadeada (o [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) seguido do [`.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)), você pode chegar a ver algo assim, também:

```js
myPromise.then(
  (number) => console.log(number),
  (err) => console.error(err),
);
```

Isto é, a passagem da função que lida com o erro, diretamente no `.then()`, que é algo também válido.

A questão do encadeamento se deve ao fato de o `.then()` **também retornar uma `Promise`**. Desse modo, você consegue até fazer isso:

```js
myPromise.then(function (number) {
  return `Number is: ${number}`;
}).then(
  (text) => console.log(text)
);
```

Que seria o mesmo que:

```js
const secondPromise = myPromise.then(function (number) {
  return `Number is: ${number}`;
});

secondPromise.then((text) => console.log(text));
```

Então, recapitulando:

- Para criar uma `Promise` (usando o **construtor padrão**), você deve passar uma função que recebe como argumento:

  - Uma função `resolve`, que será chamada *quando tudo ocorrer corretamente*;
  - E uma função `reject`, que será chamada *quando ocorrer algum problema*.

  Lembrando que, não é necessário ser exatamente esses nomes, isso é só uma convenção para deixar mais compreensível, mais "didático".
- Para esperar pelo resultado de uma `Promise`, usando a API original, você pode simplesmente usar o método `.then()`, para estabelecer as funções que serão chamadas em `resolve` e `reject`, ou você pode usar o `.then()` para estabelecer a função de `resolve` e o `.catch()` para estabelecer a função de `reject`, através do encadeamento;
- E o encadeamento se torna possível, porque o `.then()` também retorna uma `Promise`.

---

Porém, com a utilização dessa API, você pode enfrentar certos problemas na hora de criar funcionalidades que realizam diversas operações assíncronas. Isto é, que utilizam-se de diversas `Promise`s. Vejamos um exemplo:

```js
function getFilteredData(filter) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Eu faço uma requisição a uma suposta API externa de recursos
    const response = fetch('https://example.com/api/resource?filter=' + filter);
    
    // Como o código irá se basear inteiramente na resposta
    // da API, eu irei colocar praticamente todo o código da
    // da função em si, no `.then()` ou no `.catch()`
    response
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then(function (json) {
        Promise.all(
          json.map((piece) =>
            new Promise(function (res, rej) {
              const response = fetch(`https://example.com/api/rating?id=${piece.id}`);
              response
                .then((data) => data.json())
                .then((rating) => res({ ...piece, rating }))
                .catch((e) => rej(e));
            })
          )
        )
        .then((newJson) => resolve(newJson))
        .catch((err) => reject(err));
      })
      .catch((error) => reject(error));
  });
}

const filteredData = getFilteredData('some-filter');

filteredData
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Está vendo a quantidade de encadeamentos que foram feitos? E ainda, o "engarrafamento" que surgiu no código? Claro que, certas coisas (talvez) poderiam ser otimizadas, mas, foi só uma demonstração de como a API das `Promise`s pode deixar as coisas um pouco "complicadas".

Assim, [para facilitar a forma como você lida com `Promise`s, foram criados o `async` e o `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

#### Uso de `async` e `await`

Você [pode ver diversos *posts* aqui no SOpt que também falam sobre eles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=async%20await%20%5bjavascript%5d). Mas, basicamente, podemos dizer que:

- O `async` permite que você marque uma função como uma "realizadora de operações assíncronas" e que, portanto, ela mesma se tornará uma *operação assíncrona*, o que significa que ela irá gerar uma `Promise`. Além disso, marcar uma função com `async` é o que permite a utilização do próprio comando `await`.
- E o comando `await` é o que permite que você *espere* que uma `Promise` seja concluída, para então seguir com um certo código.

Vamos vê-los na prática, utilizando-os para recriar o código acima:

```js
// Marcamos com `async`, então o retorno
// de `getFilteredData` será uma `Promise`
async function getFilteredData(filter) {
  try {
    // Esperamos o resultado da `Promise` gerada por `fetch`
    const response = await fetch('https://example.com/api/resource?filter=' + filter);

    // Esperamos o resultado da `Promise` gerada pelo método `.json()`
    const json = await response.json();
    
    const data = [];
    
    for (const piece of json) {
      // Novamente, esperamos o resultado da `Promise` gerada por `fetch`
      const response = await fetch(`https://example.com/api/rating?id=${piece.id}`);

      // E o resultado da `Promise` gerada pelo método `.json()`
      const rating = await response.json();
      
      data.push({ ...piece, rating });
    }
    
    // Após "tanta espera", retornamos o resultado final
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    // Se um erro foi capturado, iremos lançá-lo novamente
    throw err;
  }
}

const filteredData = getFilteredData('some-filter');

// Falaremos sobre isso mais adiante

filteredData
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Você pode pensar: *espera, se estamos lidando com várias `Promise`s, por que só temos um único bloco `catch` ali?*

A resposta é: porque, nesse caso, quando um erro for gerado, seja qual for a operação que o gerar, a execução normal do código será interrompida. Portanto, seja qual for o ponto que o erro for gerado, ele só será gerado 1 vez, porque todos os outros pontos que podem gerar erro já não serão executados. Vejamos mais de perto:

```js
  try {
    // Se gerar erro, o restante não executa
    const response = await fetch('https://example.com/api/resource?filter=' + filter);

    // Se gerar erro, o restante não executa
    const json = await response.json();
    
    const data = [];
    
    for (const piece of json) {
      // Se gerar erro, o restante não executa
      const response = await fetch(`https://example.com/api/rating?id=${piece.id}`);

      // Se gerar erro, o restante não executa
      const rating = await response.json();
      
      data.push({ ...piece, rating });
    }
    
    return data;
  }
```

Ou talvez, um exemplo funcional:

```js
let fetchFailsCount = 0;

// A cada vez que `fetch` conseguir
// ser chamado e uma nova `Promise`,
// então, for criada, o contador será
// incrementado
function fetch() {
  return new Promise(function(_, reject) {
    fetchFailsCount++;
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject(`Fetch falhou ${fetchFailsCount} vez(es)`);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

(async function () {
  try {
    // Como o primeiro `fetch` gera
    // um erro, o segundo `fetch` não
    // será chamado
    const response1 = await fetch();
    const response2 = await fetch();
    
    console.log('Operações bem-sucedidas!');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Erro: ' + err);
  }
})();
```

Portanto, nesse caso, como só ocorrerá 1 erro durante toda a execução do código da função, só se faz necessário 1 bloco `catch`, capturando, assim, qualquer um dos erros que forem gerados por qualquer uma das operações. Mas, se você quiser lidar com cada erro individualmente, tratando de forma específica, fique à vontade.

Porém, com isso tudo, podemos fazer uma analogia de que o comando `await` "substitui" o `.then()`, e o bloco `try-catch` "substitui" o `.catch()`.

---

Mas aí, pode-se pensar ainda: *e por que, ali no final, não utilizamos o comando `await` também?*

Porque, até onde se sabe, ainda não é totalmente suportada a utilização do `await` de fora de funções assíncronas (aquelas marcadas com `async`). Ou seja:

```js
// Por enquanto, ainda pode gerar um erro
const response = await fetch('http://example.com');
```

Mas, se você quiser realmente utilizar o `await`, você pode envolver a operação em uma função assíncrona *anônima* e, ao mesmo tempo, chamá-la, dessa forma:

```js
(async function () {
  const filteredData = await getFilteredData('some-filter');
})();
```

Funciona como uma alternativa. Mas, [já propuseram trazer isso para o ES](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await). Só não sabemos se será, de fato, implementado e se será logo.

#### Analisando o código e tentando resolver o problema

Assim, vamos ao seu código:

```js
const url = 'http://files.cod3r.com.br/curso-js/funcionarios.json'
const axios = require('axios')    

const busca = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const funcionarios = axios.get(url).then(resp => resp.data)
      resolve(funcionarios)
    }
    catch(e) {
      reject(e)
    }
  })
}

async function getFuncionarios() {
  const funcionarios = await busca()
  return funcionarios
}

const fcs = getFuncionarios()
```

Na função contida em `busca`, você "misturou" algumas coisas.

Como você utilizou a API original para esperar pela `Promise` do `axios`, já não daria certo utilizar o `try-catch` para capturar o erro retornado pelo mesmo. Pois, o `try-catch` só funcionaria de verdade quando você esperasse pela `Promise` utilizando `await`, que é quando o verdadeiro erro seria lançado.

Desse modo, se o `axios` retornasse um erro, você iria, na verdade, capturar o erro de `UnhandledPromiseRejection`, isto é, *rejeição de Promise não capturada* (em tradução livre), que corresponde exatamente ao problema de não ter passado a função a ser executada quando a `Promise` é rejeitada (a função a ser executada em `reject`).

Além disso, como vimos anteriormente, o `.then()` também retorna uma `Promise`. Portanto, aquele `resolve` está, na verdade, passando a `Promise` do `.then()`, e não o valor retornado por ela, para quem chamou a função `busca`. Ou seja, o chamador da função `busca` teria que lidar com duas `Promise`s: a `Promise` **gerada** pela função `busca` e a `Promise` **retornada** pela função `busca`.

```js
// Gera uma Promise
const promise1 = busca();

// Retorna outra Promise
const promise2 = await promise1;

// Só então retorna o valor
const resultado = await promise2;
```

E é essa a causa do problema. Quando você faz `await busca()`, você está obtendo como valor **uma outra** `Promise`. E assim, teria-se que mais uma vez esperar pela resolução dessa `Promise` retornada, para então obter o valor que se deseja. E isso não é algo muito "interessante" de se fazer.

---

Portanto, se você quer utilizar a API original, você pode fazer assim:

```js
const url = 'http://files.cod3r.com.br/curso-js/funcionarios.json'
const axios = require('axios')    

const busca = () => {
  // Reutilizamos a `Promise` do `axios`,
  // através do funcionamento do .then()
  return axios.get(url)
      .then(resp => resp.data);
}

async function getFuncionarios(){
  try {
    const funcionarios = await busca();
  
    return funcionarios;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return [];
  }
}

getFuncionarios().then((fcs) {
  // faz alguma coisa com o resultado
});
```

Ou, se quiser utilizar o `async`/`await`, você pode fazer assim:

```js
const url = 'http://files.cod3r.com.br/curso-js/funcionarios.json'
const axios = require('axios')    

const busca = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const funcionarios = response.data;

    return funcionarios;
  } catch(e) {
    throw e;
  }
}

async function getFuncionarios(){
  try {
    const funcionarios = await busca();

    return funcionarios;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return [];
  }
}

(async function() {
  const fcs = await getFuncionarios();
})();
```

#### Conclusão

Note que, em ambos os códigos, utilizamos o bloco `try-catch`, na função `getFuncionarios`, para lidar com a `Promise` gerada pela função `busca`. Isso porque, seja utilizando a API, seja utilizando `async`/`await`, a `Promise` da função `busca` *pode ser rejeitada*. E como em `getFuncionarios` estamos utilizando o `await`, essa rejeição se tornaria, de toda forma, um erro a ser lançado. Portanto, nós precisamos lidar com esse erro também.

Outra observação é que, da mesma forma que lidamos com "`Promise`s simultâneas" da primeira vez, utilizando a API, poderíamos também fazê-lo com `async`/`await`. Você pode ver isso [na resposta desse *post*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/485941/125486), que demonstra a utilização do método `.map()` junto com o construtor alternativo `Promise.all`.

E sim, existem outros "construtores" para `Promise`, além do construtor padrão. Alguns deles são:

- [`Promise.resolve(value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve), que serve para criar uma `Promise` que imediatamente conclui (resolve), retornando o valor passado para o parâmetro `value`.
- [`Promise.reject(reason)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject), que serve para criar uma `Promise` que imediatamente é rejeitada com o motivo passado para o parâmetro `reason`.
- E o [`Promise.all(iterable)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), citado acima, que serve para criar uma `Promise` que resolve quando todas as outras contidas em `iterable`, são resolvidas, ou que é rejeitada quando pelo menos uma delas é rejeitada.

Answer (score 0):

Em um projeto que estava fazendo verifiquei que, utilizando `fetch()`, o que era retornado era uma Promise {state: 'pending'}. Para resolver isso eu usei await deste modo:

```js
fetch(url, {method:'POST')
   .then(async(p) => {
   var data = await p.json()
   console.log(data)
   //retorna o resultado esperado...
}
```

Não sei se é o mais correto, mas funcionou. Se alguém tiver alguma objeção, escreva abaixo.

Answer (score -1):

`axios.get(url)` retorna uma `Promise`, você está passando uma `Promise` para outra `Promise`, e depois chama uma função assíncrona, esperando que o resultado seja síncrono.

Acho que você não entendeu como funciona `Promise` direito, tem esses artigos que explicam como funciona `Promise`

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=pt-br

Para que `getFuncionarios` funciona-se de forma síncrona, o código deveria ficar:

```
const url = 'http://files.cod3r.com.br/curso-js/funcionarios.json'
const axios = require('axios')    

const busca = () =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        try{
            const funcionarios = axios.get(url).then(resp => resp.data)
            resolve(funcionarios)
        }
        catch(e){
            reject(e)
        }
    })
}

async function getFuncionarios(){
    const funcionarios = await  busca().then(resPromise => await resPromise)
    return funcionarios
}

const fcs = await getFuncionarios()
```

Ou o código poderia ser simplificado para:

```
const url = 'http://files.cod3r.com.br/curso-js/funcionarios.json'
const axios = require('axios')    

function getFuncionarios(){
    return axios.get(url).then(resp => resp.data)
}

try {
    const fcs = await getFuncionarios()

} catch(e) {
    // Faz outra alguma coisa se der erro
}
```

Comment: Acho que você também não entendeu amigo, nenhum de seus códigos sequer compilam.