# Problema ao utilizar map com async e await em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, promises

Tenho um bloco de código onde uma variável do tipo array é definida e, dentro de uma função  `map`, faço um push de alguns valores para esse array. Dentro do `map`, consigo imprimir o array com os objetos preenchidos. Porém, fora do `map` o array fica vazio. Estou me referindo a variável `resultImage`.

Meu código:

```
async store(req, res) {
  const schema = Yup.object().shape({
    title: Yup.string().required(),
    price: Yup.number().required(),
    negotiable: Yup.boolean().required(),
    status: Yup.boolean(),
    description: Yup.string().required(),

  });

  if (!(await schema.isValid(req.body))) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "Validate fails" });
  }

  const { id: idAd, title, price, negotiable, description } = await Ad.create(req.body);

  const imgs = req.files;
  let resultImg = [];

  imgs.map(async item => {
    const { id: idFile, url } = await File.create({ ad_id: idAd, url: item.path });
    resultImg.push({ id: idFile, url });
  })

  console.log(resultImg);

  return res.status(201)
    .json({ idAd, title, price, negotiable, description, imag: { files: resultImg } });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A primeira coisa é que não se deve utilizar `map` para realizar iterações comuns. O `map`, como o próprio nome diz, é utilizado para *mapear* um array em um outro array. Repare que, embora o `map` sempre retorne um novo array, você não está utilizando-o.

Se você quer realizar uma iteração "normal", pode utilizar o `Array.prototype.forEach` (ao invés do `Array.prototype.map`) ou algum laço de repetição, como `for` ou `for..of`. Nesse caso, porém, há de usar um `for` normal (ou `for..of`) porque a necessidade de *callback* de métodos como o `forEach` não são ideais dentro de uma função assíncrona.

Portanto:

```
async function store(req, res) {
  // ...

  const imgs = req.files;
  let resultImg = [];

  for (const item of imgs) {
    const { id: idFile, url } = await File.create({ ad_id: idAd, url: item.path });
    resultImg.push({ id: idFile, url });
  }

  console.log(resultImg); // <-- Estará definido aqui.
}
```

No entanto, note um problema com esse código: ele processa uma imagem atrás da outra, sequencialmente. Embora isso nem sempre seja um problema, uma forma de "paralelizar" isso é utilizar o `map` para criar um array de promessas e o `Promise.all` para aguardar a resolução (simultaneamente) de todas elas:

```
async function store(req, res) {
  // ...

  const imgs = req.files;
  const resultImgPromises = imgs.map(async (item) => {
    const { id: idFile, url } = await File.create({ ad_id: idAd, url: item.path });

    // Note que estamos retornando:
    return { id: idFile, url };
  });

  // Aguardamos que todas as promessas se resolvam.
  // Não esqueça de tratar eventuais erros.
  const resultImg = await Promise.all(resultImgPromises);

  console.log(resultImg); // <-- Estará definido aqui.
}
```

Mas, a depender da quantidade de promessas com que você lidará ao mesmo tempo, essa abordagem também pode trazer alguns problemas. Uma estratégia é criar um tipo de *pool*, de modo a lidar com 10 ou 15 (ou algum número que você considere viável) ao mesmo tempo, lidando com cada bloco "sequencialmente".

Não esqueça de procurar entender como o [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) funciona. [E sobre promessas.](https://web.dev/promises/)

Comment: Muito boa a explicação. Entendi. Obrigado.