# Retorno indefinido ao chamar a função

Tags: javascript, node.js, orientação-a-objetos

O console.log(return) esta ok, mas o retorno só da undefined, alguém saberia me dizer o por que?

```
let result = [];

module.exports = {
    async atualizar() {
        await request(url, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('.coin-table tr').each(function() {
                var name = $(this).find('th a').text().trim();
                var valor = $(this).find('.text-right').text().split('R$');
                if (name) {
                    result.unshift({ Nome: name, Valor: 'R$ ' + valor[1] });
                }
            });
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        });
    }
};
```

o arquivo que solicita a função:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const buscar = require('./busca');
router.get('/atualizar', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(await buscar.atualizar());

    res.status(200).send('ok');
})
```

Comment: Testa adicionar `return` antes de `await request`

Comment: Já tentei, mas retorna vazio, creio que nem chega a executar o request se jogo o return antes

Comment: Que função/biblioteca é esse `request`?

Comment: importação do modulo Request do node.js

Comment: Você está usando a biblioteca `request` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request))? Inclua esse detalhe na sua pergunta, por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irei basear a minha resposta partindo do pressuposto de que você esteja usando a biblioteca [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) no código da sua pergunta.

---

O problema é que você está tentando usar `await` em uma função que usa um [`callback`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback), e não retorna uma [`Promise`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119907/o-que-s%C3%A3o-promises-promessas-em-javascript).

Você pode contornar isso fazendo com que o método `atualizar` retorne uma promessa de forma explícita:

```
module.exports = {
  atualizar() {
    // Note que, por retornar uma `Promise` explicitamente, o método
    // `atualizar` não precisa ser marcado como `async`.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(url, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {
          // Se houver algum erro, iremos rejeitar a promessa:
          reject(err)
        }

        const result = []
        const $ = cheerio.load(body)

        $('.coin-table tr').each(function() {
          const name = $(this).find('th a').text().trim()
          const valor = $(this).find('.text-right').text().split('R$')

          if (name) {
            result.unshift({ Nome: name, Valor: 'R$ ' + valor[1] })
          }
        })

        // Iremos resolver a promessa com os resultados:
        resolve(result)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

#### Ao usar:

Quando você for usar o código acima, basta fazer da seguinte forma:

```
router.get('/atualizar', async (req, res) => {
  const data = await buscar.atualizar()

  console.log(data)
  res.status(200).send('Ok.')
})
```

---

#### Sugestão

Olhando o código acima, você pode ver como ele está grande. Tendo isso em vista, sugiro que, ao invés de usar bibliotecas que usam `callback`s (um padrão antigo e já considerado ruim por muitas pessoas), você use bibliotecas mais modernas, que já trabalham diretamente com promessas. Um bom exemplo é [`got`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got).

Comment: Tentei também fazer o return da promise, mas por algum motivo continua undefined. 
se quiser da uma olhada no código completo.
https://github.com/guilhermeoa07/CryptoJS.git

Comment: Editei a minha resposta, adicionando uma sessão "**Ao Usar**", demonstrando uma das formas corretas para se chamar esse método.

Comment: Deu certo, não sei por que ao parar o nodemon e rodar novamente, funcionou, acho que tinha ficado algo em cache. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Vi algo errado em seu código. O await só vai funcionar se o seu request for uma Promise e pelo visto não é, você pode colocar o seu request em uma Promise e colocar o body em como o resolve da sua Promise. Acho que esse link pode ajudar a você na questão de Promise https://javascript.info/promise-basics

Comment: Desculpa, sou meio fraco com Promise,  entraria no caso como new Promisse(minhafunção).then(resultado).catch(err)  ???

Answer (score 0):

Teria que dar uma olhada no resto do código, mas pelo resultado que está dando minha impressao é que a variável `result` não existe no contexto em que ela é invocada. Você está exportando a função `atualizar`, mas em nenhum momento exporta a variável `result`. Muda algo se você declarar `result` dentro da função atualizar?