# Como garantir a finalização de um processo angular.js

Tags: java, angularjs

Quero pedir uma ajuda nesse processo, tenho uma aplicação no angular.js que preciso emitir todas as etiquetas de um processo, e depois todas etiquetas de um segundo processo.

O problema é que está ocorrendo de imprimir uma etiqueta do processo um depois uma etiqueta do processo 2 e assim sucessivamente.

Isso provavelmente está ocorrendo porque o processo executa o segundo processo antes que o primeiro seja finalizado.

Dessa forma preciso garantir que o primeiro processo fosse finalizado antes de executar o segundo, alguma idéia?

```
    enviaImpressao = function (impressor) {

        // Imprime etiquetas de Caixa
        ImprimeEtiquetaService.enviaParaImprsessao ( numeroCaixa, "BOX" ).then(function (result) {

        // Imprime etiquetas de Picking
        ImprimeEtiquetaService.enviaParaImprsessao ( numeroPedido, "PICKING" ).then(function (result) {
    }
```

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Coloque mais detalhes do seu código, se possivel. Com o que tem ai, acredito que se vc encadear a execução do "picking", seu código irá funcionar: ImprimeEtiquetaService.enviaParaImprsessao ( numeroCaixa, "BOX" ).then(function (result) {         ImprimeEtiquetaService.enviaParaImprsessao ( numeroPedido, "PICKING" ).then(function (result) {});
  });

Comment: Cezar obrigado pelo retorno, funcionou mas ficou mais lento. Desculpe a ignorância mas esse processo que vc indicou é similar a um processo recursivo ?. Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Não é sobre recursividade mas sim promisses, vc pode obter mais informações aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/119913/2318

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme o comentário, seu problema pode ser resolvido da seguinte forma:

```js
    enviaImpressao = function (impressor) {

        // Imprime etiquetas de Caixa
        ImprimeEtiquetaService.enviaParaImprsessao ( numeroCaixa, "BOX" ).then(function (result) {
            // Imprime etiquetas de Picking
            ImprimeEtiquetaService.enviaParaImprsessao ( numeroPedido, "PICKING" ).then(function (result) {});

        });      
    }
```

O que acontece é que as duas chamadas são encadeadas, ou seja: primeiro será feito uma requisição passando o parâmetro BOX, após o fim dela ( o que tende ao infinito), é executada a próxima chamada com o parâmetro PICKING.

Mais informações podem ser obtidas aqui:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/119913/2318

Comment: ok. obrigado. Um abraço.