# Retorno assíncrono de algumas APIs

Tags: javascript, promises, response, fetch

Por que o retorno de algumas APIs são exatamente o resultado que queremos (por exemplo, um JSON) e algumas outras retornam um objeto cheio de funções e objetos?

Exemplo de API que retorna diretamente o resultado que quero:

```js
function user(id) {
  const users = {
    1: {id: 1, name: 'Lucas'},
    2: {id: 2, name: 'João'}
  };
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(users[id]), 1000);
  });
}

async function exec() {
  console.log(await user(1))
}

exec()
```

Já outras me retornam um objeto que contem várias coisas como, por exemplo, `body`, `bodyUsed`, `headers`, `ok`, `redirected`, `status`, `statusText`, `type`, `url` e outros.

Como, por exemplo, a API do GitHub:

```js
async function getUserGithub() {
  console.log(await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/decarvalholucas`))
}
getUserGithub()
```

Por que é assim e qual a diferença delas pra isso acontecer?

Comment: Ambas funções retornam a mesma coisa: um objeto. 1) Você está retornando um objeto "simples" com as propriedades ID e o nome do usuário; 2) Você está retornando o objeto [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Response), que — para acessar um *json*, por exemplo — é necessário utilizar um dos métodos disponíveis.

Comment: Ta, beleza; Mas a forma como demonstrei ali, do github.. Ele retorna várias coisas "padrões", digo padrões porque a maioria das APIs que usamos retorna isso, ai sempre tempos que fazer outra requisição pra puxar o que de fatos queremos realmente, por EXEMPLO, teríamos que dar um await result.json(). Isso é um padrão? Sempre vai ser assim esse retorno das APIs?

Comment: O `fetch` retorna uma classe (Response), que possuem atributos (`ok`) e métodos `json` Na verdade isso vai depender da API que você está utilizando, caso utilize `FormData`, ela terá outros métodos etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL;DR: Os métodos em questão não vêm da API, mas sim do objeto [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) que é retornado como uma promessa pelo [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Para obter os dados do corpo da resposta, você deve usar métodos como o [`json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) ou [`text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text), disponíveis no protótipo do objeto da resposta (`Response`).

---

Você está a usar a [API `fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), que retorna uma [`Promise`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119907/o-que-s%C3%A3o-promises-promessas-em-javascript) que resolve em um objeto [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), que possui os métodos descritos na sua pergunta.

Portanto, não é a API do GitHub (ou nenhuma outra) que retorna os métodos descritos na pergunta, até porque isso não seria um JSON válido, uma vez que essa notação não é capaz de transferir dados como funções ou métodos.

Então, o código a seguir **não retorna** o JSON da sua API, mas sim um objeto [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response):

```js
async function resolveFetch(...params) {
  // O `await` resolve a `Promise` retornada pelo `fetch` no objeto `Response`.
  const responseObject = await fetch(...params);

  // Aqui, `responseObject` é um objeto `Response` (retornado pelo `fetch`)
  // como uma promessa que já se resolveu.
  // Esse objeto possui diversos métodos, como o `json`, `text`, e 
  // propriedades como o `headers`, que te permitem converter o retorno da
  // API a um formato desejado (como o `json`) ou obter informações sobre
  // a resposta da requisição.
  return responseObject;
}

(async () => {
  const result = await resolveFetch('https://api.github.com/users/lffg');
  
  console.log(result instanceof window.Response); // true
})();
```

Desse modo, para obter o valor do corpo da resposta, você deve fazer uso de algum dos métodos a seguir, disponíveis no protótipo do objeto [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), que também foram listados [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Methods):

- [`arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer), que retorna uma promessa que resolve como um [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBuffer).
- [`blob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob), que retorna uma promessa que resolve como um [`blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).
- [`formData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/formData), que retorna uma promessa que resolve como um [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).
- [`json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), que retorna uma promessa que resolve com o resultado do *parse* do texto do corpo como [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).
- [`text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text), que retorna uma promessa que resolve com um texto ([`USVString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USVString)).

No seu caso, como você está lidando com APIs que retornam um JSON, é mais interessante trabalhar com o [`json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) para converter o corpo da resposta em um texto com o JSON "*parseado*".

Então, ficamos assim:

```js
async function fetchJSON(...params) {
  // Aqui, `resolvedResponse` será um objeto `Response`, que veio da
  // resolução da promessa que o `fetch` retorna.
  const resolvedResponse = await fetch(...params);

  // Abaixo estamos usando o método `json`, presente no objeto `Response`
  // para obter o texto do corpo da resposta e já convertê-lo em JSON:
  const json = await resolvedResponse.json();

  // Podemos retornar o JSON.
  // Agora SIM! É o JSON retornado pela API! ;)
  return json;
}

(async () => {
  const json = await fetchJSON('https://api.github.com/users/lffg');

  console.log(json instanceof Response); // false

  // Notamos abaixo que agora sim se trata de um JSON.
  console.log(json.login); // "lffg"
})();
```

Podemos até transformar esse *workflow* em um simples diagrama:

[image: Diagrama 1]

Comment: Caraca que massa! Obrigado, Luiz. Mas ainda tenho uma dúvida. Pelo que vejo, eu tenho que fazer a "requisição principal" que é no endpoint da API, no caso: https://api.github.com/users/lffg, e, como eu preciso dos dados em json, eu novamente uso o await pra retornar o json em si, await response.json() Quando faço isso, eu novamente estou fazer outra requisição naquela API ou esse json ja está dentro do primeiro Response recebido? A pergunta é justamente por conta disso, terei que fazer 2 rquests a API pra obter de fato os dados que preciso?

Comment: Não. Somente o fetch faz a requisição. O json só é usado para “transformar” o corpo da resposta em JSON. :)

Comment: Ahh, agora faz sentido, perdão a "nubisse" hahaha, muito obrigado, Luiz! +50

Answer (score 1):

Faltou tratar o recebimento:

```js
async function getUserGithub() {
  await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/decarvalholucas`).then(function(response) {
      response.json().then(function(data){
          console.log(data);
        });
    });
}
getUserGithub()
```