# Problema com promisse, retorna: "Promise {<pending>} "

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises, google-sheets

Fala pessoal! Estou com um problema ao conectar Node.js com Spreedsheet.

Eu uso a função abaixo para buscar o valor 'data' na minha planilha. Até ai funciona muito bem, porém, quando vou utilizar "data" ou "data.length" fora da função ela me retorna: "Promise {} ".

Alguém sabe o que eu deveria fazer para conseguir usar este dado fora da função accessSpreadsheet?

```
async function accessSpreadsheet() {
    await promisify (doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
    const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
    const sheet = info.worksheets[0]; 
    const data = await promisify(sheet.getRows)({                                                                       
    query: `data = ${datainput}`                                                                                        
});
return data.length;
}

var total = accessSpreadsheet();
console.log(total);
```

Comment: Você pode usar `await` assim `var total = await accessSpreadsheet(`, mas o lugar aonde chama também tem que ser async. O importante é você entender como funciona callbacks https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45706/3635 e entender com funciona os promises: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119907/3635

Answer (score 11):

O que você precisa entender, é que toda função `async` retorna uma promise.

Por traz das cortinas, a seguinte função:

```
async function somar(a, b) {
    return a + b
}
```

É exatamente o mesmo que:

```
function somar(a, b) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(a + b)
    })
}
```

---

Repare que a função `async` imediatamente retorna uma `Promise`, ela retorna a promise antes mesmo de processar o resultado. Isso é o que está acontecendo no seu código, quando você invoca `accessSpreadsheet()`, a função te retorna uma promise, se você precisa do `total`, então você tem que esperar pela resolução da promise. Exemplos:

```
// Utilizando o método then
var totalPromise = accessSpreadsheet()
totalPromise.then(total => {
    console.log(total)
})
```

---

```
// Utilizando await dentro de uma função imediatamente invocada
void async function() {
    var total = await accessSpreadsheet()
    console.log(total)
}()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação. Ficou muito mais claro agora :)

Comment: Uma resposta que salvou meu dia!

Comment: Resposta que salvou meu dia também. Valeu mesmo, André.