# comport uma requisição do tipo POST utilizando uma PROMISE de uma função

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, axios, https

sou programador python e estou programando agora em javascript com Nodejs, já estou conseguindo programar normalmente mas uma dúvida que não está deixando eu progredir na linguagem é a questão das promises, preciso compor uma requisição do tipo POST onde será encorporado o body que é o resultado de uma promise, pensei em usar o timeout mas creio que há saídas melhores para isso, gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês, vou deixar um exemplo abaixo.

```
function composeBody(){
   const build = axios.get('www.exemplo.com/json')
   return build.json()
}

function sendPostRequest(bodyComposer){
   axios.post('www.sendpostrequest.com', {body: bodyComposer})
}

composeBody().then((r) => { sendPostRequest(r) })
```

o código acima é meramente ilustrativo, só gostaria de entender como é a maneira correta de fazer isso, enviar uma requisição tipo POST com body, headers recebendo o resultado de uma função que será uma promise.
sei que poderia usar um .then na função e passar a promise como parâmetro na segunda função mas creio que quando tiver que compor um POST mais detalhado irei ter problemas.
li sobre await/async mas ainda sim não consegui fazer funcionar como deveria, quem puder me ajudar fico muito grato.

Comment: Você já tentou começar pela [documentação do axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#readme)?

Comment: o axios só utilizei como exemplo, quero entender como se faz algo do tipo para saber como lidar com cadeias de funções que dependem uma das outras, por programar em linguagem síncrona isso ainda é meio confuso para mim.

Comment: Se você quer entender sobre como encadear operações assíncronas no JavaScript, vale começar entendendo [o que são callbacks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback). Depois, dar uma olhada nas [`Promise`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119907/o-que-s%C3%A3o-promises-promessas-em-javascript)s, que são mais usadas hoje em dia.

Comment: eu já tenho conhecimento teórico e prático das três soluções (callback, time out e promise), o que eu precisava era ver na prática o encadeamento com um tipo de design pattern pois queria ver a maneira correta de se fazer já que eu tenho experiência com linguagens totalmente síncronas. a resposta abaixo já tirou todas minhas dúvidas, de qualquer forma obrigado pelas dicas ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, boa noite. Tudo bem?

Então, vamos a uma breve conceituação antes de passar para o hard coded:

### Conceituação:

O JavaScript é *single thread* e isso significa que ele lê e executa uma instrução por vez de forma síncrona. No entanto há maneiras de implementar o comportamento assíncrono e fazer com que ele espere um retorno ser finalizado para então dar tratativa nesse dado.

Existem basicamente (geral) três maneiras de implementar o comportamento assíncrono, sendo elas via callback, async/await e promises (a primeira forma acaba por não ser tão eficiente por conta de um velho problema conhecido como callback hell (inferno das callbacks aninhadas)).

### Entendendo assincronismo:

Para entender melhor como isso funciona, pense que o JavaScript saí executando as instruções que estiverem à sua frente de maneira procedural e não espera que elas tenham algum retorno para seguir com a execução (se esperasse, isso geraria um problemão de lag e performance no browser/client).

Quando implementamos o comportamento assíncrono estamos dizendo que queremos que ele continue executando suas instruções procedurais normalmente, porém que em paralelo lembre-se de retornar àquela execução passada quando tiver uma resposta.

### Por que NÃO utilizar o TIMEOUT?

O timeout não seria nada performático e muito menos útil para você, pois você não sabe o tempo que a requisição *GET* vai levar para voltar e iria gerar uma trava na aplicação com o timing apenas para aguardar o retorno de uma resposta que você nem sabe se vai voltar.

Para isso vamos implementar uma *promise* que será consumida por uma *async function* e nesta *async function* iremos tratar o comportamento de *POST*.

---

### Mão no código:

#### *Criando a promise:*

```
function composeBody() {
  // Cria um objeto de promise.
  // Parâmetros resolve (retorno bem sucedido) e reject (retorno mal-sucedido).

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Executa a requisição GET.

    axios.get('http://api.exemplo.com.br/repositories')
      // Recebe a res (resposta da requisição).

      .then(res => {
      // Tente resolver o parse da resposta para JSON
      // Se a resposta for undefined ou qualquer coisa diferente de um JSON o parse falhará e caíra no catch.

        try {
          resolve(res.json());
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
  });
}
```

#### *Criando a função assíncrona:*

```
// Determino que deverá ser uma função assíncrona.

async function sendRequest() {
  // Recupero o body executando nossa promise.
  // O await determina que o runtime espere o resolve/reject da promise.

  const body = await composeBody();
  // Disparo a requisição com o body recuperado
  // OBS.: a partir do ES6 propriedades de objetos com o mesmo nome da variável são autorreferenciados em chave e valor.

  axios.post('http://mysite.com.br/addrepo', {
    body
  });
}

sendRequest();
```

#### *Requisições síncronas:*

```
// Determino que deverá ser uma função normal.

function syncRequest() {
  // Cria um objeto do XMLHttpRequest (construtor embutido do ambiente no browser).

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // Abro a requisição com o método open.
  // Parâmetro 1: Tipo da requisição.
  // Parâmetro 2: Url para onde a requisição será enviada.
  // Parâmetro 3: Determino que minha requisição deve ser síncrona (async: false)
  // Caso coloque para true a requisição se torna assíncrona via AJAX.

  xhr.open('GET', './hello.json', false);
  // Envio a requisição com o método send.

  xhr.send();
  // Verifico se o status da requisição foi 200 (sucesso).
  // Se sim, mostro a resposta em formato raw text no console.

  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
}
```

OBS.: Para usar este objeto no Node.js, você terá que instalar a biblioteca dele https://www.npmjs.com/package/xhr. Se comporta de uma maneira um pouco diferente no Server-Side, mas nada de absurdo.

Comment: você entendeu perfeitamente minha dúvida, já estava ciente dos problemas com callbacks e da deficiência dos time outs quando se trata de situações flexíveis. Obrigado por mostrar o jeito correto e sem gambiaras de fazer esse tipo de encadeamento.

Comment: uma dúvida que me surgiu lendo sua introdução, vendo o javascript hoje em dia só se usa de modo assíncrono, e claro pelas suas vantagens de performance me pergunto: seria possível executar uma request de modo síncrono?
se sim como seria, poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: @JeffersonMatheusDuarte Bom, podemos sim executar uma requisição síncrona. Mas por razões óbvias e que você mesmo reconhece, isso é extremamente contraindicado.

Claro que existem casos que é preferível executar uma requisição síncrona ao invés de uma assíncrona, mas isso é raro (ainda mais no cenário multinível que temos hoje).

PS.: Editei o código acima com um título para as requisições síncronas.

Comment: obrigado por esclarecer, as questões que eu levantei aqui eram para entender melhor a lógica com sua explicação já tenho conhecimento necessário para adicionar a linguagem a meu leque.
muitíssimo obrigado pela atenção e pelos detalhes nas explicações.