# Dúvida sobre espera de retorno de uma função JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promises

Estou tendo uma dificuldade em uma situação.

Estou utilizando React Native e, em um arquivo a parte, possuo algumas variáveis globais e pensei em utilizar também algumas funções como esta:

```
//Função "Global" que utilizo para retorna uma única string
global.gServidor = () => {
 //Função que acessa o "Local Storage", estou passando @Config para trazer as Configurações salvas
 getStorage('@Config')
 .then((response) => JSON.parse(response))
 .then((json) => {
   console.log(json);
   return json != null ? json.servidor : "";
 });
};
```

O problema aqui é como o resultado vem, se eu chamar `gServidor()` em qualquer lugar, e passar um `console.log` nele, `undefined` é impresso. No entanto, o `console.log` de dentro dele retorna o json normalmente, o problema esta em acessar pelo lado de fora.

Isso se tornou uma dor de cabeça porque, com `fetch()` eu passo a mesma dificuldade. Pensei em montar uma função fixa para consultas simples como por exemplo `getAPI()`, em que eu passaria apenas o caminho da URL da requisição como parâmetro e ele me retornaria um JSON, ou seja, `getAPI('produtos')` e dentro dela teria todo o processo de requisição do `fetch` já configurado. Mas passei pela mesma situação, me retorna um valor indefinido, mas se eu acessar de dentro, ele funciona.

Estou tendo muita dificuldade com isso e coisas do tipo `async`/`await`.

Mas uma coisa de cada vez, alguém pode me explicar usando meu exemplo do `gServidor` o porque que ele retorna `undefined` do lado de fora função, e retorna certo pelo lado de dentro dela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que ocorre é que a sua função `gServidor` não está retornando nada. Logo, se você a chamar, nada será retornado, embora o código, de fato, esteja rodando *dentro* dela.

Você precisa utilizar o `return`, de modo a retornar explicitamente a promessa em questão. Assim:

```
global.gServidor = () => {
  return getStorage('@Config')
    .then((response) => JSON.parse(response))
    .then((json) => {
      return json != null ? json.servidor : '';
    });
};
```

Note que agora, `gServidor` está, de fato, retornando o valor trabalhado. Nesse caso, provavelmente se trata de uma `Promise` (ou *promise-like*), já que implementa o método `then`.

Portanto, quando você chamar `gServidor`, haverá de utilizar o `then` para aguardar pelo valor retornado. Uma outra opção é utilizar o `await`, dentro de uma função assíncrona para fazer essa espera.

Um exemplo de chamada:

```
gServidor()
  .then((dados) => {
    console.log('Valor retornado:', dados);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Aconteceu um erro:', error);
  });
```

Para saber mais, leia:

- [O que são promises (promessas) em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119907/69296)
- [JavaScript Promises: An Introduction](https://web.dev/promises/), embora seja em inglês, esse é (na minha opinião) um dos melhores guias introdutórios às promessas em JavaScript.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, de coração, me ajudou de mais, pude entender o conceito e com isso, várias coisas fizeram sentido e agora posso dar andamento nos estudos e projetos por aqui, ajudou muito mesmo. Valeu!!!!