# Como adaptar uma função que só aceita callback à interface de promessas em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, assincronismo, promises, callback

Estou usando uma função de uma biblioteca externa para adquirir o `token` de um usuário, ela é a seguinte:

```
export default function GetGraphToken(
  email: string,
  password: string,
  callback: (graphClient: Client, token: string) => void,
): void {
  ...

  context.acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword(
    resource,
    email,
    password,
    clientId,
    (tokenError, token) => {
      if (tokenError) {
        throw new Error(tokenError.message);
      }

      const tokenResponse = token as TokenResponse;

      ...

      callback(graphClient, tokenResponse.accessToken);
    },
  );
}
```

A função *callback* da `acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword` é a que eu obtenho de fato o token, porém após isso eu quero expor esse token para outras funções utilizarem ele. Atualmente, a maneira como eu estou fazendo isso é passando outro *callback* para lidar com isso. Como é de se esperar de funções *callbacks*, isso vai me levar ao uso encadeado de função dentro de função e eu penso que seja possível evitar isso utilizando `Promise`.

Se eu pudesse alterar a função `acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword` eu a faria retornar uma `Promise` ao invés de receber um *callback*. Entretanto, como ela pertence a uma biblioteca externa, eu não posso. Eis que surge minha dúvida, eu estou preso ao uso de *callback* ou há alguma maneira de me livra disso utilizando `Promise`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você acertou: pode utilizar promessas para evitar o *callback hell* (e evitar *callbacks* em geral).

De modo geral,  `Promise` é a forma ideal para se lidar com assincronismo no JavaScript moderno, já que permitem composição e encadeamento. Além disso, casam extremamente bem com [funções assíncronas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas).

Se você está utilizando uma biblioteca legada que ainda faz uso de *callbacks*, **não** faça o seu código funcionar com base em *callbacks*. Você só estará retrocedendo a sua *codebase* em detrimento de uma biblioteca retrógrada. Ao invés disso, crie um tipo de *wrapper function* que envolve a função original, operando em interface de promessas.

Não sei muito bem como é a assinatura de `acquireTokenWithUsernamePassword`, mas darei um exemplo de como converter a função `fs.readFile` do Node.js, que normalmente opera com *callbacks*:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function readFilePromise(fileName) {
  // Note que retornamos uma promessa explicitamente:
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        // Em caso de erro, rejeitamos a promessa:
        reject(data);
      } else {
        // Em caso de sucesso, resolvemos a promessa com o conteúdo desejável:
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Agora você pode utilizar `readFilePromise`, que opera através de uma interface que faz uso de promessas. Mas observe que o exemplo acima é certamente "leigo", já que ignora o argumento `options` de `readFile`. Foi só para dar uma ideia mesmo. Além disso, o Node.js também já oferece uma [API de *file system* baseada em promessas](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api).

Um outro exemplo muito comum de *promissificação* é converter o `setTimeout` para poder usá-lo com o `await`. Veja:

```js
// Promissificamos o `setTimeout`, chamando-o de `delay`:
function delay(timeout) {
  // Como `setTimeout` não lança erros, não usaremos o parâmetro `reject`:
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
  });
}

async function main() {
  console.log('A');
  await delay(500);
  console.log('B');
  await delay(250);
  console.log('C');
  await delat(250);
  console.log('End.');
}

main();
```

Sempre que estiver utilizando uma biblioteca antiga que opera via *callbacks*, haverá de fazer esse envolvimento manual para cada função legada. Mas, tendo em vista que o ecossistema já se estabeleceu relativamente bem com o uso de promessas, creio que não será um número tão grande de *wrappers*.

Só tome cuidado para não converter *tudo* em promessa. Algumas APIs (como `Observable` e `Stream`) utilizam *callbacks* que podem ser chamados múltiplas vezes e, como promessas se resolvem somente uma única vez, não são ideais nesse tipo de cenário.

Para saber mais sobre como as promessas funcionam, sugiro [este artigo](https://web.dev/promises/). A [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) também traz boas informações.

Comment: +1 *wrappers* assim são coisas maravilhosas, facilitam inclusive a criação de testes. Uma outra opção é, caso seja uma lib open source, tentar colaborar com o projeto (criando uma *issue* sobre e, se bem aceito, um PR) ou então ameaçar o dono do repositório *(não recomendo, seja uma pessoa legal)*

Comment: Caiu como uma luva! Até agora eu só tinha achado exemplos, que convertia callback em promise, em códigos que o desenvolvedor podia modificar e não me toquei que também daria utilizar essa técnica em bibliotecas de terceiros.