# Como fazer o bloco esperar a execução de um método para continuar

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma rota verificar login, ela chama um método que devolve um boolean, preciso fazer um if com o valor retornado, mas ele retorna undefined, pois ainda não foi executado.

```
app.post('/home', urlencodeParser, (req, res) => {
    var resLogin = cruds.verificaLogin(req.body.username, req.body.password)
    console.log(resLogin)
    res.send('<h1>Olá Mundo</h1>')    
})
```

Método `verificaLogin`:

```
verificaLogin(_email, _senha) {
    var res = new Boolean(0)       
    this.sql.query(`SELECT COUNT(*) login [login] FROM users where email = ${_email} and senha = ${_senha}`, function(erro, results, fields){            
        //if (!erro)                
        console.log(res)    
        return res    
    })   
}
```

Comment: Você precisa utilizar [callbacks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/69296) ou [adaptar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486268/69296) seu código para utilizar [promessas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119907/69296). É importante também entender como o assincronismo funciona no JavaScript.

Comment: `var resLogin = cruds.verificaLogin(req.body.username, req.body.password)` aqui está usando de forma síncrona um método que dentro tem uma chama assíncrona (`this.sql.query(....`), isso não vai funcionar