# Função retornando [ Promise { <pending> } ]

Tags: javascript, node.js

Alguém pode me ajudar, estou com uma função retornando como pendente, mas não sei o que pode ser já tentei de tudo. segue meu código:

```
  const episodes = seasons.map((el) => {
    const season = moviedb
      .seasonInfo({ language: language, id: tmdbId, season_number: el.season_number })
      .then((res) => {
        const meta = res.episodes.map((el, index) => {
            return {
              id: `${tmdbId}:${el.season_number}:${el.episode_number}`,
              name: `${el.name}`,
              season: `${el.season_number}`,
              number: `${el.episode_number}`,
              episode: `${el.episode_number}`,
              thumbnail: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${el.still_path}`,
              overview: `${el.overview}`,
              description: `${el.overview}`,
              rating: `${el.vote_average}`,
              firstAired: el.air_date,
              released: el.air_date,
            }
          })
        return meta
      })
      .catch(console.error);
    return season
  });
  console.log(await episodes)
  return episodes;
}
```

Comment: você está fazendo uma confusão com a promise... aconselho que leia mais em [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: invés de season = moviedb....then().catch(), você deveria ou usar um await movie..sem o then.catch, ou cerca toda a função com uma promise e chamar o resolver()/reject(), ao final da cadeia de then,catch,e um await para está promise, se a função for assincrona...

Comment: Você pode usar `await` assim `const season = await moviedb`, mas o lugar aonde chama também tem que ser async. O importante é você entender como funciona callbacks https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45706/3635 e entender com funciona os promises: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119907/3635

Answer (score 0):

Oi, suspeito que ele imprime no console.log o que tu deseja mas retorna na função o valor errado, é isso? Se for o caso pode ser que retornar o valor da promise ao invés da promise em si seja o problema. Troca o teu último return por:

`return await episodes;`