# O que é uma Promise?

Tags: javascript, promises, concorrência

Por que ela existe?

Como ela funciona e como deve ser usada da forma mais simples? Algum cuidado específico? Quando é abuso adotar este mecanismo?

Só existe em JavaScript?

Comment: Com a intenção de ser canônica já que o assunto ainda renderá muito.

Comment: Já tem: [O que são promises (promessas) em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119907/o-que-s%c3%a3o-promises-promessas-em-javascript), apesar de que as respostas têm muito a melhorar lá. :-)

Comment: Eu vou deixar como duplicata porque eu busquei eu não apareceu. Essa busca é muito ruim.

Comment: @LuizFelipe manda uma resposta lá... :)

Comment: @CmteCardeal, **[done](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/504674/69296)**! :-) A ideia é tornar aquela resposta meio canônica, então se tiver alguma sugestão do que mais colocar pode deixar nos comentários. Tentei ser bem generalista, mas sugestões são bem-vindas.

Comment: Me senti menos mal de ver uma pergunta do Maniero marcada como Duplicada, não acontece só comigo :)
Pesquisei sobre promises e achei essa pergunta, não a canônica