# Quando usar success: function() e .done(function()) em requisições assíncronas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, assincronismo

De maneira simples, posso escrever uma requisição assíncrona como:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (_user){
        alert (_user)
    }
});
```

que me alerta o retorno `_user`. Igualmente, escrevo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET'
}).done(function(_user){
    alert(_user);
});
```

que alerta precisamente o mesmo resultado. Eu sei que `success: function()` no primeiro caso é um *callback*, executado no sucesso da requisição, assim como `fail: function()` e `always: function()` são executados conforme os nomes dizem.

Falando em nomes, é possivel inferir que, quando a requisição está pronta (`done`), o método *chainable* `.done()` é executado. Entendo também que o método `$.ajax` retorna um [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), que é exatamente no qual o `.done()` atua, por isso a diferença na sintaxe entre ele e o `success`.

De qualquer jeito, apesar do meu exemplo minimalista, na grande maioria dos casos eu não entendo quando usar cada uma das maneiras - seja ela um *callback* ou o encadamento de mais um método - visto que eu obtenho o resultado esperado em ambas. Eu conheço ainda uma terceira maneira para obter esse resultado, mas ela envolve a diretiva `async: false`, que acaba fugindo do escopo da pergunta.

Então, em que momento usar `.done()`? Quando usar o *callback* `success: function()`? Gostaria de exemplos práticos e, se possível, exemplos cujo resultado seja diferente quando uma ou outra aproximação é executada.

Comment: Não serve como resposta mas segue alguma explicação: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754619/jquery-ajax-success-callback-function-definition/14754681#14754681

Comment: @Guerra eu já havia lido essa resposta, e ela é excelente. Até pensei em entrar no mérito de `resolve` na minha questão, mas acho que isso vale uma pergunta completamente diferente. De qualquer maneira, boa referência =)

Comment: Eu desconheço um caso que tenha que utilizar especificamente um deles. E acho que o uso de _Promisses_, o `done()`, facilita a leitura do código e faz a linguagem se aproximar mais de OO.

Comment: @LeonardoLeal eu concordo. A aproximação ao OO, ainda mais agora com o ES6 virando a esquina, me agrada bastante, fora que é possível separar as responsabilidades de captura e de manipulação do dado, nesse caso em especial

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TL;DR: o `.done()` é a maneira moderna de usar o `success`, e cumpre mais ou menos(*) as especificações de uma Promise. O que quer dizer que pode ser encadeado ao estilo jQuery e protege a execução em caso de erros.

---

Antes de o conceito de Promises e callbacks deferidos surgir o método habitual era passar um objeto ao método ajax com as configurações necessárias. Assim a callback ia nesse objeto também assim como o futuro código que dependesse dessa resposta, que tinha de começar de dentro da callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (_user){
        fazerUpdateTabela(_user);
        guardarUmCookie(_user);
        procurarNoutraAPIqqCoisa(_user.nif, function(dadosPessoais){
            verificarCartao(dadosPessoais.nrCartao, function(ver){
                if (!ver) fazerTudoDeNovo();
                // etc
            });
        });
        // etc
    }
});
```

No caso de por exemplo `procurarNoutraAPIqqCoisa` tivesse lá dentro outro passo a seguir depois desse ter completado a cadeia de acções fica fragmentada e passadas algumas linhas já é dificil saber a origem e direção de execussão do código.

Mais tarde, com o conceito de Promises é possivel escrever código que é um esqueleto do que vai acontecer e tem um caminho mais visual e fácil de perceber. O exemplo acima poderia ser adaptado (com alguns ajustes internos nas funções) para isto:

```
var ajax = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET'
});
ajax
    .done([guardarUmCookie, fazerUpdateTabela])
    .done(procurarNoutraAPIqqCoisa.then(verificarCartao).fail(fazerTudoDeNovo));
```

`*` - O jQuery tem tido problemas com encadeamentos de deferreds jQuery. Há um bug/pr com uma discussão longa sobre isso [no Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1996). Parece que na versão 3 isso vai ser resolvido mas a meu ver tarde demais pois os browsers já permitem uma versão nativa da mesma ideia.

A versão moderna é portanto mais versátil e permite como referi o encadeamento de funções que devem correr quando a resposta do servidor chegar. Permite funções como argumento mas também arrays de funções, ao estilo do `Promise.all`, o que pode ser prático.

Esta versão tem uma API paralela ás promises para encaminhar essas cadeias de `.done()` e `.fail(`)` com [vários métodos](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), dando mais flexibilidade para gerir o fluxo da aplicação.

Um outro aspeto importante das Promises é que os erros gerados dentro de Promises não fazem estragos como antigamente. Um erro ('throw') dentro de uma Promise faz ela e as seguintes da cadeia serem rejeitadaa e chama o `.catch()` da cadeia. Isto é muito útil para evitar código que deixa de funcionar.

#### Depois do que escrevi em cima e retornando à pergunta: Qual usar?

Eu prefiro usar Promises e Ajax nativo. Hoje em dia isso já é possivel.

Assim a versão "normal" com callbacks podia ser:

```
function _ajax(method, url, done) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url);
  xhr.onload = function () {
    done(null, xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function () {
    done(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.send();
}

// e para usar
_ajax('GET', 'http://example.com', function (err, dados) {
  if (err) { console.log(err); }
  else console.log('A resposta é:', dados);
});
```

A versão com Promises poderia ser assim um encapsulamento desta versão antiga, com poderes Promise:

```
function ajax(method, url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        _ajax(method, url, function(err, res) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(res);
        });
    });
}
```

ou refazendo:

```
function _ajax(method, url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.onload = resolve;
        xhr.onerror = reject;
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

e depois usar com:

```
ajax('GET', 'http://sopt.moon')
    .then(function(dados) {
        console.log(dados);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error('Oh não!!', err.statusText);
    });
```

Com mais algumas adaptações pode permitir `POST`, `PUT,` etc. Há um [polyfill completo na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Example_using_new_XMLHttpRequest()) para isto.

---

Comment: Gostei do exemplo *vanilla*, bem útil!

Comment: Vou marcar essa resposta como a correta, por conta do exemplo com JS puro, apesar de todas as que apareceram serem muito boas e didáticas.

Answer (score 15):

Os resultados práticos são iguais. A diferença está principalmente no estilo do código.

As [promessas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16921/como-realmente-aprender-a-usar-promessas-em-javascript) (no jQuery, implementadas como *deferred objects*) são um modelo amplamente utilizado para se lidar com operações assíncronas, em JavaScript e em outras linguagens. Elas facilitam diversos tratamentos sobre operações assíncronas, principalmente quando você precisa lidar com o resultado de mais de uma operação, seja em sequência ou em paralelo.

Pense por exemplo numa cadeia de operações assíncronas onde cada operação depende do resultado da anterior, com o callback da primeira operação iniciando a segunda e assim por diante. Isso rapidamente se torna um "inferno de callbacks" (*callback hell*). A consequência típica é que o código fica menos legível, parecendo uma seta para a direita:

[image: callback hell]

Isso é muito comum de ocorrer com `if`s também, mas no caso deles, que são todos síncronos, é mais simples resolver, muitas vezes bastando colocá-los em sequência em vez de aninhados, ou juntar múltiplas condições num único `if`.

Já para resolver esse problema com operações assíncronas não é tão simples. É preciso tomar conta do estado dessas operações, que muda ao longo do tempo, e criar um mecanismo para registrar o que fazer dependendo do estado.

E basicamente é isso que as promessas fazem, permitindo transformar o código da figura em algo assim:

```
a().then(b).then(c).then(d).then(e).then(f);
```

Outro exemplo, desta vez com jQuery, executando um callback apenas quando 3 requisições ajax tiverem sido completadas:

```
$.when(reqA, reqB, reqC).then(callback);
```

Claro que é possível criar suas próprias soluções para resolver os problemas de legibilidade versus assincronicidade, mas as promessas já fazem isso e de modo padronizado – ou seja, que módulos independentes de código são capazes de entender. Lembre-se de que operações assíncronas não se resumem a requisições HTTP. No jQuery, por exemplo, também é possível obter promessas outros tipos, como animações completadas, diálogos modais confirmados, etc. E com essas promessas você consegue expressar de maneira mais simples o fluxo de operações que seu código executa. Em Node.js (portanto, no servidor), o callback hell é ainda mais fácil de se atingir, considerando que operações essenciais como acesso a banco de dados ou ao sistema de arquivos são assíncronas.

Comment: _"Isso é muito comum de ocorrer com ifs também, mas no caso deles, que são todos síncronos, é mais simples resolver"_ - excelente exemplo

Comment: Excelente! Gostei da citação ao `node.js`. + 1

Answer (score 8):

Isso sempre foi um grande paradigma pra mim também. Já pesquisei sobre e vou dizer o que pude absorver.

No início usava-se sempre o *callback* `success` falando em `$.ajax`. Porém quando veio a implementação do [`$.Deferreds`](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), que seriam retornos com mais rendimentos, passou a usar-se `done` para *callback* positivo.

Comparação de *callback* `positivo`:

**Antes do $.Deferreds**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url.php',
  type: 'POST'
  success: function(data) {
      alert("SUCESSO"); 
  }
});
```

**Depois do $.Deferreds**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url.php',
  type: 'POST'
}).done(function() { 
     alert("SUCESSO"); 
});
```

Pelo que pude perceber a principal vantagem em utilizar `$.Deferreds` é que você pode ter uma função em comum para requisições diferentes.
Isso pode ser explicado de uma forma bem simplista:

```
function ajax_get_somethings(id) {

  return $.ajax({
    url: get_somethings.php,
    type: 'GET',
    data: {id: id},
    dataType: 'json'
  }).always(function() {
    // Sempre de um alerta
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // Caso falhe solicite outro id
  });

}

ajax_get_somethings(1).done(function(data) {
  // pegue algo com esse id e faça determinada tarefa
});

ajax_get_somethings(2).done(function(data) {
  // pegue algo com esse outro id e faça outra tarefa
});
```

E isso não acaba por ai ainda temos uma série de leques a ser explorado caso for necessário: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Espero ter ajudado.

Referência de pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840257/jquery-ajax-handling-continue-responses-success-vs-done

Comment: Complementando, a separação do que realmente é esperado é mais visível aos olhos do programador: O que tem que fazer quando dá certo, o que tem que fazer quando dá errado. Só acho uma falha (ou falta de implementação) que o `fail()` não receba parâmetros, como status_code, por exemplo.

Comment: Esta aproximação de parametrizar a requisição é bem interessante. Por ora, +1