# Significado dos parâmetros em uma requisição AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, terminologia

Quando faz uma requisição utilizando `$.ajax`,

- Qual o significado de `processData: false`, `contentType: false` e
  `async: false`, pra que servem esses campos?
- Existe diferença em usar `type: "post"` ou  `type: "POST"`?
- Por que se utiliza `data: JSON.stringify`?

  ```
  $.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: "POST",
       async: false,
       data: JSON.stringify({ grid: grid }),   
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (data){
               console.log("Olá");   
       }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**"async": false ou true**

Se é assíncrono o não. Você pode notar uma diferença nesse atributo quando trabalha com respostas na tela ou quando precisa disparar algum gatilho exatamente no fim da execução, por exemplo. Assim, você dispara outro evento somente no final da execução síncrona do `$.ajax`. Mas isso as vezes faz com que a página fique congelada.

Você pode testar a aplicação disso usando um `alert("alguma coisa");` na função `success`. Vai perceber que `async: true`, o alerta vai ser disparado antes de ter uma resposta da execução do `ajax`, e com o `async: false`, o alerta apenas vai aparecer quando ocorrer o fim exato do `ajax`.

**Existe diferença em usar type: "post" ou  type: "POST"?**

Por experiencia própria, nunca notei diferença. No entanto, no site oficial do `$.ajax`[[+]](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) está tudo em maiúsculo.

**Por que se utiliza data: JSON.stringify?**

Depende de como o servidor está aguardando a resposta da execução. Para um simples envio de `post` por exemplo, basta um `data: $("form").serialize()`.

Para envio de um **`JSON`** para o servidor, aí sim usa o `JSON.stringify` combinado com o `contentType: "application/json"`.

Comment: O `async` determina assincronia do método `ajax` com relação ao resto do código, e não com relação ao *callback* `success`. O `success` só ocorre quando a requisição é bem sucedida, i.e., quando o que quer que você esteja requerendo estiver disponível, o `async` determina se o *resto* da sua lógica aguarda (ou não) esse sucesso. Veja [essa discussão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142978/quando-usar-success-function-e-donefunction-em-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-ass%C3%ADncronas)

Answer (score 9):

Acho que sua própria resposta já responde alguma das suas perguntas.

- **JSON.stringify**: serve simplesmente para converter o objeto JSON para um formato que seja possível trasmitir via uma requisição HTTP.
- **contentType: false**: o header 'contentType' não será colocado na requisição HTTP. É sempre bom especificar o tipo de dado sendo enviado - no seu caso 'application/json'
- **tipos 'post' e 'POST'**: o padrão é enviar com letras maiúsculas. Mas a requisição irá converter automaticamente caso você envie com letras minúsculas. Ou seja, não faz diferença. (Veja [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-open-method) item 4.6.1)
- **async**: basicamente, executando de modo assíncrono, o resto do código não irá esperar a resposta do servidor para prosseguir. Se **async: false**, o resto do código só será executado após a resposta do servidor.

Answer (score 8):

Na [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (em inglês), tem o significado dos parâmetros.

- **`async`**: Por padrão, todas as requisições são enviadas de forma assíncrona, definido com `true`. Se você precisar de solicitações síncronas, defina esta opção como false . Requisições cross-domain e `dataType: "jsonp"` não suportam a operação síncrona. Observe que solicitações síncronas podem bloquear temporariamente o navegador, desativando quaisquer ações enquanto a solicitação estiver ativa.
- **`beforeSend`**: Para alterar o cabeçalho da requisição ou realizar operações antes do envio da requisição, utilize esta função.
- **`cache`**: Se definido como `false`, ele vai forçar páginas não devem ser armazenados em cache pelo navegador solicitado.
- **`complete`**: A função a ser chamada quando os acabamentos de solicitação (depois `success` e `error` retornos de chamada são executados).
- **`contents`**: Um objeto de pares string/expressão regular que determinam como o jQuery irá analisar a resposta, dado o seu tipo de conteúdo.
- **`contentType`**: Ao enviar dados para o servidor, use esse tipo de conteúdo. O padrão é "`application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`", o que é bom para a maioria dos casos. Se você passar explicitamente em um tipo de conteúdo para `$.ajax()`, então é sempre enviado para o servidor (mesmo que nenhum dado é enviado).
- **`context`**: Este objeto será o contexto de todos os retornos de chamada relacionados ao Ajax. Por padrão, o contexto é um objeto que representa as configurações Ajax utilizadas na chamada (`$.ajaxSettings` fundiu-se com as definições passadas para `$.ajax`).
- **`converters`**: Um objeto que contém os conversores `dataType-to-dataType`. O valor de cada conversor é uma função que retorna o valor transformado da resposta.
- **`crossDomain`**: Se você deseja forçar um pedido `crossdomain` (como JSONP) no mesmo domínio, defina o valor de `crossdomain` a `true`. Isso permite, por exemplo, redirecionamento do servidor para outro domínio.
- **`data`**: Dados a serem enviados para o servidor. O formato deve ser variável/valor e se você não deixar nesta formatação a função formatará automaticamente.
- **`dataFilter`**: Uma função a ser usada para manipular os dados de resposta brutos de `XMLHttpRequest`. Esta é uma função de pré-filtragem para sanitizar a resposta. Você deve devolver os dados higienizados. A função aceita dois argumentos: Os dados brutos retornados do servidor e o parâmetro `dataType`.
- **`dataType`**: Você define qual o tipo de dado a ser retornado pela requisição. Os valores possíveis são: xml, html, json, jsonp, script e text. Configurando esta opção você permite uma avaliação dos dados que são retornados. Se esta opção for omitida a função identifica o tipo de dado, mas não avalia.
- **`error`**: Uma função a ser chamada se a solicitação falhar. A função recebe três argumentos: O objeto jqXHR (em jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest), uma string que descreve o tipo de erro que ocorreu e um objeto de exceção opcional, se ocorreu.
- **`global`**: Indica se os eventos manipuladores definidos em `.ajaxSend()` e `.ajaxError()` valerão na requisição atual. Por padrão está setado para `true`.
- **`headers`**: Um objeto de cabeçalho adicional para enviar junto com solicitações usando o transporte XMLHttpRequest.
- **`ifModified`**: Permitir que a solicitação seja bem-sucedida somente se a resposta tiver sido alterada desde a última solicitação. Isso é feito verificando o cabeçalho `Last-Modified`. O valor padrão é `false` , ignorando o cabeçalho.
- **`isLocal`**: Permite que o ambiente atual seja reconhecido como "local" (por exemplo, o sistema de arquivos), mesmo que o jQuery não o reconheça como tal por padrão. Os seguintes protocolos são reconhecidos atualmente como locais: `file` , `*-extension` e `widget` . Se o `isLocal` definição precisa de modificação, recomenda-se a fazê-lo uma vez no `$.ajaxSetup()` método.
- **`jsonp`**: Substitui o nome da função `callback` em uma solicitação `JSONP`.
- **`jsonpCallback`**: Especifica o nome da função `callback` para uma solicitação `JSONP`. Este valor será usado em vez do nome aleatório gerado automaticamente pelo jQuery.
- **`method`**: O método HTTP a ser usado para o pedido (por exemplo, `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`).
- **`mimeType`**: Um tipo mime para substituir o tipo XHR mime.
- **`password`**: Uma senha para ser usada com XMLHttpRequest em resposta a uma solicitação de autenticação de acesso HTTP.
- **`processData`**: Esta variável é configurada para processar e transformar as informações passadas para o padrão `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Se por algum motivo você não quer esta formatação, como mandar no formato xml para o servidor, atribua `false` para esta variável.
- **`scriptCharset`**: Aplica-se somente quando o transporte "script" é usado (por exemplo, solicitações entre domínios com tipo de dados `jsonp` ou `script` e tipo `GET`). Define o `charset` atributo na tag script usado no pedido. Usado quando o conjunto de caracteres na página local não é o mesmo do script remoto.
- **`statusCode`**: Um objeto de códigos e funções numéricas HTTP a ser chamado quando a resposta tem o código correspondente.
- **`success`**: Se a requisição finalizar com sucesso, é executada esta função, que recebe os dados recebidos do servidor.
- **`timeout`**: Se você quer limitar o tempo para a execução da requisição, defina um valor em milissegundos. Não retornando sucesso dentro do tempo definido, uma mensagem de erro, configurada por você na função `error`, será mostrada.
- **`traditional`**: Defina esta opção como `true` se você quiser usar o estilo tradicional de serialização de parâmetro.
- **`type`**: O método usado para a requisição. Aceita `GET` ou `POST`. O padrão é `GET`.
- **`url`**: Endereço no servidor que receberá a requisição.
- **`username`**: Um nome de usuário a ser usado com `XMLHttpRequest` em resposta a uma solicitação de autenticação de acesso HTTP.
- **`xhr`**: `Callback` para criar o objeto `XMLHttpRequest`.
- **`xhrFields`**: Um objeto de pares `fieldName-fieldValue` para definir sobre o nativo XHR objeto.

Informações com base na [Resposta aceita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152836/51124):

> **Existe diferença em usar type: "post" ou type: "POST"?**
>
> Não.
>
> **Por que se utiliza data: JSON.stringify?**
>
> Depende de como o servidor está aguardando a resposta da execução.
>   Para um simples envio de post por exemplo, basta um data:
>   `$("form").serialize()`.
>
> Para envio de um JSON para o servidor, aí sim usa o `JSON.stringify`
>   combinado com o `contentType: "application/json"`.
>
> O `JSON.stringify` serve para transformar um objetos com *tipos
>   primitivos* numa string para poder ser enviada em *tipo String* num
>   formato universal JSON.

Comment: Referência canônica relevante: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax