# Requisição Ajax no construtor ES6

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6

Como eu faço para que no meu construtor seja feita uma requisição `Ajax` e atribuir os valores dessa requisição aos meus atributos?

Até o momento está assim e não está funcionando, eu estou retornando 2 `jsons`... no `console.log` os atributos estão vazios, ou seja, a atribuição não está sendo feita, a consulta funciona normalmente lá no meu `PHP`, já testei.

O console não apresenta nada
Usando Promisse:

```
    class pergunta {
      constructor(perguntas, respostas, desafios) {
          return new Promise((perguntas, respostas, desafios) => {
              jQuery.ajax({
                  url: '../php/consulta.php' + location.search,
                  type: "GET",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: (pergunta, resposta, desafio) => {
                      this.perguntas = pergunta.pergunta;
                      this.respostas = pergunta.resposta;
                      this.desafios = desafio.descricao;
                  }
              });
          });
      }
  }

  new pergunta().then((perguntas) => {
      console.log(pergunta);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Tens 2 problemas aqui:

- **`#1`:** O `this` dentro do ajax está a apontar para a instância do jQuery, e não para o teu construtor pois não é uma propriedade dele.
- **`#2`:** O ajax é assíncrono, não podes fazer `console.log` depois de instanciar a classe, pois isso acontece antes da respostas vir do servidor.

### #1:

Dentro de `success: function(pergunta, desafio){` o `this` aponta para o jQuery, e não para o que está à volta. Assim se quiseres ter o `this` a apontar para a tua classe tens 3 alternativas:

- usar a propriedade `context` e passar aí a referência do contexto que queres:

Exemplo:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: '../php/consulta.php' + location.search,
   type: "GET",
   dataType: 'json',
   context: this,
   success: function(pergunta, desafio){
       this.perguntas = pergunta.pergunta;
       this.respostas = pergunta.resposta;
       this.desafios = desafio.descricao;

     }
});
```

- podes usar um `sósia`/`alias`, dando o nome `self` ao this fora do `success` do jQuery para teres um ponteiro depois (a ideia que [o Heber também sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/201643/129)).

Exemplo:

```
const self = this;
jQuery.ajax({
   url: '../php/consulta.php' + location.search,
   type: "GET",
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(pergunta, desafio){
       self.perguntas = pergunta.pergunta;
       self.respostas = pergunta.resposta;
       self.desafios = desafio.descricao;
     }
});
```

- usar `arrow functions` que não mudam o contexto de execução:

Exemplo:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: '../php/consulta.php' + location.search,
   type: "GET",
   dataType: 'json',
   success:(pergunta, desafio) => {
       this.perguntas = pergunta.pergunta;
       this.respostas = pergunta.resposta;
       this.desafios = desafio.descricao;
     }
});
```

### #2:

Aqui tens de usar [callbacks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27182/129), [promises](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143062/129) ou `async`/`await`

Um exemplo com Promisses poderia ser assim:

```
class pergunta {
    constructor(id, title) {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '../php/consulta.php' + location.search,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: (pergunta, desafio) => {
                    this.perguntas = pergunta.pergunta;
                    this.respostas = pergunta.resposta;
                    this.desafios = desafio.descricao;
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

new pergunta().then((perguntas) => {
    console.log(perguntas);
});
```

---

#### Demo com promisse:

```js
class pergunta {
  constructor(id, title) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: ({
          id,
          title
        }) => {
          this.id = id;
          this.title = title;
          res(this);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
new pergunta().then((perguntas) => {
  console.log(perguntas);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Eu tentei usar as arrow functions e coloquei uma função pra exibir, mas não me é exibido nada, da undefined. Vou editar a pergunta, pra você ver.

Comment: @TiagoSilveira essa nova versão com `exibir` tem o mesmo problema. Viste a minha _demo_ com promisses? é a ideia de `.exibir()` mas respeitando a natureza assíncrona do ajax. Testa essa ideia.

Comment: fiz com o promisse, mas nem o console log funciona, fiz as alterações devidas dando o get pra minha api, testei a api pura e a consulta ta normal. Vou alterar a pergunta com o código editado.

Comment: @TiagoSilveira usa o meu código e cria um jsFiddle com o teu códig para eu ver

Comment: Como meu código não está online eu fiz usando outro jsonplaceholder e não funcionou, olha o fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L0yb12og/3/ Json: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Comment: @TiagoSilveira tinhas alguns erros: https://jsfiddle.net/L0yb12og/4/

Comment: Nesse ultimo exemplo o console não retorna nada, nem um alert é executado, outra duvida, poderia me explicar como funciona o promisse dessa forma eu poderia trabalhar melhor com ele.

Comment: @TiagoSilveira o ultimo exemplo funciona bem, testa de novo. Podes ler mais sobre promisses aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143062/129

Comment: porque nada me é exibido no console então? :(

Comment: @TiagoSilveira testa assim: https://jsfiddle.net/o3uub8tn/

Comment: Tentei novamente e não foi, tentei rodar pelo JSbin e não executou nada tbm @Sergio♦

Comment: @TiagoSilveira tens alguma firewall onde estás? ou um browser antigo?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58124/discussion-between-tiago-silveira-and-sergio).

Comment: @TiagoSilveira se alguma das respostas resolveu o problema podes marcar como aceite. Senão diz o que falta para completar!

Answer (score 1):

O escopo da função success da requisição ajax é diferente do escopo do constructor, tente isto:

```
class pergunta {

      constructor(perguntas = [], respostas = [], desafios = [], valor = 100, posicao = 0){

        var _self = this;

        [.. código suprimido ..]

        jQuery.ajax({
           url: '../php/consulta.php' + location.search,
           type: "GET",
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data){
               _self.perguntas = data.perguntas;
               _self.respostas = data.respostas;
               _self.desafios = data.desafios;
           }
        });
    }
}
const perguntas = new pergunta();
console.log(perguntas);
```

Lembre-se também que é um método assíncrono, então só irá "preencher" o valor após a requisição finalizar.

Comment: testei, mas não rolou, editei a pergunta.

Comment: Você não está considerando que a requisição é assíncrona, é outra, está utilizando o alias self junto com a Arrow function, veja a explicação do colega abaixo novamente, também implemente a promise, isso resolve o seu problema.

Comment: No console do Chrome você consegue ver as propriedades da instância dá classe pergunta após a requisição, imaginei que o problema fosse apenas o escopo.