# Async/Await não funciona com callback

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-7

Eu tenho uma função que converte uma imagem em base 64 porém eu quero que somente quando acabar a execução o console.log('1'); deve aparecer é o local onde executo um post mas mesmo dentro da arrowFunction ele faz a requisição no servidor antes de terminar de converter a imagem e isso da erro.

```js
async getImageUrl(event, contentIndex: number) {
  await this.toDataUrl(event, (base64image) => {
    console.log(base64image);
    this.base64image = base64image;

  });
  console.log("1");
}

toDataUrl(url, callback) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = () => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      callback(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Você tem de colocar async / await em todos os níveis de toDataUrl. Na funcão propriamente dita, no onload e nos arrow functions abaixo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há maneiras diferentes de encadear funções assíncronas. Neste caso `toDataUrl()` é uma função assíncrona que usa callbacks. Isso não pode ser combinado com `async/await` dessa maneira. Ou seja, ou usas o `await` e `toDataUrl()` retorna uma Promise, ou então `toDataUrl()` retorna uma callback e encadeias o código dentro da callback.

As duas variantes seriam assim:

### Usando [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback):

```js
async getImageUrl(event, contentIndex: number) {
   this.toDataUrl(event, (base64image) => {
    console.log(base64image);
    this.base64image = base64image;
    
    // aqui podes escrever o resto do código
    console.log("1");
  });
}

toDataUrl(url, callback) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = () => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      callback(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();
}
```

### Usando Promise:

```js
async getImageUrl(event, contentIndex: number) {
  const base64image = await this.toDataUrl(event);
  console.log(base64image);
  this.base64image = base64image;
  // aqui podes escrever o resto do código
  console.log("1");
}

toDataUrl(url, callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = () => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        resolve(reader.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = reject;
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

Encontras uma variante de Promise e callback (sem `async/await`) aqui também: [Quando usar success: function() e .done(function()) em requisições assíncronas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142978/129)