# Como obter valor [[PromiseValue]]?

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo dificuldade de obter valor `[[PromiseValue]]`

Segue exemplo da imagem no modo debugger:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código:

**Html:**

```
<img id="new_profile_photo" alt="Perfil">
```

**JS:**

```
$('#new_profile_photo').croppie({
    url: e.target.result,
    viewport: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        type: 'circle'
    },
    boundary: {
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    }
});
var result = $('#new_profile_photo').croppie('result');
```

"Promisse" fica dentro da variável `result`.

Alguém tem ideia como eu posso obter o valor ?

Exemplo: `"data:image/png...."`.

Estou usando plugin : https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A sua variável é uma [Promise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16921/como-realmente-aprender-a-usar-promessas-em-javascript), ou seja, uma promessa de que um determinado valor (esse que você quer pegar) pode estar disponível no futuro. Quando estiver, ou seja, quando a promessa estiver *resolvida*, ela executa os callbacks que tiverem sido registrados antes com o método `then()`, e passa o valor obtido para esses callbacks.

No seu código, isso ficaria assim:

```
var result = $('#new_profile_photo').croppie('result');
result.then(function(valor) {
    // Faça algo com o valor aqui dentro.
    // Se precisar dele em outro lugar, chame uma função
    // e passe adiante. Não tente atribuir seu valor a uma
    // variável de fora e acessar lá embaixo, não vai funcionar.
    // (exceto em certos casos com frameworks reativos)
});
```

O que você viu no console, com duplos colchetes `[[ ... ]]`, é uma propriedade interna do objeto, não acessível pela linguagem, somente pelo host dela (o browser, o nodejs, etc). Essa é a notação que [a especificação](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) da linguagem usa para se referir a propriedades/métodos/valores internos, que só existem para efeito de explicar como a linguagem deve funcionar e ser implementada.

Comment: Na variável `valor` retorna assim: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtWK6eAAAgAElEQV...` final da linha com 3 pontinhos.  Como posso obter ela completa ?

Comment: Se o servidor está mandando ela completa, deve ser só o console abreviando. Seu código deve ter acesso ao valor completo.