# Consumo da API do Bing

Tags: javascript, json, api

Preciso pegar o endereço de uma imagem da API do Bing:

> https://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=pt-BR

Essa API me retorna um JSON que contém essa informação que quero, mas não consigo acessá-la:

```xml
{
  "images": [
    {
      "startdate": "20181023",
      "fullstartdate": "201810230700",
      "enddate": "20181024",
      "url": "/az/hprichbg/rb/LiquidNitrogen_ROW10236809816_1920x1080.jpg",
      "urlbase": "/az/hprichbg/rb/LiquidNitrogen_ROW10236809816",
      "copyright": "Liquid nitrogen (© Sunny/Getty Images)",
      "copyrightlink": "javascript:void(0)",
      "title": "",
      "quiz": "/search?q=Bing+homepage+quiz&filters=WQOskey:%22HPQuiz_20181023_LiquidNitrogen%22&FORM=HPQUIZ",
      "wp": true,
      "hsh": "c15d9d44fef770c98a00bc8edc3c6ab6",
      "drk": 1,
      "top": 1,
      "bot": 1,
      "hs": []
    }
  ],
  "tooltips": {
    "loading": "Carregando...",
    "previous": "Imagem anterior",
    "next": "Próxima imagem",
    "walle": "Esta imagem não está disponível para ser baixada como papel de parede.",
    "walls": "Baixe esta imagem. O uso desta imagem é restrito ao papel de parede."
  }
}
```

Segue meu código:

```
const data = fetch('https://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx? 
        format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=pt-BR', {method:'GET'})    
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => console.log(result));
         const img = data.images['0'].url;
```

Já tentei tirar as aspas do zero e também tentei colocar duas aspas no mesmo, mas não funcionou de nenhuma das duas formas.

O erro que o console mostra é o seguinte:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer `console.log(data)` e você entenderá o problema. `data` é uma promise, não um objeto.

Mude seu código para:

```js
var data;
const promise = fetch('https://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1&mkt=pt-BR', {method:'GET'}) 
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => data = result);

const img = data.images[0].url
console.log(img)
```

Para ter um maior entendimento sobre promises, seguem algumas referencias dentro do SOpt encaminhadas pelo nosso colega Pedro Gaspar:

[O que são promises (promessas) em javascript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119907/86952)

[Como realmente aprender a usar promessas em javascript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16921/86952)

Comment: Eu ia responder isso também, mas você foi mais rápido! :) Eu ia citar essas perguntas aqui também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119907/86952 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16921/86952. Se quiser adicionar à resposta, talvez fosse interessante.

Comment: Adicionei, obrigado pela adição