# Qual a diferença entre utilizar o metodo da classe e o prototype Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Olá gostaria de saber se ha alguma diferença entre o metodo normal( criado na classe ) e o prototype.

Estou pensando em alta escala tipo: varias objetos(instancias) de um determinada classe. Haveria alguma mudança na performance dependendo de qual eu utilizaria?

Codigo com a minha classe JS:

```
function Scroller(){
    var teste = 'hue';
    this.teste2 = 'ola';
    this.getTeste = function(){
        return teste;
    }
}

var teste = new Scroller();
teste.getTeste();
```

Att,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se forem poucos objetos, não importa, mas se o número dos mesmos for grande, colocar no `prototype` tem a vantagem de que somente uma cópia da função existe, e não várias (funções são objetos de primeira classe em JavaScript). Essa representação abaixo ilustra o fato:

```
{x,y,z,a,b,c} {x,y,z,a,b,c} {x,y,z,a,b,c} {x,y,z,a,b,c} {x,y,z,a,b,c} {x,y,z,a,b,c}
```

Vs.:

```
{a,b,c}
   ^
   |
   +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
   |       |       |       |       |       |
{x,y,z} {x,y,z} {x,y,z} {x,y,z} {x,y,z} {x,y,z}
```

Isso não garante *necessariamente* que a performance **em tempo** será pior, somente que ao copiar a função em cada instância vai se gastar **mais memória**. E muitas vezes esses dois fatores constituem justamente um *tradeoff* (i.e. aumenta-se o espaço para reduzir o tempo, ou vice-versa). Mas nesse caso em particular, eu creio que solução com o `prototye` se sairá melhor nos dois quesitos, pois:

- Se um objeto ocupa mais memória, menos objetos cabem numa página da cache, de modo que o número de *misses* é maior;
- Se a função a ser chamada várias vezes está no protótipo, e o protótipo está na cache, o acesso a ela é tão rápido quanto poderia ser (o *overhead* de subir a cadeia de protótipos existe, mas deve ser negligível).

De novo, essa é só minha interpretação particular, para saber com certeza somente testando. [Esse exemplo no jsperf](http://jsperf.com/functions-in-prototype-vs-object-itself), por exemplo, deu resultados de acordo com minha interpretação (no Chrome, pelo menos).

P.S. Dependendo da forma como for feito, pode ser que exista um único objeto da função, e somente várias referências para ela. Exemplo:

```
function foo() { ... }

function MinhaClasse(...) {
    ...
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

Nesse caso ainda há a memória gasta pela referência em si, mas o impacto não é tão grande. Por outro lado, se a função for definida internamente - *principalmente* se ela capturar variáveis da função externa (ver [*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/215)) - então o requisito em espaço torna-se ainda maior (pois há de fato um objeto extra para cada instância):

```
function MinhaClasse(...) {
    ...
    this.foo = function() { ... }
}
```